# Unable to show a Git tree in terminal

Tags: git, terminal, tree, console, revision-history

[Killswitchcollective.com's old article, 30 June 2009](http://killswitchcollective.com/articles/36_git_it_got_it_good), has the following inputs and outputs

```
git co master
git merge [your_branch]
git push

upstream    A-B-C-D-E            A-B-C-D-E-F-G
                 \        ---->               \
your branch       C-D-E                        G
```

I am interested how you get the tree like-view of commits in your terminal without using Gitk or Gitx in OS/X.

**How can you get the tree-like view of commits in terminal?**

Comment: It's not important to the question, but the article in question is no longer available. A cached copy is available via the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20110831142839/http://killswitchcollective.com/articles/36_git_it_got_it_good

Answer (score 972, accepted):

How can you get the tree-like view of commits in terminal?

```
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

is a good start.

You may get some strange letters. They are ASCII codes for colors and structure. To solve this problem add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
export LESS="-R"
```

such that you do not need use Tig's ASCII filter by

```
git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit | tig   // Masi needed this
```

The article [text-based graph from Git-ready](http://www.gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/26/text-based-graph.html) contains other options:

```
git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

[image: git log graph]

Regarding the article you mention, I would go with [Pod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064361/unable-to-show-a-git-tree-in-terminal/1064415#1064415): ad-hoc hand-made output.

---

**[Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narbski)** mentions in the comments **[tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/manual.html)**, a ncurses-based text-mode interface for git. See [their releases](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/releases/).
It added [a `--graph` option](http://markmail.org/message/b4nxlifggqb7nj44) back in 2007.

Comment: I just tested it on my repo. It works but I am on Windows with MSysGit1.6.3.

Comment: files.getdropbox.com is blocked here at work :( I will see your picture in about one hour, time to get home.

Comment: @Vonc: I now typed two for the first command. I get a similar view as in the picture for the second command.

Comment: There is also 'tig', text-mode interface for git (using ncurses), which had graphical history view in terminal before there was '--graph' option to git-log.

Comment: I find `--decorate` to be indispensable on this sort of a display as well -- it shows you ref names (branches, remote and local) alongside the abbreviated commit name.

Comment: @MattEnright I agree, and use it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022890/how-to-display-the-tag-name-and-branch-name-using-git-log-graph/7023272#7023272. But beware of the colors used by decorate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889878/color-in-git-log/5892582#5892582

Comment: @MattEnright and for certain tasks, decorate isn't the best option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659273/how-can-i-know-what-was-the-latest-changes-made-to-a-branch

Comment: I've found out that this is an easier way to remember git log --graph --oneline

Answer (score 359):

A solution is to create an Alias in your `.gitconfig` and call it easily:

```
[alias]
    tree = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

And when you call it next time, you'll use:

```
git tree
```

To put it in your ~/.gitconfig without having to edit it, you can do:

```
git config --global alias.tree "log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit"
```

(If you don't use the --global it will put it in the .git/config of your current repo.)

Comment: How is this not a default alias? I guess it would make Git's CLI slightly less infuriating to use and we can't have that...

Answer (score 143):

```
git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph
```

A visual tree with branch names included.

Use this to add it as an alias

```
git config --global alias.tree "log --oneline --decorate --all --graph"
```

You call it with

```
git tree
```

[image: Git Tree]

Comment: Very nice, this one. I use it in combination with `less -S` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38062876), to prevent wrapped lines from obfuscating the tree.

Comment: Sebastian: `ty 4 alias`

Answer (score 70):

## `tig`

If you want a **interactive** tree, you can use [`tig`](https://github.com/jonas/tig). It can be installed by `brew` on OSX and `apt-get` in Linux.

```
brew install tig
tig
```

This is what you get:

[image]

Comment: Can you get such a tree as in VonC's answer by Tig currently? We use Tig in VonC's answer only as Ascii filter.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest anyone to write down the full command

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

rather than create an alias.

It's good to get the commands into your head, so you know it by heart 
i.e. do not depend on aliases when you change machines.

Comment: It is actually `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, after the mnemonic `git log a dog` ;)

Comment: @VonC The final result is the same. Anyway, I agree with you. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Yes, that is what the smiley `;)` at the end of my previous comment was trying (imperfectly) to convey: you can use those option in any order you want. I just find "log a dog" funny :)

Comment: Or you could `scp ~/.bashrc root@remote:~/` and your aliases move over real quick.

Answer (score 7):

Keeping your commands short will make them easier to remember:

```
git log --graph --oneline
```