# Visualizing branch topology in Git

Tags: git

I'm playing with Git in isolation on my own machine, and I find it difficult to maintain a mental model of all my branches and commits. I know I can do a `git log` to see the commit history from where I am, but is there a way to see the entire branch topography, something like these ASCII maps that seem to be used everywhere for explaining branches?

```
      .-A---M---N---O---P
     /     /   /   /   /
    I     B   C   D   E
     \   /   /   /   /
      `-------------'
```

It just feels like someone coming along and trying to pick up my repository would have difficulty working out exactly what was going on.

I guess I'm influenced by AccuRev's [stream browser](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/accurev/72/WebHelp/AccuRev_WUI_Guide/GUID-C21657AA-7CDF-4484-9658-7E28A5BB7A91.html)...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064361/unable-to-show-a-git-tree-in-terminal

Comment: @leif81, a half-duplicate, for me. @Masi explicitly excluded gitk in his question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs)

Answer (score 1323, accepted):

Use `git log --graph` or `gitk`. (Both also accept `--all`, which will show all the branches instead of just the current one.)

For branch names and a compact view, try:

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline
```

Comment: Thanks! gitg also has the `--all` option and also labels the commits. I also never saw in the dropdown that you can select all branches there.

Comment: --pretty=oneline also comes in pretty handy

Comment: [tig](https://github.com/jonas/tig) (a ncurse git client) also provides the ``--all`` option. Quite handy !

Comment: See also [answer by Andrew](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git#answer-7509303) regarding `--simplify-by-decoration` option.

Comment: throw in a `-n` also. Where `n` is the number of commits you want to limit the log to

Comment: I think `--decorate` seems to be the default now, so it's no longer necessary

Comment: zsh: command not found: gitk

Comment: Is there a way to arrange the log horizontally as opposed to vertically?

Comment: Actually `git log --graph --simplify-by-decoration --oneline --all` gets quite close. The `--all` is needed to show other branches and `--simplify-by-decoration` to collapse the linear parts of the history.

Answer (score 635):

I have 3 aliases *(and 4 alias-aliases for quick usage)* that I normally throw in my `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
    lg = lg1
    lg1 = lg1-specific --all
    lg2 = lg2-specific --all
    lg3 = lg3-specific --all

    lg1-specific = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(auto)%d%C(reset)'
    lg2-specific = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(auto)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)'
    lg3-specific = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(bold cyan)(committed: %cD)%C(reset) %C(auto)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset)%n''          %C(dim white)- %an <%ae> %C(reset) %C(dim white)(committer: %cn <%ce>)%C(reset)'
```

`git lg`/`git lg1` looks like this:

[image: git lg1]

`git lg2` looks like this:

[image: git lg2]

and `git lg3` looks like this:

[image: git lg3]

It should be noted that this isn't meant as a end-all-be-all solution— it's a template for you to change, add to and fix up to your liking.  If you want to use these, my recommendation is to:

1. Add them to your `.gitconfig`,
2. Customize to your liking (different color choices, different line arrangements for the 2- and 3-line versions, etc.),
3. And then save a copy to a Gist or other code snippet tool so you can copy & paste it into `.gitconfig`s in the future *(or alternatively version control your dotfiles, of course)*.

*<sub>Note: Answer copied from and improved upon the answer at [stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs/9074343#9074343) since it's far more appropriate here than it was there.  Left the copy on the other question for historical reasons— it's closed now, and the answer's referenced by a bunch of other answers.</sub>*

Comment: @Atcold I'm personally on-the-fence regarding that change— while it does give you those differing colors, they're all inverted colorings (colored background w/ black text), and the punctuation (`(` `)` `,` `->`) ends up dim-white.  **TL;DR: I find Git's `auto`-coloring useful but ugly.**  However, it cannot be understated that these shortcut commands are _meant_ to be customized by the user— everyone who adds these should consider changing colors and flags to best fit their workflow & terminal setup.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson, I'm not sure what you're talking about. To me it looks just fine (see this [image](https://s11.postimg.org/xgeaatj77/git.png)).

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson, there is something odd with your configurations. On a fresh Ubuntu install `git log --decorate` looks just fine (see [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22git+log+--decorate%22&espv=2&biw=1855&bih=990&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUuLOA6dPQAhUI_4MKHZhZC7gQ_AUIBygC)).

Comment: @Atcold Yep, I did have `reverse` under my `color.decorate.*` settings.  Oops.

Comment: Note that you can avoid manually adding indentation in your format string by using `%w()`; this way you can also properly line-wrap longer or multi-line commit messages without messing up the graph.

Comment: You can also append this to your ~/.bashrc which I found more powerful for using it in different git repos.

Comment: @lostcitizen I'm not sure I see the advantage over `~/.gitconfig` (not to be confused with the per-repo `«a-repo-dir»/.git/config`)— both will apply to all git repos on your machine (while logged in with that user account).  And if you regularly work across multiple machines, there are a number of tools and solutions out there for syncing all your config `~/.…` dotfiles.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson when I remove `--abbrev-commit --decorate` switches from command lines, I don't see an effect on the output. Are those redundant if `--format` is specified?

Comment: I took the liberty to modify `lg3-specific` in @SlippD.Thompson's answer and added this line to my `.gitconfig` to consider line endings in the subject by using `%B` instead of `%s`, and used `%w()` instead of explicit spaces: `lg4-specific = log --graph --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(bold cyan)(committed: %cD)%C(reset) %C(auto)%d%C(reset)%n''%C(white)%w(100,10,10)%B%C(reset)''%w(,18,)%C(dim white)- %an <%ae> %C(reset)%n%n'`

Comment: @mbadawi23 They are redundant for the sake of consistency across platform and Git installations.  `--abbrev-commit` is in there because the 2nd-3rd lines are hand-indented with spaces, and I wanted to make absolutely sure that it would use the short SHA— so better safe than sorry.  `--decorate` is also in there because although Git's defaults do the same thing, that could be config'd differently or different in different Git versions— for these, I absolutely want decoration.  Ultimately, extra/redundant flags aren't bad here— this goes in a file; it's not something you type all the time.

Comment: I configured these aliases in a Docker image that you can run to display such aliases. Link: https://github.com/ferrarimarco/open-development-environment-git

Comment: combine this with github.com/theZiz/aha and you got a wonderful html git log, you just have to append `--color` to the gitlog command

Comment: How do you know what each branch is?

Comment: @TimothyPulliam At the end of each line that represents the tip of each branch/tag, you'll see the associated branch/tag names in parentheses— e.g. in the `lg1` & `lg2` screenshots you can see `(origin/test_on_10.8)` showing the remote branch, and in the `lg2` screenshot you can see `(HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)` showing both local and remote positions of the `master` branch and `HEAD`.  This matches what popular branch-visualizing GUI tools for Git do (gitk, SourceTree, TortoiseGit, Tower, Fork, GitX), though with a bit more verbosity _(some GUI tools use color-coding)_.

Comment: @TimothyPulliam To understand what commits are “part of each branch”, you have to visually trace the colored line.  Nearly every tool doesn't help you much with this because Git commits don't intrinsically belong to any branch— they're implied (at graph-visualization-time) to belong to any branch or tag that has them in their parent-ancestry.  If no branch/tag referencing a commit and it disappears (but isn't garbage-collected for about 2 weeks); add a branch/tag referencing a previously-unreferenced commit and it reappears.  I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson An incidental question: what does the "!" symbol do? I read something about delayed expansion of the variables, but in that case two of them are used (!variable!). I also noted that removing it, when the git + alias command is executed the word "git" is taken as part of the command and an error is thrown because "'git' is not a git command".  Thank you

Comment: @PedroGarcíaMedina I means “run this quoted text as a shell command, rather than calling another git command”, and is designed mainly for integrating other tools with git _(for example, you could write something like `syncup = !"git pull && make all"`)_.  I'm using it here because I couldn't call another alias in an alias (I could only call a git command), but maybe that's changed in newer versions of git.  I'll double-check it and simplify if it can now be done with just `lg = lg1`.

Comment: i get the expansion of alias failed error, when i simply copy paste this in my ~/.gitconfig. Am i missing something?

Comment: Vs code extension 'Git Graph' does all of this including many more functions like cherry-pick, merge, revert etc.

Comment: @utkarsh-k Exactly.  There are many great Git GUI tools out there that will show you a graph view and so much more.  I use Fork and love it so much I almost never use these command aliases… however, I keep them in my .gitconfig because they're still handy if you're already on the command line need to look at the commit graph just temporarily, or if you're working on a remote machine via an SSH terminal, or whenever the command line is handier.  I don't consider these aliases a “power tool”, just a “handy tool not dissimilar to the GUI you already use”.

Comment: About the use of %an %ae: you ignore mailmap entries in this way. Usually they are set for good reason, namely authors/committers changed name or email and want to point users to the correct current information. It would be better to use %aN %aE here, which is also default behaviour for git log.

Answer (score 533):

I usually use

```
git log --graph --full-history --all --pretty=format:"%h%x09%d%x20%s"
```

With colors (if your shell is Bash):

```
git log --graph --full-history --all --color \
        --pretty=format:"%x1b[31m%h%x09%x1b[32m%d%x1b[0m%x20%s"
```

This will print text-based representation like this:

```
* 040cc7c       (HEAD, master) Manual is NOT built by default
* a29ceb7       Removed offensive binary file that was compiled on my machine and was hence incompatible with other machines.
| * 901c7dd     (cvc3) cvc3 now configured before building
| * d9e8b5e     More sane Yices SMT solver caller
| | * 5b98a10   (nullvars) All uninitialized variables get zero inits
| |/
| * 1cad874     CFLAGS for cvc3 to work successfully
| *   1579581   Merge branch 'llvm-inv' into cvc3
| |\
| | * a9a246b   nostaticalias option
| | * 73b91cc   Comment about aliases.
| | * 001b20a   Prints number of iteration and node.
| |/
|/|
| * 39d2638     Included header files to cvc3 sources
| * 266023b     Added cvc3 to blast infrastructure.
| * ac9eb10     Initial sources of cvc3-1.5
|/
* d642f88       Option -aliasstat, by default stats are suppressed
```

(You could just use `git log --format=oneline`, but it will tie commit messages to numbers, which looks less pretty IMHO).

To make a shortcut for this command, you may want to edit your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
  gr = log --graph --full-history --all --color --pretty=tformat:"%x1b[31m%h%x09%x1b[32m%d%x1b[0m%x20%s%x20%x1b[33m(%an)%x1b[0m"
```

---

However, as [Sodel the Vociferous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508745/sodel-the-vociferous) notes in the comments, such long formatting command is hard to memorize. Usually, it's not a problem as you may put it into the `~/.gitconfig` file.  However, if you sometimes have to log in to a remote machine where you can't modify the config file, you could use a more simple but faster to type version:

```
git log --graph --oneline
```

Comment: If you like dates: git log --graph --full-history --all --color --date=short --pretty=format:"%x1b[31m%h%x09%x1b[32m%d%x1b[0m%x20%ad %s"

Comment: --oneline is a more memorable substitute for all that pretty formatting deep-magic.

Comment: @SodeltheVociferous, indeed, I didn't approach the problem from the side you talk about; I expanded my answer.

Comment: Note: `--full-history` is only relevant when using `--simplify-by-decoration` or specifying a filepath.

Comment: Might I ask where you got the format string from? Or how on earth you concocted that thing?

Comment: @elli0t if you're still wondering 2 years later, see [git log documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log) section "PRETTY FORMATS" a little way down under the "format: <string>" item

Answer (score 288):

To any of these recipes (based on git log or gitk), you can add `--simplify-by-decoration` to collapse the uninteresting linear parts of the history.  This makes much more of the topology visible at once.  I can now understand large histories that would be incomprehensible without this option!

I felt the need to post this because it doesn't seem to be as well-known as it should be.  It doesn't appear in most of the Stack Overflow questions about visualizing history, and it took me quite a bit of searching to find--even after I knew I wanted it!  I finally found it in this [Debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=482474).  The first mention on Stack Overflow seems to be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298972/relationship-between-n-git-branches/5299045#5299045) by Antoine Pelisse.

Comment: Perfect -- exactly what I was looking for! It should get more upvotes; almost everybody already knows about gitk/gitg/git log --graph, but those are not at all very useful if you want to visualize the branch topology and don't care about single commits.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, fantastic. It's the only thing that helped me, out of all answers. `--simplify-by-decoration` makes so clear what's going on.

Comment: This should really be the answer. `git log --graph --all --simplify-by-decoration` works as well.

Comment: If only we could use `--simplify-by-decoration`while adding n commits before/after each deocrated commit (like `-B` and `-A` for `grep`).

Comment: I use this solution so frequently I have it aliased as 'git tree'.

Answer (score 85):

Gitk's output is sometimes painful for me to read:

[image]

It motivated me to write [GitVersionTree](https://github.com/crc8/GitVersionTree):

[image]

Comment: @exhuma I have a PR in with the author to support Mono (tested on Ubuntu 13.10 against Mono 2.10)

Comment: I've found that GitVersionTree keeps branches in the same place with time, which makes it easier to see how things change.

Comment: Just stumbled on this. It looks really cool; I can't wait t check it out. One suggestion (maybe you already have it), but it could be nice to collapse multiple commits that aren't forking points. That would make it easier to view the branch topology.

Answer (score 63):

Take a look at [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) - a cross-platform GUI that shows topology in a lucid way.

[image: Topology]

Here's a quick [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=21&v=j1rP21RcbH0) on some advanced features.

*Note: registration is required.*

Comment: How does this thread have GitKraken, but it doesn't have the older and free SourceTree? (I know, I know, Atlassian doesn't always get everything right. But SourceTree is a pretty great tool for visualizing.)

Comment: @XML It isn't available for Linux.

Comment: The same company has also made an extension for Visual Studio Code, called [GitLens](https://www.gitkraken.com/gitlens). It's free, and it doesn't even require registration.

Answer (score 53):

*99.999% of my time is looking at history by `git lg` and the 0.001% is by `git log`.*

I just want to share two log aliases that might be useful (configure from .gitconfig):

```
[Alias]
     lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset %ad %s %C(yellow)%d%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --date=short
     hist = log --graph --full-history --all --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset %ad %s %C(yellow)%d%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --date=short
```

- `git lg` will see the current branch history.
- `git hist` will see the whole branch history.

Answer (score 45):

I like, with [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), to do:

```
 git log --graph --oneline --branches
```

(also with --all, for viewing remote branches as well)

Works with recent Git releases: introduced [since **1.6.3**](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.6.3.txt) ([Thu, 7 May 2009](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=f01f1099f40f24fe6f7802185340a6fa3a3d4f35))

> - "`--pretty=<style>`" option to the log family of commands can now be  spelled as "`--format=<style>`".
>     In addition, `--format=%formatstring` is a short-hand for `--pretty=tformat:%formatstring`.
> - **"`--oneline`" is a synonym for "`--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`".**

```
PS D:\git\tests\finalRepo> git log --graph --oneline --branches --all
* 4919b68 a second bug10 fix
* 3469e13 a first bug10 fix
* dbcc7aa a first legacy evolution
| * 55aac85 another main evol
| | * 47e6ee1 a second bug10 fix
| | * 8183707 a first bug10 fix
| |/
| * e727105 a second evol for 2.0
| * 473d44e a main evol
|/
* b68c1f5 first evol, for making 1.0
```

You can also limit the span of the log display (number of commits):

```
PS D:\git\tests\finalRepo> git log --graph --oneline --branches --all -5
* 4919b68 a second bug10 fix
* 3469e13 a first bug10 fix
* dbcc7aa a first legacy evolution
| * 55aac85 another main evol
| | * 47e6ee1 a second bug10 fix
```

(show only the last 5 commits)

---

What I do not like about the current selected solution is:

```
 git log --graph
```

It displayed way too much info (when I want only to look at a quick summary):

```
PS D:\git\tests\finalRepo> git log --graph
* commit 4919b681db93df82ead7ba6190eca6a49a9d82e7
| Author: VonC <vonc@laposte.net>
| Date:   Sat Nov 14 13:42:20 2009 +0100
|
|     a second bug10 fix
|
* commit 3469e13f8d0fadeac5fcb6f388aca69497fd08a9
| Author: VonC <vonc@laposte.net>
| Date:   Sat Nov 14 13:41:50 2009 +0100
|
|     a first bug10 fix
|
```

`gitk` is great, but forces me to leave the shell session for another window, whereas displaying the last n commits quickly is often enough.

Comment: I choose this method also, but I made an alias so that typing "git graph" is the same as executing "git log --graph --decorate --oneline".

Comment: @ConnerPike good idea. I have the alias 'lg' myself: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3667139/6309

Answer (score 41):

[Gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg/) is a great tool for Linux, similar to Gitx for OS X. Just run 'gitg' on the command line from somewhere inside your repository's tree structure (same with gitx).

Comment: In so many words: gitg has a drop-down menu where one can chose which branch to visualize. This drop-down also has an "All" option.

Comment: Or you can start it with `gitg --all`, if you want to avoid mucking around in the drop down menu.

Answer (score 29):

A nice web based tool is [ungit](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit). It runs on any platform that [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and Git supports. There is [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkBVAi3oKvo&feature=youtu.be) of how it works for those that find that sort of things easier than reading...

[image]

Comment: I am using it. Works well on small project - when there are not too many branches. Unfortunately it is unusable with 20-50 open branches

Answer (score 28):

I found [git-big-picture](https://github.com/esc/git-big-picture) quite useful.

It creates pretty 2D graphs using dot/[Graphviz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) instead of the rather linear, "one-dimensional" views [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) and friends produce. With the `-i` option it shows the branch points and merge commits, but leaves out everything in-between.

Comment: It should scale with the number of commits just fine (if you use -i), it might become unreadable if you have complexing branches and merges (but then, which tool doesn't)

Comment: With our project of a medium scale, this generates a huge picture with tons of lines. Can I limit the depth it goes to? I.e. commits from last N days or so.

Answer (score 28):

Have a look at [BranchMaster](https://github.com/ChristianStroyer/BranchMaster).

I wrote it to visualize a complex branch structure, by collapsing all commits between them to a single line. The numbers indicates the number of commits.

[image]

Comment: This is what i'm looking for. Are there alternative commands/tools to do this?

Comment: @AalexGabi   Put this into your gitconfig, it does same thing, but in command line

gbranch = log --graph --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(white)%d %C(bold black)%ar %C(reset)%n' --all

Comment: How are you getting the data to visualize the branches?

Comment: My only beef with your app is that it works, but I can't reposition the nodes or scroll around.

Answer (score 25):

I found [this blog post](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/graphs-and-git/visualizing-your-git-repository.html) which shows a concise way:

```
git log --oneline --abbrev-commit --all --graph --decorate --color
```

I usually create an alias for the above command:

```
alias gl='git log --oneline --abbrev-commit --all --graph --decorate --color'
```

And simply just use `gl`.

You can also add the alias to the Git configuration. Open file `~/.gitconfig` and add the following line to the *[alias]* section:

```
[alias]
        lg = log --oneline --abbrev-commit --all --graph --decorate --color
```

And use it like this:

```
git lg
```

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

I'm using the [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) editor, and I found myself very pleased with the *Git Graph* extension of it, made by mhutchie. (And I'm not alone, there are 1 million users of the extension!).

[image]

If you happened to like the editor, then just go to the extension tab (the cubicles on the left middle) and type in "Git Graph" and install

[image]

To use it, go to the Git control tab and press View Git Graph button

[image]

Comment: Sadly the main dev of this project at https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph seems to have gone awol.  The project has been dormant since mid 2021.  There is some attempt to move it forward (see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hansu.git-graph-2) but mhutchie put a line in the license that makes that action questionable.  This is an open issue with GitHub (Q1/23).  An Alternate may be a maturing project which some are considering - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=phil294.git-log--graph - Personally I hope mhutchie opens up the license.

Comment: suggestion: May be worth mentioning that all of vscode-git-graph git-graph-2 and (I assume) git-log--graph do far more than visualize.  They all fully integrate into VSCode's IDE and can be used to perform pretty much all the every day tasks you need right from the GUI. Leaving the CLI for the more unusual and complex tasks.  Checkin/Checkout/Clone/Merge/Branch/Compare/Revert/Stash git-graph also supports sub-modules I don't know about git-log--graph.

Answer (score 18):

There is also [Tig](https://jonas.github.io/tig/). It doesn't fold branches like "BranchMaster", but...

It is fast, runs in the terminal.

Because it is so quick (+ keyboard control) you get a great UX. It is almost like my "`ls`" for directories containing Git repositories.

It has the usual shortcuts, `/` to search, etc.

[image: The revision graph]

(PS: It is the terminal in the background of this screenshot. It looks better nowadays, but my computer refuses to take a screenshot, sorry)

(PPS: I use [GitKraken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axosoft) as well, and it has really clear visualisations, but it's much heavier than Tig)

Comment: I'm a terminal lover and Tig(text-mode interface for Git) is good tool to interact with Git repositories, it is very useful including graph view and Git history. I recommend it to the terminal lovers as an extra tool to the Git command line.

Answer (score 18):

For Mac users, check out (no pun intended) the free, open source tool [GitUp](http://gitup.co/).

I like the way the graphs are displayed. It's clearer than some of the other tools I've seen.

The project is [at GitHub](https://github.com/git-up/GitUp).

[image: GitUp screenshot]

Comment: This is the only graph where you see the branches on the x axis and time on the y axis. It's very intuitive. GitUp is absolutely awesome! macOS isn't, any more, so I'm switching to Windows and will very sorely miss Gitup.

Comment: Great work. wow - Don't know what "Fixup with Parent" does. a tool tip for these would be great.

Answer (score 17):

[Giggle](http://live.gnome.org/giggle) draws really nice graphs.

Comment: So does [Grittle](https://github.com/NewAlexandria/grittle), if you use [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnigraffle/)

Comment: Tried it and I see a line per commit and not a line per branch/tag. It's too detailed when you have dozens of branches/tags.

Answer (score 15):

[TortoiseGit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/Download) has a tool called "Revision Graph". If you're on Windows it's as easy as right clicking on your repository → *Tortoise Git* → *Revision Graph*.

Comment: what a fantastic feature, using tortoise git for a long time but do not know this feature.

Answer (score 12):

I use the following aliases.

```
[alias]
    lol = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
    lola = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
```

It has more info in the color scheme than aliases that I saw above.  It also seems to be quite common, so you might have a chance of it existing in other's environment or being able to mention it in conversation without having to explain it.

With screenshots and a full description in *[Git lola](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html)*.

Answer (score 12):

For those using the [VSCode text editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/), consider the [Git History Extension](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode) by D. Jayamanne:

[image]

Comment: this extension is kinda slow in my opinion. It also does not auto update and looks unpolished. But it does a good job visualizing the commit tree...

Comment: Another extension for Visual Studio Code is [Git Graph](https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph) by mhutchie.  I use this along with GitLens.

Answer (score 11):

I have this `git log` alias in `~/.gitconfig` to view the graph history:

```
[alias]
l = log --all --graph --pretty=format:'%C(auto)%h%C(auto)%d %s %C(dim white)(%aN, %ar)'
```

With the alias in place, `git l` will show something like this:

[image]

In Git [2.12](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.12.0.txt)+ you can even customize the line colors of the graph using the [`log.graphColors`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) configuration option.

As for the logs' format, it's similar to [`--oneline`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---oneline), with the addition of the **author name** (respecting `.mailmap`) and the **relative author date**. Note that the `%C(auto)` syntax, which tells Git to use the default colors for commit hash, etc. is supported in Git >= [1.8.3](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt).

Comment: It's the very first time i see the realtive author date and it's pretty nice! thanks, i will add that to my gitconfig to!

Comment: windows users should replace single quotes with double quotes

Answer (score 10):

Another git log command. This one with **fixed-width columns**:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:"%x09%h | %<(10,trunc)%cd |%<(25,trunc)%d | %s" --date=short
```

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Gitx is also a fantastic visualization tool if you happen to be on OS X.

Comment: gitk (for everyone) is very similar. not exactly the same, but pretty similar.

Comment: There are a couple of forks of Gitx - [this one](http://rowanj.github.io/gitx/) (rowanj) seems to be the best at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [`SmartGit`](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). It very much reminds me of the [TortoiseHg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseHg) branch visualization and it's free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 7):

My personal favorite alias, via `.gitconfig`, is:

```
graph = log --graph --color --all --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%H%C(green)%d%C(reset)%n%x20%cd%n%x20%cn%x20(%ce)%n%x20%s%n"
```

You can test directly from the command line like this:

```
git log --graph --color --all --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%H%C(green)%d%C(reset)%n%x20%cd%n%x20%cn%x20(%ce)%n%x20%s%n"
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: A little explanation what command will looks like would have been great.

Answer (score 7):

I found it incredible that among the many answers it is not mentioned [Gitviz](https://github.com/Readify/GitViz), available for Window/Linux/Mac
In addition to providing a 2-D view of the branches and commit, it listens your git commands and it modify by itself the graph.

[image]

Comment: I think is only for windows, can you please share links for Mac/Linux ?

Comment: It is .net, so in theory you could run it using mono on Linux (maybe mono works on Mac too?)
But this is probably why not many mention it: From Gitviz GitHub:

Release Quality
**Alpha**. This entire project so far consists of one Readify guy sitting down the back of a training course and tapping away for a few hours, no more.

Answer (score 5):

I want to share my `compact` preset for `git log` command:
<sup>(green is my default console color)</sup>
[image: Preset preview]

It's designed to be as compact and table-like as possible (without adding any excess spaces) while still being informative and easy to read. This is basically a compact version of `medium` format Git uses by default.

Features:

- Fixed item positions;
- Default colors of commit hash and ref names;
- Commit author date is in local time zone;
- Commit message is wrapped at 128 characters and indented;
- Extended commit message is also shown (if any) with any trailing newlines removed.

---

You can add it into your config file using these commands:
<sup>(note that they will change the date format for *all* `git log` formats!)</sup>

```sh
$ git config --global log.date 'format-local:%d %b %Y %H:%M'
$ git config --global pretty.compact '%C(auto)%h %C(cyan)%<(17,trunc)%an%C(auto) %D%n        %C(cyan)%ad%C(auto) %w(128,0,26)%s%w(0,0,26)%+b%-(trailers:key=FAKE)'
```

... and then use it like so (with `--graph`, `--all` or any other options):

```
$ git log --graph --pretty=compact
```

If you'd also like to make it default you can do so with this command:

```
$ git config --global format.pretty compact
```

Or if you like aliases:

```sh
$ git config --global alias.logc "log --date=format-local:'%d %b %Y %H:%M' --pretty='%C(auto)%h %C(cyan)%<(17,trunc)%an%C(auto) %D%n        %C(cyan)%ad%C(auto) %w(128,0,26)%s%w(0,0,26)%+b%-(trailers:key=FAKE)'"
```

If you'd like to make any changes, see the [PRETTY FORMATS section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) of `git log` reference.

Comment: This answer has taught me a lot about fancy formatting capabilities. For example `%+b`. I was going to ask you about what `%-(trailers:key=FAKE)` does but it is clarified near the end of the pretty formats section in the documentation, you can search for `after % of a placeholder`. Not really sure what a FAKE trailer is though. Maybe you could help me out by explaining that.

Comment: Hi, @StevenLu. This part is a bit of a hack.
As you've seems to already figured out, the `%-` prefix is used to remove any trailing newlines here. But the problem is, it only does so "if the placeholder expands to an empty string". I was searching for a placeholder that would _always_ expand to an empty string and the trailers with a non-existent key seems to be the only one.

Answer (score 5):

## Git built-in tools (no add-ons) with date-time formatting

Because the docs are a little obtuse on using the built-in formatting, here's two more example aliases that will work right out of the box.

#### `git tree` – Timestamped log of all commits

```yaml
# Tools for analyzing the merge history of a repo using tree-like graphics
[alias]
    tree = log --no-show-signature --graph --date=format-local:%H:%M:%S --all \
        --pretty="'%C(#ffe97b ul)%h%C(reset) %C(#568ea6)%cs %C(#305f72)%cd%C(reset)%C(auto)%d%C(reset) %s %C(yellow)(%C(reset)%C(#1abc9c)%an%C(reset)%C(yellow),%C(reset) %C(#007055)%cr%C(reset)%C(yellow))%C(reset)'"
```

[image: git tree]

#### `git tree.branches` – Timestamped log of all branch/tag commits

```yaml
# Some refinements to normal 'git tree' output for alternative perspectives.
[alias "tree"]
    branches = tree --simplify-by-decoration
```

[image: git tree.branches]

### Color code

| Spec | Color | Style |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Commit ID** | Yellow | Underline |
| **Commit date** | Dark Blue |  |
| **Commit time** | Light Blue |  |
| **Commit message** | White |  |
| **Commit Author** | Green |  |
| **Commit relative date** | Dark Green |  |
| **Remote branches** | Red |  |
| **Local branches** | Purple |  |
| **Tags** | Pink | Underline |

Comment: _"None of the existing answers show how to change the date-time format using the built-in `git log` tooling"_ – Well, [my answer](/a/67289484/11725753) does, [two](/q/1838873/11725753#11594406:~:text='-,--date=short&text=--date=short,-git) [other](/q/1838873/11725753#31459695:~:text="-,--date=short) answers use a preset and [another one](/q/1838873/11725753#34467298:~:text=%25aD,-%25C%28reset&text=%25cD,-%29) uses the `%aD`/`%cD` placeholders.
Nevertheless, you have a nice example of using different colors for date and time here. ;-)

Comment: @EvgenKo423 Rescanning the thread, yeah, I have no idea why I said that! My apologies. Removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The most rated answers are showing `git log` commands as favorite solutions.

[image]

If you need a **table-like**, say column-like output, you can use your awesome `git log` commands with slight modifications and the *.gitconfig* **alias.table** snippet below.

**Modifications:**

In your format part of your log alias, each commit placeholder that should lead to a column needs a width limit

`%<>(N,ltrunc,mtrunc,trunc)%CommitPlaceholder`

where in `%<>(N,ltrunc,mtrunc,trunc)`

- `N` sets the column width to N characters, with N >= 2
- `<>` place it on the < - left, <> - middle or > - right
- `ltrunc,mtrunc,trunc` truncate longer contents from the ltrunc - left, mtrunc - middle or trunc - right

and is optional for every last commit placeholder of a format line or every commit placeholder that always expands to the same length.

To recognize your format part in the snippet below, `format:''` must be used and nowhere else in your Git log alias.

**Example:**

`log --all --graph --color --pretty=format:'%Cblue%h %Cgreen%cr %Creset%s' -10`

becomes

`log --all --graph --color --pretty=format:'%Cblue%<(7,trunc)%h %Cgreen%<(15,trunc)%cr %Creset%s' -10`

where

- `%<(7,trunc)` is optional as every abbrev commit `%h` has length 7
- `%s` is the last commit placeholder of the format line

**Explanation:**

The key point is to count the tree characters. The resulting tree length is then appended to the beginning of each format line in a special format.

**Snippet:**
Add this bash snippet that only uses the external commands `wc` and of course `git` to your .gitconfig.

```
[color "decorate"]
    HEAD   = blink bold italic 196
    branch = 214
    tag    = bold 222

[alias]
    # change alias names to give them a more meaningfull name or add your own versions here
    tlog0 = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) %C(bold green)%<(15,trunc)%ar%C(reset) %C(dim white)%<(22,trunc)%an%C(auto)%<(15,trunc)%d %C(white)%s%C(reset)' --all
    tlog1 = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%<(31,trunc)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%<(22,trunc)%ar)%C(reset)%C(auto)%d%C(reset)%n%<(10,trunc)%x20%C(white)%s%C(reset)%n%<(10,trunc)%x20%C(dim white)%<(31,trunc)%an %ae%C(reset)'
    tlog2 = log --all --color --date='format:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --decorate=short --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold dim white)%ad%C(reset) %C(bold dim cyan)%<(20,trunc)%an%C(reset) %C(bold cyan)%h%C(reset)%C(auto)%d%C(reset)%n%C(dim white)%<(19,trunc)%ar%C(reset) %C(dim cyan)%<(20,trunc)%ae%C(reset) %C(bold white)Commit:%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset)%n'

    table = !bash -c '" \
            alias=$1; \
            apost=$(echo -e \"\\u0027\"); \
            shift; \
            log_cmd=\"$(git config alias.$alias) $@\"; \
            [[ \"$log_cmd\" == \" $@\" ]] && { git $alias $@; exit; }; \
            \
            \
            log_fst_prt=\"${log_cmd%%\"format:$apost\"*}format:\"; \
            log_tre_prt=\"${log_cmd#\"$log_fst_prt$apost\"}\"; \
            log_tre_prt=\"${log_tre_prt%%$apost*}\"; \
            log_lst_prt=\"${log_cmd#\"$log_fst_prt$apost$log_tre_prt$apost\"}\"; \
            log_cmd_tre=\"${log_fst_prt}$apost%x20$apost${log_lst_prt}\"; \
            \
            \
            for opt_dis in \"--color\" \"--stat\";do \
              log_cmd_tre=\"${log_cmd_tre//\" $opt_dis\"}\"; \
            done; \
            tre_width=$(eval git \"${log_cmd_tre}\" | wc -L); \
            \
            \
            i=0; \
            log_tre_new=; \
            while IFS= read -r line;do \
              ((i++)); \
              if [[ $i -eq 1 ]];then \
                log_tre_new+=\"%<|($tre_width,trunc)%x20${line}\"; \
              else \
                log_tre_new+=\"%n%<|($(($tre_width-1)),trunc)%x20${line}\"; \
              fi; \
            done <<< \"$(echo -e \"${log_tre_prt//\\%n/\\\\n}\")\"; \
            [[ \"${log_tre_prt%\"%n\"}\" != \"$log_tre_prt\" ]] && log_tre_new+=\"%n\"; \
            \
            \
            log_cmd=\"${log_fst_prt}${apost}${log_tre_new}${apost}${log_lst_prt}\"; \
            eval git \"$log_cmd\"; \
            "' "git-table"
```

where the

- first section loads your alias and your optional parameters into variables
- second prepares your alias for counting
- third disables some options for counting and counts the tree length
- fourth adds the tree length in an appropriate format to any format line
- fifth calls Git with your prepared table-like alias

This is more or less only a part of my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61487052/8006273 where you can find deeper explanations, but nicely fits to this question here too.

[image]

[image]

If there are problems with your `git log` commands, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows there is a very useful tool you can use: [Git Extensions](http://gitextensions.github.io). It's a GUI tool and makes Git operations very easy.

Also it's open sourced.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried `--simplify-by-decoration` but all my merges are not shown.  So I instead just prune off lines with no "\" and "/" symbols at the headers, while always keeping lines with "(" indicating branches immediately after that.  When showing branch history I'm in general uninterested in commit comments, so I remove them too.  I end up with the following shell alias.

```
gbh () { 
    git log --graph --oneline --decorate "$@" | grep '^[^0-9a-f]*[\\/][^0-9a-f]*\( [0-9a-f]\|$\)\|^[^0-9a-f]*[0-9a-f]*\ (' | sed -e 's/).*/)/'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Git's official site enlisted some third-party platform specific GUI tools. Open *[Git GUI Tools for Linux Platform](https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux)*.

I have used `gitg` and [GitKraken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axosoft) for the Linux platform. Both are good for understanding the commit tree.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you that work in [VIM](https://www.vim.org/) anyway, [gv.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/gv.vim) may be interesting. That's what I use directly from within VIM that also enables to conveniently browse through the commit history and check the specific changes.

This is the screenshot directly from [gv.vim's Github page](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/700826/12355378/8bbf0834-bbdf-11e5-9389-1aba7cd1fec1.png):

[image]

The specific style depends on the utilized color theme.