# Which git tool generated this tree view?

Tags: git

[image]

Just wondering which tool generated this git tree view? Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested because you want to use that tool again, or because you want to extract that tree from git as data, or because you want to generate similar graphics from arbitrary data?

Comment: @matt, I'm interested because this tree looks great compared to others I have seen. E.g. the one from gitk. Are there any tool on linux that provides just as good looking graphics?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/seeit.html), as suggested in other answers.  However, this graph is not an achievement of this tool only; such a view can be generated by many tools ([qgit](http://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/qgit/screenshots/72597.jpg), [tortoisegit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/Screenshots#Log_Dialog), [gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=history.png)), including [bare git itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git) output to console!

Comment: Thanks Pavel. I'm interested in a tool on linux that provides just as good graphics as gitx (assuming gitx only runs on MacOSX).

Comment: @grm, gitg also has cute round commit markers ^_^.   Added link to screenshots to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Can be any of gitk, gitextensions, tortoisegit, and many more.

Looks like gitx http://gitx.frim.nl/seeit.html

Comment: definitely not gitk, maybe gitx

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `git log --graph` to see the graphical view of commits, very similar to what is shown above in the picture, but from commandline, and without installing any additional software

Answer (score 1):

Yup it is gitx

http://gitx.frim.nl/seeit.html