# What does tree-ish mean in Git?

Tags: git, git-archive

I'm very confused about how to use `git archive`.

I have a git repository with folder  *Foo*, *Bar* and *Baz* at the top level.  I need to export folder **Foo** in a SVN-ish sort of way for quick test deployment.

I learned that I could use `git-archive` in an [SVN-ish export sort of way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039700/setting-up-a-project-directory-structure-for-git-repo-of-a-website).

But here's the thing, **The following works fine:**

```
git archive master | tar -x -C ~/destination
```

it results in *Foo*, *Bar*, *Baz* folders in the *destination* folder.

**However, the following will error out** with `fatal not a valid object name`:

```
git archive master/foo | tar -x -C ~/destination
```

#### The Documentation

Looking as the synopsis for the `git archive` program I see that it can take a `<tree-ish> [path]` as a parameter (synopsis summarized to relevant parts):

```
git archive <tree-ish> [path...]
```

**If** `master/foo` **is not** `tree-ish`**, then what is?**

Comment: `master:foo` is tree-ish, but you better use `master foo` as i `<tree-ish> <path>`.

Comment: I had interpreted <tree-ish> as and adjective of [path].  That's where I went wrong.  And all the examples I saw only used the <tree-ish> part of the command, so I had wrongly assumed they were using a '<tree-ish> path.  Oh semantics :)

Comment: Related: [What are commit-ish and tree-ish in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23303549/456814).

Comment: I have a problem with this question because the title asks about what tree-ish is in git but then it starts and seems to be mainly about some command. Furthermore, the accepted answer doesn't seem to address what the term tree-ish means exactly. Either the title of the question must change or the question must change. I suggest that the title is better adapted to what the question really cases about and what the accepted answer was. Or maybe changing the accepted answer to what the question title really is. Or the answer should address the question title.

Comment: @CharlieParker apparently the man pages for `git archive` command no longer refer to tree-ish, but when I asked this question they did.  And regarding the accepted answer; at the time no one else bothered to answer the question.  It was over two years later that another answer had was even posted.

Comment: @CharlieParker I just re-checked the man pages for `git archive` and they still refer to `<tree-ish>` as of Git version 1.9.3.  see `git help archive`.

Comment: `$ man gitglossary` has a short explanation. Do not confuse the git tree with the filesystem tree `[path...]`.

Comment: Online [gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddeftree-ishatree-ishalsotreeish): __tree-ish (also treeish)__  
A tree object or an object that can be recursively dereferenced to a tree object. Dereferencing a commit object yields the tree object corresponding to the revision's top directory. The following are all tree-ishes: a commit-ish, a tree object, a tag object that points to a tree object, a tag object that points to a tag object that points to a tree object, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are commit-ish and tree-ish in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303549/what-are-commit-ish-and-tree-ish-in-git)

Answer (score 217, accepted):

## The Short Answer (TL;DR)

"Tree-ish" is a term that refers to any identifier (as specified in [the Git
revisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions)) that ultimately leads to a (sub)directory
tree (Git refers to directories as "trees" and "tree objects").

In the original poster's case, `foo` ***is a directory*** that he wants to
specify. The correct way to specify a (sub)directory in Git is to use this
"tree-ish" syntax (item #15 from [the Git revisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions)):

> `<rev>:<path>`, e.g. `HEAD:README`, `:README`, `master:./README`
>
> A suffix `:` followed by a path names the blob or tree at the given path in
>   the tree-ish object named by the part before the colon.

So, in other words, `master:foo` is the correct syntax, not `master/foo`.

### Other "Tree-ish" (Plus Commit-ish)

Here's a complete list of commit-ish and tree-ish identifiers (from [the Git
revisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions), [thanks to LopSae for pointing it
out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754113/456814)):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Commit-ish/Tree-ish    |                Examples
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1. <sha1>                | dae86e1950b1277e545cee180551750029cfe735
|  2. <describeOutput>      | v1.7.4.2-679-g3bee7fb
|  3. <refname>             | master, heads/master, refs/heads/master
|  4. <refname>@{<date>}    | master@{yesterday}, HEAD@{5 minutes ago}
|  5. <refname>@{<n>}       | master@{1}
|  6. @{<n>}                | @{1}
|  7. @{-<n>}               | @{-1}
|  8. <refname>@{upstream}  | master@{upstream}, @{u}
|  9. <rev>^                | HEAD^, v1.5.1^0
| 10. <rev>~<n>             | master~3
| 11. <rev>^{<type>}        | v0.99.8^{commit}
| 12. <rev>^{}              | v0.99.8^{}
| 13. <rev>^{/<text>}       | HEAD^{/fix nasty bug}
| 14. :/<text>              | :/fix nasty bug
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|       Tree-ish only       |                Examples
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 15. <rev>:<path>          | HEAD:README, :README, master:./README
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|         Tree-ish?         |                Examples
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 16. :<n>:<path>           | :0:README, :README
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Identifiers #1-14 are all "commit-ish", because they all lead to commits, but
because commits also point to directory trees, they all ultimately lead to
(sub)directory tree objects, and can therefore also be used as "tree-ish".

#15 can also be used as tree-ish when it refers to a (sub)directory, but it
can also be used to identify specific files. When it refers to files, I'm not
sure if it's still considered "tree-ish", or if acts more like "blob-ish" (Git
refers to files as "blobs").

## The Long Answer

At its lowest levels, Git keeps track of source code using four fundamental
objects:

1. Annotated tags, which point to commits.
2. Commits, which point to the root directory tree of your project.
3. Trees, which are directories and subdirectories.
4. Blobs, which are files.

Each of these objects has its own sha1 hash ID, since Linus Torvalds designed
Git like an [content- addressable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_storage) filesystem, i.e. files can be retrieved
based on their content (sha1 IDs are generated from file content). The Pro Git
book gives [this example diagram](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects):

[image: Figure 9-3 from Pro Git book]

Many Git commands can accept special identifiers for commits and (sub)directory
trees:

- "Commit-ish" are identifiers that ultimately lead to a commit object. For example,

  `tag -> commit`
- "Tree-ish" are identifiers that ultimately lead to tree (i.e. directory) objects.

  `tag -> commit -> project-root-directory`

Because commit objects always point to a directory tree object (the root
directory of your project), any identifier that is "commit-ish" is, by
definition, also "tree-ish". In other words, ***any identifier that leads to a
commit object can also be used to lead to a (sub)directory tree object***.

But since directory tree objects never point to commits in Git's versioning
system, not every identifier that points to a (sub)directory tree can also be
used to point to a commit. In other words, **the set of "commit-ish" identifiers
is a strict subset of the set of "tree-ish" identifiers.**

As explained in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_identifier_terminology) ([thanks to Trebor for helping
me find it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16042171/456814)):

> ```
> <tree>
> ```
>
> Indicates a tree object name.
>
> ```
> <commit>
> ```
>
> Indicates a commit object name.
>
> ```
> <tree-ish>
> ```
>
> Indicates a tree, commit or tag object name. A command that takes a `<tree-ish>`
>   argument ultimately wants to operate on a `<tree>` object but automatically
>   dereferences `<commit>` and `<tag>` objects that point at a `<tree>`.
>
> ```
> <commit-ish>
> ```
>
> Indicates a commit or tag object name. A command that takes a `<commit-ish>`
>   argument ultimately wants to operate on a `<commit>` object but automatically
>   dereferences `<tag>` objects that point at a `<commit>`.

The set of tree-ish identifiers that ***cannot be used as commit-ish*** are

1. `<rev>:<path>`, which leads ***directly*** to directory trees, not commit
   objects. For example, `HEAD:subdirectory`.
2. Sha1 identifiers of ***directory tree*** objects.

Comment: What about entry 16 on your table? Does it mean you're not sure if it's a tree-ish or not? The 0 refers to the merge state, and this concept applies only to blobs, since the index doesn't even contain directories. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25806452/895245 . So the question then comes down to: are all blob-ishes also tree-ishes? As far as I can tell yes: all man pages that use `<tree-ish>` accept both, and `man gitrevisions` defines: `trees ("directories of files")`.

Comment: Note that `git-archive` says it takes a `<tree-ish>` but it disallows a `<sha1>`. So I guess it should instead ask for a `<tree-ish-ish>`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12073669/680464

Comment: However I wonder about what happens when I use <rev>:  (without any path?. It works as tried - but I cannot find relevant section in documentation.

Answer (score 61):

A tree-ish is a way of naming a specific tree which can be one of the following:

- References like:

  - HEAD
  - Tags
  - Branch names
  - Branch names with remotes, like `origin/somebranch`
- Hash
- Short hashes

On top of that, any of the above can be appended with `^`, `~`. References can also use the `@{}` notation for some additional features:

- `HEAD^` or `HEAD^1` will be resolved to the first parent of HEAD.
- `HEAD^2` will resolve to the second parent
- `HEAD^3` will resolve to the third parent and so on, which is more rare and product of  [merges with the octopus strategy](http://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies).
- `HEAD~` or `HEAD~1` will resolve to the first parent of head
- `HEAD~2` will resolve to the first parent of the first parent of HEAD. This would be the same as `HEAD^^`
- `HEAD@{0}` will resolve to the current HEAD
- `HEAD@{1}` will resolve to the previous head. This can only be used by references since it makes use of the reference log. In the case of `HEAD` every commit, merge, checkout will change the value of HEAD and thus add it to the log. `git reflog HEAD` will display the reference log where you can see all the movements of HEAD and properly what `@{1}` and so on will resolve to.

Most of the above can be further combined as long as it makes sense in your repository, for example: `HEAD@{2}~3`, `somebranch^2~4`, `c00e66e~4^2`, `anotherbranch~^~^~^`.

So any of the described above, and its combinations, is what is meant in the documentation as a tree-ish, which is just a way to say what tree (or revision) is the one that should be used for most of git commands.

More info in [Revision Selection in the Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection).

Comment: This answer explains revisions (commit-ishes) in general and misses the crucial case: `master:path/to/directory`, which is a tree-ish but not a commit-ish. Cupcake's makes that clearer.

Answer (score 11):

You probably want

```
git archive master foo | tar -x -C ~/destination
```

The expression `master/foo` does not make sense: `master` is a branch name and `foo` is a directory name, as I presume.

**Edit**: (Removed broken link.  See comments.)

Comment: The word "tree" is no-longer found on your "Git Treeishes" link.  FYI

Comment: Treeish generally refers to the revision tree, not to a directory layout.

Comment: @JürgenStrobel: That's not true. It referred to neither of the two – in past tense, because the term isn't used any more in the current version of the documentation. (That's also why the link is broken.) Formerly, a *treeish* referred to something that could be resolved to a tree object in git's object store.  This inlcuded any commit specification, since each commit refers to a single tree object.  The tree object contains information about the directory tree of this commit – see the [section on git objects in "Pro Git"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) for details.

Answer (score 7):

For definitions of `<tree-ish>` and `<commit-ish>` see the [git(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) man page. You'll have to search for the terms. In general `<tree-ish>` means a reference to a git tree object, but if you pass a type of object that references a tree (such as a commit or branch), git will automatically use the referenced tree.

Comment: And `gitrevisions(7)`.

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie to source control and git. This is what I know. A tree is the structure of files in a repository. Its similar to a directory in a file system.See -
[Which git tool generated this tree view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509776/which-git-tool-generated-this-tree-view)

Tree-ish means like a tree. It references a part or commit of a tree. You can reference a commit using any one of these: full or part of the SHA-1 hash of a commit, HEAD pointer, branch reference, tag reference. Another method uses any of the mentioned methods along with ancestors or parents of a commit. Ancestors example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [Git Glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddeftree-ishatree-ishalsotreeish) tree-ish is 
"A tree object or an object that can be recursively dereferenced to a tree object."
commit, HEAD and tag are examples of tree-ish objects.