# Can a file added to the index be retrieved?

Tags: git

As I read through as many sources on how to use git, I haven't come across any article which suggests when you can rollback should the need arise. So for example I have initialized a git directory in my working directory i.e. `git init`

I then add files to git's index i.e. `git add .`. This has added all files to git's index. Now rather than committing the files to git's repository i.e. `git commit`, I make a change to one of the files I added to the index. I realize I made a mistake. Can I rollback to the previous state or is this only possible when I have committed the file? My understanding is that when I run the command `git add .` a copy of the file or files is made in git's object store. I believe the files in the object store are compressed. Does this mean I can rollback from the object store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Try

```
git checkout-index -f foo
```

to checkout `foo` from index. Or checkout all files by

```
git checkout-index -fa
```

Comment: Is `foo` the file I added to the index? What happens when I checkout the file? Does it overwrite my changes? Does it merge them?

Comment: Yes. It will overwrite the file in working directory, not merge.

Comment: It will overrite them. The `-f` is meant to force the operation in case a file already exists.

Comment: But really, I think just `git checkout -- foo` is a better way. I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
git checkout -- <file>
```

to discard changes in working directory while keeping changes to index.

Comment: Is `<file>` the name of the file I added to the index?

Answer (score 1):

Using `git checkout` without specifying a tree-ish will checkout from the index.

Comment: Sorry for being a n00b. What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Usually you use `git checkout <treeish>` to checkout a branch, tag, HEAD, or a specific commit. If you dont use that parameter the checked out content will come from the index. For what is a treeish check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044368/what-does-tree-ish-mean-in-git

Answer (score 1):

I got intrigued by the question and the answer appears to be "yes", git add puts a copy of the file in the repository and you can rollback the file even if no commit has been made in the repository, tested with the following example.

```
% mkdir test && cd test
% git init .
% echo "1" > test.txt
% git add test.txt
  - git status shows now "added" file
% echo "2" > test.txt
  - git status shows "added" and "modified" file, test.txt contains number 2
% git checkout test.txt
  - git status shows only "added" again, and test.txt contains the number 1
```