# Remove some commits from the beginning setting a new root

Tags: git, commit

I've worked on a new project in the last months and want to make it public on GitHub in the next days. I will therefore create a new repository. The current private Git repository contains about 400 commits and I want to throw away about the first 20 commits and define a new root.

If my commit history looks like the following:

A - B - C - D - E - F

The new repository should look like this afterwards:

D - E - F

I've already searched for days for a solution but didn't find one. I'm not sure whether it is so obvious or if I just don't get it. Is that possible? And how?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Im working with git for few years now.

As far as i know (and if i'm wrong i'll be more than happy to learn something new),
you **can't** do it since git commit have reference to the parent (commitId) 
so if you want to delete the first X commits the next commits
 (git commit only changes = changesets,treeish [[What does tree-ish mean in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044368/what-does-tree-ish-mean-in-git]))
you will lose the reference to the previous commit (in your case d will be detached from C)