# What happens to a modified file when using "git checkout"?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-checkout

I was simply trying out a few things on a project and wanted to delete some modified files I was working with but no longer needed.

I got careless and typed `git checkout file` instead of `git checkout -- file`. So essentially I was just checking out this modified file and I have no clue where that modified file went off to.

I've tried using `git update-index --fresh` just to try and see where this modified file could have gone but it seems like it may have been deleted in the end?

```
    modified:   test/ssc_test/cmod_tcsdirect_steam_test.cpp
    modified:   test/ssc_test/cmod_tcsfresnel_molten_salt_test.cpp
    modified:   test/ssc_test/cmod_tcsmolten_salt_test.cpp
```

These were the files I was trying to get rid of but forgot to add the `--` to get rid of one of the edited files.

After checking out this file, instead of deleting it, it gave me the message, `Updated 1 path from the index` and it was no longer displayed along with the other modified files when using `git status`.

I'm pretty clueless with what happened exactly. Was it was deleted or hidden somewhere in the index, or something else?

Comment: Did you have any another branches cloned ?

Comment: `git checkout X`, for any X without the `--` in front, first tries to treat `X` as a *branch name*. If that works, you just did a checkout of that branch (and `git status` will tell you that you are `on branch X` now). If that *doesn't* work, Git tries to treat `X` as a commit hash ID: does `git rev-parse X^{commit}` succeed? If so, you did a checkout of that commit, and `git status` will say "detached HEAD". If not, the last resort is to act as if you ran `git checkout -- X`: try `X` as a file name. So you probably did the same as `git checkout -- file`.

Comment: Note that `git status` won't *list* a file if it's in the index now and is *the same* as the copy in the `HEAD` commit *and* the same as the copy in the work-tree. That's when-and-why `git checkout -- X` makes file `X` drop out of the `git status` listing: Git replaced the work-tree `X` with the index version of `X`, and if the index version of `X` matches the `HEAD` version of `X`, all three copies now match.

Comment: Why do you keep talking about “delete”? Checkout does not delete anything.

Answer (score 10):

> I got careless and typed 'git checkout file' instead of 'git checkout -- file'

Those commands do the same thing, unless for some reason teh actual name of `file` could be confused with a non-path argument to `checkout`.

Or to say that differently - the only thing `--` does is to separate paths from other options in case it's ambiguous

Comment: I got careless too :)

Comment: Okay but what's the solution to revert this accidental command?

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid any ambiguity between branch and file, you can use the new [`git restore` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore). See [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore).
It is available with Git 2.23, still experimental for now.

```
git restore -- afile
```

It will restore working tree *files* from any source you want.
By default, HEAD, but you can specify [any treeish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18605496/6309) you want.

Using or not `--` won't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Git will set the file to the working head/[index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203).

To test and illustrate:

```sh
mkdir test
cd test
git init
touch testfile
git add --all
git commit -m "Commit"
echo hi > testfile
cat testfile # hi
git checkout testfile
# Testfile is now empty
```

Comment: Okay but how can this be undone?