# How to git ls-tree from a commit object?

Tags: linux, git, internals

From documentation, in order to use `git ls-tree` you need to pass the hash of a tree object. What if I want to obtain the same output of `git ls-tree` starting from a commit object.
I can obviously do it with something like this:

```
git ls-tree $(git cat-file -p my_commit | grep -oP "(?<=tree ).*")
```

But I feel like I am reinventing the wheel. Is there a git command that already does this?

Comment: "*…in order to use git ls-tree you need to pass the hash of a tree object…*" Wrong, any commit or a pointer to a commit is ok. `@`, `HEAD`, `master^2~`, any branch or tag…

Comment: Thank you @phd, I even tried with a commit hash on git, but I clearly made a mistake somehow. I completely misunderstood the "tree-ish" the doc refers too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `git ls-tree` takes a [*tree-ish* object](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree).

The "-ish" suffix here is important.  Per the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ish):

> -ish suffix (QUITE)
>
> used to form adjectives to give the meaning to some degree; fairly:
>
> - He had a sort of reddish beard.
> - She was oldish - about 60, I'd say.
> - We'll start at sevenish (= about seven o'clock).

In this case, "tree-ish" means *like a tree*.  A tree, of course, is *like a tree*.  But a *commit* is also *like a tree* since it has exactly one tree component; that means that you can unambiguously refer to that tree by simply using the commit itself.

So, just do `git ls-tree <commit-ish>`.

Comment: Thank you @EdwardThomson for the dictionary reference and the explanation (yes, I am not english), but I think that saying "a commit is also like a tree since it has exactly one tree component and that tree can be **identified** by simply using the commit itself." is a mistake: a tree can belong to many commits.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044368/what-does-tree-ish-mean-in-git#answer-18605496) definition would be more correct: *"Tree-ish" is a term that refers to any identifier [...] that ultimately leads to a (sub)directory tree*.

Comment: That a commit has a single tree does not imply that a tree cannot be part of multiple commits.

Comment: (Or even part of other trees.)

Comment: Yes exactly, we are saying the same thing I guess. I simply did not like that "identified", but now I get what you meant. Basically since a commit has a single root tree, that -ish refers to the fact that there is no ambiguity in using a commit hash.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say.  I like the way that you've phrased that a lot.  I'll update my answer.