# Showing Git branch structure

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Is there a way to show only the branch structure in Git? There are a number of tools that show the commits graphically, but in my case the list is so long that it's impossible to see the structure. I guess git-log could be the answer, but I can't find any switches that only show the branching commits. This along with "--graph --branches --oneline --all" could do the trick.

EDIT: I'm looking for a way to do this in Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty git branch graphs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs)

Comment: Here's [a list of them from Git's official website](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis/) and [a list of them from Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Git_GUIs) that may be of help. I suggest you to use [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) to get such images. [![GitKraken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNp6k.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNp6k.png)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I am not sure about what you mean by "branch structure".
`git log` can help visualize the branches made through commits (See this [blog post](http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/pimping-out-git-log)):

```
[alias]
    lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative

git config --global alias.lg "log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative"
```

[image]

But if you only wants the different HEAD branches, you could try [something along the lines of](http://gist.github.com/492227):

```
heads = !"git log origin/master.. --format='%Cred%h%Creset;%C(yellow)%an%Creset;%H;%Cblue%f%Creset' | git name-rev --stdin --always --name-only | column -t -s';'"
```

(using the [`column command`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_column.htm), and here only for commits since the last `origin/master` commit)

Note: [Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski) recommands adding the option  **`--simplify-by-decoration`**, see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666953/showing-git-branch-structure/3681149#3681149).

Comment: This was pretty close (the latter solution), I just had to add the date  and --branch to the command. Otherwise it only shows the current branch. Although it still doesn't leave out commits that are not the head. What I meant by "branch structure" is a way to see from what branch each branch is created, but with this command I can scroll through the list (which has about 350 commits) to see what has been going on.

Comment: @Makis: if you have a final command, you can post it as an answer: I am interested (and will vote it up). Then, you can even accept your own answer as the official one if you want.

Comment: I'm still looking into it, I'll be back at the office tomorrow to try to make sense of the structure. The repo was created with svn2git and I'm not 100% sure the svn repo was by the book either.

Comment: @Makis: Try `--simplify-by-decoration` option to git-log.

Comment: This does the trick, thanks! Thanks for everyone else for your suggestions as well!

Answer (score 35):

Perhaps what you want is `--simplify-by-decoration` option, see [git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) documentation:

> *--simplify-by-decoration*
>
> Commits that are referred by some branch or tag are selected.

So it would be

```
git log --graph --simplify-by-decoration --all
```

or following [VonC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666953/showing-git-branch-structure/3667139#3667139)

```
git log --graph --simplify-by-decoration \
   --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset-%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' \
   --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

Comment: Excellent, I had missed that particular option. +1

Comment: @VonC: This is quite new option; it appeared in git version 1.6.1

Comment: 1.6.1? http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=tags : Thu, 25 Dec 2008, seems a lifetime away to me ;)

Comment: This is pretty close, but it misses commits that are common ancestors to multiple branches but that are not named as branches or tags.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe I'm missing something, but nobody seems to have mentioned `gitk --all` yet.

Comment: I've just tried `gitk --all --simplify-by-decoration` and that works quite well. (That was with the gitk supplied with git 1.7.9.5)

Answer (score 6):

Basic solution is:

```
git log --graph --all
```

If you want to get more fancy:

```
git log --graph --all --pretty=format:"%Cblue%h%Creset [%Cgreen%ar%Creset] %s%C(yellow)%d%Creset"
```

Answer (score 3):

[gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/) if you are on a macOS

[smartgit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) for macOS or Windows (but i have not used it)

[git-gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) to use the native git gui (cross-platform)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I use Ubuntu.

Comment: git-gui (you mean gitk, right?) doesn't work for me - 1. it only shows branches you checkout, I wan the entire tree. 2. It shows all the commits, I'm interested just in the branch structure.

Comment: @ripper234 you can use `gitk -a` to show all branches

Answer (score 2):

To get more information on how a particular branch relates to other branches in your repository and remotes, you can use `git wtf` which is an add on script by William Morgan: http://git-wt-commit.rubyforge.org/

It produces summary information like:

```
$ git wtf
Local branch: master
[x] in sync with remote
Remote branch: origin/master (git@gitorious.org:willgit/mainline.git)
[x] in sync with local

Feature branches:
{ } origin/experimental is NOT merged in (1 commit ahead)
    - some tweaks i'm playing around with [80e5da1]
{ } origin/dont-assume-origin is NOT merged in (1 commit ahead)
    - guess primary remote repo from git config instead of assuming "origin" [23c96f1]
```

(example taken from the above URL).