# How to display the tag name and branch name using git log --graph

Tags: git

I am using gitk --all to view the git log. gitk does not display the sha hash for each commit. you need to manually click on the commit to view the sha hash. I want to see the sha hash and the branch name in a single view.

How to display the tag-names and branch names using the git log command.

Comment: Note: if you need those branch names *without* parenthesis around, you now have the `%D` option (instead of `%d`), with Git 2.2 (Nov. 2014). See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

With `git log` (so, not gitk), you can use the decorate option (`%d`) in a pretty format, for displaying the branch name (but only for commits which are the HEAD of said branches):

```
alias.lgb=log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset%n' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --branches
```

(you have to declare that alias with:

```
git config --global alias.lgb "log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset%n' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --branches"
```

Then you can use it with '`git lgb`'. Note: you can name it with a different alias.
)

Will give:

```
* e33afe7 - (HEAD, master) fix zlib make install issue on cygwin (8 seconds ago) <VonC>
|
* f825f36 - add CPPFLAG option for cygwin compilation of gcc (26 hours ago) <VonC>
|
* 9341979 - (origin/master, origin/HEAD) update error messages for compiling gcc within cygwin (2 days ago) <VonC>
|
* 42d81af - copy dll in $H/usr/local/bin instead of linking when compiling in cygwin (3 days ago) <VonC>
```

---

Update Git 2.2 (November 2014): see [commit 9271095](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9271095cc5571e306d709ebf8eb7f0a388254d9d) from [Harry Jeffery (`eXeC64`)](https://github.com/eXeC64):

### `pretty`: add `%D` format specifier

> Add a new format specifier, '`%D`' that is identical in behaviour to '`%d`', except that it does not include the ' `(`' prefix or '`)`' suffix provided by '`%d`'.

Comment: I tried the command "git log alias.lgb=log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset%n' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --branches" which give s the error  "fatal: ambiguous argument 'alias.lgb=log': unknown revision or path not in the w
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions"

Comment: @Talespin: I have added the correct `git config` command to declare that git alias. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666953/showing-git-branch-structure/3667139#3667139 or http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/pimping-out-git-log

Comment: Thanks! added this to my dotfiles! https://github.com/chrisjlee/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitconfig

Comment: @chrisjlee good idea :) I like to complement that `git lg` command with some bash aliases: https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/bb0a9afb4195da083e77157d54cb626d1b9eaa1d/git/bash_aliases#L4-L7

Comment: This is my long time favorite alias, I can't up vote it enough. I also created a lg alias, dropping the --branches for when I only want to see the current branch... and lgbd with iso date instead of relative. Note that for this we need to change %Cgreen(%cr) to %Cgreen(%cd), otherwise the --date option is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it works on my pc

```
git log --format='here you put formats you need for your case is like %d contain branch name and %cn committer  name ' | grep -F 'origin'
```

this will list all branch names with committer names