# Shortcoming of git log? Why can't I see all the branches?

Tags: git, version-control, git-log, gitk

I have a branch in `git` and I am on that branch and not on `master` branch.
Using `git log --graph` I can only see linearly that I am on that branch. But I can not see that I have "splitted" from the `master` branch.
I.e.  I see:

```
* b  
*     
*    
*
```

Where `b` is the private branch I made and I was expecting to see:

```
*master  
* / *b  
*    
*  
*
```

But I do see this in `gitk`. Is it not possible to get an accurate graph of the tree via command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see the same as in gitk, you would need at least a:

```
git log --branches
```

A more complete equivalent would be a:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

I use a more complex alias in "[How to display the tag name and branch name using `git log --graph`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7023272/6309)".

Comment: If you have some time to spare, could you please check out this one as well? Thank you in advance! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155436/can-git-figure-out-that-the-branch-to-be-merged-has-obsolete-changes

Comment: @Cratylus I have always time for a Stack Overflow user.