# Can git figure out that the branch to be merged has obsolete changes?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-merge, git-rebase

I am new in `git` and I am find it hard to wrap my head around the fact that everything is around snapshots/commits and not individual files.
So assume that I have a tree in my repository as follows.

```
C4 (HEAD,Master,Origin/Master)  
*  
C3  
*  
C2  
*  
C1
```

Now I branch out from here:

```
B1 (HEAD, testBranch)  
*  
C4 (HEAD,Master,Origin/Master)  
*  
C3  
*  
C2  
*  
C1
```

In my `testBranch` I only modify 2 files of the whole repository. Just 2.
The development in `master` in the remote repository continues so eventually we have the following tree:

```
                    C8(Master,Origin/Master)   
                    *   
B3(testBranch)    C7   
  *              *   
  B2           C6  
    *         *
     B1    C5   
       *  
       C4  
       *  
       C3  
       *  
       C2  
       *  
       C1
```

Now I have finished working on the branch and want to merge to master. But the master has moved further ahead.
But the only difference between `B3` the latest of `testBranch` and `C8` the latest of `master` are the changes in the 2 files that I originally started to work on when I forked the branch. But additionally `testBranch` is "lest behind" the `master` branch since other modifications have occurred.
So what will happen if I merge `testBranch` to `master`?
Will `git` figure out that the only changes to merge are the 2 files I originally worked on?
Will I get conflicts? Should I not do a merge but a rebase? Why?

Comment: Try one of the git-branching [tutorials](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/) out there. These are some basic questions well-covered by the [resources](http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am find it hard to wrap my head around the fact that everything is around snapshots/commits and not individual files.

Did you used ClearCase before?
If yes, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771) for a difference between a file-centric VCS (here a [CVCS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705214/6309)) and a [DVCS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705286/6309) like git ([that I introduce here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7187252/6309)).

> So what will happen if I merge `testBranch` to `master`?
>   Will git figure out that the only changes to merge are the 2 files I originally worked on?

yes

> But how does git "understand" that the different code in the branch has been made obsolete by the code in master? Due to timestamps?

Due to the fact that **each commit knows its parent**: that allows to find a **common ancestor** commit between `B3` (merged to) `C8`: `C4`.

The merge operation know what has evolved since `C4`: only 2 files, and it will merge only those to `master`.

See also "[What makes merging in DVCS easy?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2614937/6309)".

> > The merge operation know what has evolved since `C4`: only 2 files, and it will merge only those to `master`.
>
> But `B1-C5` `B2-C6` are different.
>   E.g. a function in `C5` that exists in `B1` and `B2` could have been deleted.
>   I am not sure I understand how does it figure this out and it doesn't "reinclude" the function

It does figure out and *not* reintroduce that function because:

- that function existed in `C4` (common ancestor)
- that function existed in `B2` (so no change there on the source branch of the merge)
- that function no longer exist in `master` (but it is a change, a deletion here, which affects the *destination* branch of the merge)

A merge is about reporting and merging modifications from the source branch to the destination branch.
You are referring to a modification in the destination branch only, while the source branch has not evolved compared to the common ancestor:

- that function from `testBranch` will be ignored by the merge since there no modification  to report.
- that deleted function in `master` will be kept deleted by the merge, since the merge ignores said function from `testBranch` (for the reason I just mentioned in the previous point: no modification since the common ancestor)

> Will I get conflicts?

You could get a conflict if those two files have also changed in master (and if those changes occurred on common lines)

> Should I not do a merge but a rebase? Why?

A rebase would be better if you didn't pushed yes `testBranch`, and have other commits to do on it (but want to do them based on a up-to-date version of `master`)

Comment: But how does `git` "understand" that the different code in the branch has been made obsolete by the code in `master`? Due to timestamps? (BTW thank you so much for helping me out)

Comment: @Cratylus I have edited (again) the answer in order to add links to other interesting answer about git.

Comment: `The merge operation know what has evolved since C4: only 2 files, and it will merge only those to master.` But `B1-C5` `B2-C6` are different. E.g. a function in `C5` that exists in `B1` and `B2` could have been deleted.I am not sure I understand how does it figure this out and it doesn't "reinclude" the function

Comment: @Cratylus I have edited the answer (ter) to address your previous comment.

Comment: @Cratylus I "own" ClearCase: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/clearcase/topusers (and git too ;) http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/topusers)

Comment: How can you do this? I need to know your secret.

Comment: @Cratylus I do dev support for a living, so this is just basic daily training: https://plus.google.com/u/0/106661248019508703534/posts/EKVsiHK55cB, and https://plus.google.com/u/0/106661248019508703534/posts/B2i3GZjVru5

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish I could also help you out, but you are 50 years ahead of me... :)

Comment: @Cratylus but you are helping (you *and others*) with interesting questions on this topic :)