# Files not updating using 'git pull'

Tags: git, git-pull

I am using Git to cooperate with other users, but today I cannot get the latest change on some files using "`git pull`", and I cannot see the changes in "`git log`".

What could be the issue?

Comment: are you sure they pushed correctly their work?

Comment: It seems nothing is there to get the updates. Are you sure the files are committed correctly by other user and in the same repository? No Logs gives a doubt in this direction.

Comment: Are you sure you sub ordinates have pushed to the branch you are trying to pull ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue (I'm the only one at work with this issue).  It's driving me batty!  For the past few days I've been doing manual merges because pulls just aren't happening.  But the manual merge causes all sorts of warnings to go off, which scares the entire team.

Comment: What is your error message or what is your ouput of the git pull command?

Comment: This happened to me more than once in git. It's very weird. I've used hg for more then 15 years and it's never happened.

Comment: I have been visiting this page so ofthen that I added it to favorites list.

Answer (score 60):

what worked for me is ,

1. remove `.git` folder
2. copy `.git` from other repo
3. now `git checkout`

**Before Removing , You can try**

```
git fetch --all 
git reset --hard origin/master
```

You will need to replace `master` with the appropriate branch, which now defaults to `main`.

Comment: The last two steps (fetch and reset) worked for me. Btw, "copy .git from other repo" shouldn't work, as each .git contains info specific to the repo it belongs to.

Comment: ```git reset --hard origin/[my branch]``` worked for me. But can anyone explain why git pull just stopped working and that worked?

Answer (score 27):

What worked for me,

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

It showed me that some file names were too long for git to pull them from my repo and hence the mismatch and incorrect builds.

So I ran following to fix and did a hard reset again.

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Thankfully it worked.

Comment: wouldn't this have some consequences?

Comment: Like now we can name and push/pull files with long names? I dont think it would break anything and I am not sure if it came from any GIT or Java standards.

Answer (score 11):

In my case the issue was me having an `index.lock` file in my `.git` folder.  I removed that, and pull worked.

Comment: For some reason, Git doesn't mention this!

Comment: My `index.lock` file had 0 bytes, deleted it, and voila.

Comment: This has worked for me also

Answer (score 7):

Check your current branch.

```
git status
git branch
```

If you are not in a branch, you are in a [detached HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309) and `git pull` wouldn't merge anything.

```
git log --all --branches
```

That `git log` will help make sure you see if there are any new commits on fetched branches (that is, the [remote tracking branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070851/6309)).
I use that [git log alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7023272/6309) to display those commits as a graph.

Comment: Good thinking.  Cover the edge cases.

Answer (score 7):

You could have an unfinished merge that prevents the pull. Check if you have a commit in progress.

Comment: How do you check to see if there's a commit in progress?

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me:
Instead of

```bash
$ git pull
```

Use

```bash
$ git pull [remote] [local-branch>
```

Comment: it worked for me: `git pull origin master` it did work I guest my upstream setup was wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add another case where this could happen.  I was using a sparse checkout. For some reason I had a directory in my working tree that I thought was included in the sparse checkout (I thought it was listed in `.git/info/sparse-checkout`) but wasn't (I had removed it from `.git/info/sparse-checkout` for some reason I now forget.)  So it was just being ignored by `pull` or `checkout` or `reset` or any other commands.  It was very confusing until I started replicating the sparse checkout configuration in a new, fresh clone and realized the error.

This would only happen to you if you are using a sparse checkout.  If you are not using a sparse checkout, it couldn't happen. (Check git config to see if sparseCheckout is enabled, and check for the existence of .git/info/sparse-checkout, but you would know if you were doing this since I think it has to be set up manually by the user anyway.)  (Google it if you're curious what it is-- its just a simple mechanism to omit files and directories from a checkout that would otherwise be tracked/pulled/fetched etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with our enterprise Gitlab repo which recently changed from HTTPS to SSH. As  my repo still used HTTPS, any `git pull` got silently ignored.

After changing the origin to SSH, everything went smooth again.

```
git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.yourdomain.com:username/repo.git
```

(To get the SSH URL just click  the "Clone" button in your Gitlab/Github web interface and select "Clone with SSH")

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible sceanrios:
1. If you have any account in Bitbucket, gitlab and etc. 
You might have to synchronise with your fork directory first and then perform git pull on your local branch. Basically you have to rebase your fork copy to get in sync with remote master and perform git pull in your local copy.
2. Just try to rebase your local work copy to be in sync with remote master.

Comment: How do we rebase the local copy to sync with remote master?

Answer (score 0):

git reset --hard origin/master

works for me but you have to go inside the folder and then use this command not only on the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was commits that I made locally.
These commits modify something I want to pull.
So git pull doesn't get the file from origin

Answer (score 0):

For me the FETCH_HEAD file did not have all the branches, because my newest branch was not tracked
So I:

To force delete a branch (from outside that branch)

```
git branch -D <branch_name>
```

To create a new branch from a given branch

```
git fetch origin <remote_branch>:<local_branch>
```

To make the remote branch a tracking branch

```
git push --set-upstream origin <branch_name>
```

then to test it with `git fetch`, I noticed my FETCH_HEAD file was now correctly updated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the FETCH_HEAD was broken somehow.

When I checked it using `git branch -avv`, my branch was tracking the wrong commit. Even using a commit from months before.

I solved it using `git reset --hard [commit hash]`