# Set pretty format for git log only

Tags: git

I find the default pretty format to verbose, so I have made i more concise version with:

```
[format]
    pretty = %C(yellow)commit:   %h%Creset%C(auto)%d%C(reset)%nauthor:   %an <%ae>%ndate:     %ad%nsummary:  %s%n
```

which produces something like:

```
commit:   ab6cdf4 (HEAD -> master, tag: v1.1)
author:   author name <author@email.com>
date:     Fri Nov 15 22:00:00 2019 +0100
summary:  A very nice commit title
```

with the first line coloured a lot like usual.

However, this does not only affect `git log` but also `git show`, and for `git show` I would actually rather use the `medium` or `fuller` formats.

Is there any way of setting the format for `git log` only? Maybe through another option than `format.pretty`.

An obvious solution is to make an alias for a version of `log` or `show` using the *other* format, but I would rather avoid that, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Considering [`git config format.pretty`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-formatpretty) is *always* for [`git log` (configuration)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_configuration) *and* [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_pretty_formats), I have always defined an alias for git log.

For instance:

- "[How to display the tag name and branch name using `git log --graph`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7023272/6309)"
- "[Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/6309)"

So an alias in this case might still be the current recommended workaround.