# Relationship between n git branches

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

**If I have n git branches, how do I easily show the relationship between these branches?**

Basically I am interested in seeing a tree of a subset of all the branches in my repository. I am however not interested in all the intermediate commits.

E.g.: My repository looks like this:

```
     o---o--o A
    /      /
o--o--o--o--o--o B
 \  \        \
  \  o--o C   \
   \     \     \
    o--o--o--o--o--o D
```

But probably way more complicated. Now I want to see the relationship between branch A, C and D. Something along the lines of:

```
     o A
    /
o--o--o
   \   \
    o---o C
         \
          o--o D
```

Or an equivalent overview. Is this possible, and how? (A graphical tool will be just fine.)

**Solution**

Based on Antoine Pelisses answer, the below line seems to do (almost) exactly what I want:

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --simplify-by-decoration A B C
```

**Update**

Mark Longair points out in his answer below that `gitk` accepts the same parameters as `git rev-list`, so it is possible to do:

```
gitk --simplify-by-decoration A C D
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
git log --graph --all --decorate --simplify-by-decoration
```

It will only show commits that are branch heads or tagged.

Comment: This looks very good. Adding the `--oneline` helps me a bit. Now if I could only choose a subset of all my branches. :)

Comment: @bjarkef: You can - just change `--all` to `A C D`

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, obviously. :) `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --simplify-by-decoration A B C` seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: @bjarkef: indeed - I didn't know about `--simplify-by-decoration`, but it's very nice (+1)

Comment: @Dolphin: You will have to create an alias (check on this page: http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

Answer (score 20):

I would use:

```
gitk A C D
```

... there are probably other git GUIs that produce a prettier rendering of the commit graph, but I've always found `gitk` fine for this purpose.  All the branches and tags are labelled in the "London Underground"-style representation:

[image: A screenshot of gitk showing several merges and branches]
<sub>(source: [mark at mythic-beasts.com](http://mythic-beasts.com/~mark/gitk-screenshot.png))</sub>

---

You can also use the `--simplify-by-decoration` option to `gitk`, since it understands all of the parameters that `git rev-list` does, for example:

```
gitk --simplify-by-decoration A C D
```

[image: A screenshot of gitk with the --simplify-by-decoration option]

Comment: I also use gitk (and gitg) a lot. However, I have a case where I have around 5 branches, which each has several hundreds commits on them, and somewhere in between there are merges between these branches. Getting a overview of the merge history is very hard with gitk (or gitg).

Comment: Right.  I think if it's a case that's that complicated, I would probably just care about whether a particular branch has already been merge into another one and use command-line tools to explore that.  I think someone might have deleted a comment on your question that suggested using `git branch --contains C` for this purpose, which is indeed very helpful - it shows you all the branches that include the tip of the branch C (and so contain the complete history of branch C).

Comment: @bjarkef: just as an additional note, I should have pointed out that you can use the --simplify-by-decoration option with gitk as well - I've updated my answer with a mention of that.

Comment: That looks very useful, I will be sure to give it a try Monday. Thanks.