# How to get birds eye view of git tree with just branch names, not individual commits?

Tags: git, visualization

I like the ability of git to give me a visual tree showing how the commits flow on various branches, but with a lot of commits you may drown in detail.

I was wondering how I can just get the basic outline of the branch structure without all the individual commits, but with branch names put in the right locations anyway.

Much like `gitk --all .` but then zoomed a bit out.

Suggestions?

---

EDIT: 2013-03-16 - I have still not found a good solution to this.  I've found however that the history view in Git Extensions for some reason gives better information than the history view in Eclipse.

Comment: A bit similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666953/showing-git-branch-structure

Comment: Also a bit similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298972/relationship-between-n-git-branches

Comment: These similar questions are all pretty old, there may be more modern tools nowadays.

Answer (score 19):

Using a [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666953/showing-git-branch-structure/3681149#3681149) from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666953/showing-git-branch-structure/) [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) linked in the comments, the following should suffice:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph --simplify-by-decoration
```

Comment: This still gives me one line pr commit with the text.  I would like a bit more zoomed out, so there just are the lines without individual commits.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`--simplify-by-decoration`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-log.html#_history_simplification) option:

```
gitk --simplify-by-decoration --all
```

And if you are a CLI junkie, the same is possible in the console as well:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --simplify-by-decoration --all
```

```
* a6b4b080e4 (origin/next) Merge branch 'jk/plug-list-object-filter-leaks' into next
| * 12f70ac9b5 (origin/seen) Merge branch 'jk/proto-v2-ref-prefix-fix' into seen
|/  
* 79f2338b37 (origin/master, origin/main, origin/HEAD) The eighteenth batch
* ac8035a2af (tag: v2.37.3, origin/maint) Git 2.37.3
* ad60dddad7 (tag: v2.37.2) Git 2.37.2
* bbea4dcf42 (tag: v2.37.1) Git 2.37.1
*   69ab3309e9 Sync with Git 2.36.2
|\  
| * fd59c5bdee (tag: v2.36.2) Git 2.36.2
| *   8f8eea8c3a Sync with 2.35.4
| |\  
| | * 359da658ae (tag: v2.35.4) Git 2.35.4
| | *   aef3d5948c Sync with 2.34.4
| | |\  
| | | * f2eed22852 (tag: v2.34.4) Git 2.34.4
| | | *   378eaded1a Sync with 2.33.4
.
.
.
```

Comment: Finally I found it here.

Comment: Thanks, it should be a selected answer

Comment: Well... I have been a "CLI junkie" [all those years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709317/6309) ;)

Answer (score 3):

I have a little [Ruby script](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577572-display-a-git-repository/) that uses graphviz to display a repository. It dies on really large repositories (but you can tweak it a little to not display too many intermediate commits). I use it during my git trainings and I've found it useful.

Update:
I blogged about it [here](http://nibrahim.net.in/2013/07/31/git_tree_and_repo_diagrams.html). There are pictures of the graphs as well as notes on how to use the scripts.

Comment: I don't want all the commits.  Just branch names.  Can it do that?

Comment: You'd have to edit it a little but yes, it can. The commits (atleast a few) are useful to show relationships between the branches. The question VonC has linked to also has a useful `--simplify-by-decoration` option to `git log` which might give you what you want.

Comment: I would suggest you add some sample graphs to your web page.

Answer (score 2):

For those who looking for GUI alternative. I use [GitUp](http://gitup.co/) for Branch Visualisation. The UI looks sleek and clean. Although, GitUp can be used for editing Git repo. I only use its Visualisation tool. Its free, open source, and only 9.1 MB.

[image]

Another GUI tool is Git Client like Atlassian's Source Tree, Git Kraken or Git Tower. Those Client usually have built-in Git Visualisation tool.

Comment: Gitup is amazing.  They have a command-line tool so you can just do `gitup` and it will visualize your current repo.