# Condense git log --graph output?

Tags: git, git-log

Is there a way to condense the output of `git log --graph` so it'll visually squash commits that follow a linear history? Basically, I just want to see the points in the graph where some branches diverge/merge to get an top-level 'overview' of what my branch structure looks like. As an example, if I had this:

```
A
|
Z
|
H
|
B    G
|   /
C  F
| /
D
|
E
```

I'd want it to show something like:

```
A    G
|   /
.. ..
| /
D
|
E
```

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but try `--simplify-by-decoration`? It only shows commits that are referred to by a branch or tag.

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Ismail Badawi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281108/ismail-badawi)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705429/condense-git-log-graph-output/24709317#comment38313892_24705429), I like:

```
git log --simplify-by-decoration --graph --format="%d"
```

On the [git repo itself](https://github.com/git/git/), that would give:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git>git log --simplify-by-decoration --graph --format="%d"
*  (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
*  (tag: v1.9.1)
*  (tag: v1.9.0)
*
|\
| *  (tag: v1.8.5.5)
* |  (tag: v1.9.0-rc3)
* |
|\ \
| |/
| *  (tag: v1.8.5.4)
* |  (tag: v1.9-rc2)
* |  (tag: v1.9-rc1)
```

---

Slightly longer:

```
git log --simplify-by-decoration --graph --pretty="format:%H%n" | git name-rev --stdin --name-only | less
```

In multiple lines:

```
git log --simplify-by-decoration --graph --pretty="format:%H%n" | \ 
  git name-rev --stdin --name-only | \
  less
```

On the [git repo itself](https://github.com/git/git/), that would give:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git>git log --simplify-by-decoration --graph --pretty="format:%H%n" | git name-rev --stdin --name-only | less
* master
|
* tags/v1.9.1^0
|
* tags/v1.9.0^0
|
*   tags/v1.9.0~2
|\
| |
| * tags/v1.8.5.5^0
| |
* | tags/v1.9.0-rc3^0
| |
* |   tags/v1.9.0-rc3~4
|\ \
| |/
| |
| * tags/v1.8.5.4^0
| |
* | tags/v1.9-rc2^0
```

Comment: Without tags: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70456061/6309)