# git log show everything _except_ tags

Tags: git, tags

The situation:
I use tags in git to flag version releases. I also have a quick command to show me a simple graph in git with all my active dev branches:

```
git log --oneline --graph --simplify-by-decoration --all
```

The issue is that this shows all of the tags, eating up a lot of real estate on the screen. Is there a way I can filter out the tags? I still want all of the other information (i.e. just the active development branches).

I've tried using `--exclude="refs/tags/*` to no avail - any other suggestions?

I've included an [image of what my git log looks like with all the tags cluttering it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2alva.png).

Comment: Did you mean `git log ...` rather than `git --log`?

Comment: Yes my apologies, its been a long morning - will fix in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command I'm looking for is:

```
    git log --oneline --graph --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --branches --remotes --decorate-refs=refs/heads --decorate-refs=refs/remotes
```

Thanks to @jthill and @torek for helping with this issue.

EDIT:

After further experimenting, I found the following command:

```
log --oneline --graph --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --all --decorate-refs-exclude=refs/tags
```

The above command will include all local and remote branches, including the HEAD indicator, and will *exclude tags*

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get close:

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline \
        --simplify-by-decoration --branches --decorate-refs=refs/heads
```

Add `--decorate-refs=refs/remotes` to include remote branches in the decoration, `--remotes` to include them in the starter tips.

Comment: This is still showing all the tags - in my case I'm not seeing a difference between this and what I was using previously.

Comment: I'm on git 2.25 and it works, ![here's what my Git repo log looks like with the stock 2.25.0](https://i.imgur.com/yCY1IxE.png)

Comment: I just update to 2.25 (unsure what I was using before, I think I updated last August). I'm now getting my local repository (without tags). So we're partially there (thanks!).

While this is already cleaner than the mess I was working with earlier, do you know how I would go about including remote branches?

Comment: Sure: add `--decorate-refs=refs/remotes`.

Comment: upon further investigation, the addition of '--decorate-refs=refs/remotes' seems to only be adding the remote branches for which I have a local branch already checked out. If a remote branch has moved as much as a single commit from my own local corresponding branch, the remote is not shown.

Comment: @FKus: with `--branches`, the starting point for `git log` walking the graph is *all refs whose name starts with `refs/heads/`*, i.e., all branch names. Your remote-tracking names are refs that start with `refs/remotes/` so `git log` isn't looking at those. It *does* look at this for decoration purposes *afterwards*, when you add the `--decorate-refs`, but that's too late. You'll need to start your walk from remote-tracking names too: `git log ... --branches --remotes ...`.

Comment: @torek Thanks! That seems to have done it. Will post the final solution in another answer

Answer (score 1):

In your first command:

```
git log --oneline --graph    --decorate --simplify-by-decoration \
        --branches --remotes --decorate-refs=refs/heads --decorate-refs=refs/remotes
```

You can remove the `--decorate` if you are using Git 2.35 (Q1 2022):

When "[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/00cbaf93628282779504b470653ad239c4eca463/Documentation/git-log.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> implicitly enabled the decoration processing without being explicitly asked with `--decorate` option, it failed to read and honor the settings given by the "`--decorate-refs`" option.

See [commit be73860](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be738607934ceb0c99fbcc81bb1949413acd3459), [commit 14b9c2b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14b9c2b3e35929325329e616e122fd71e15b092c) (02 Dec 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 00cbaf9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00cbaf93628282779504b470653ad239c4eca463), 21 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be738607934ceb0c99fbcc81bb1949413acd3459): load decorations with --simplify-by-decoration
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> It's possible to specify `--simplify-by-decoration` but not --decorate.
> In this case we do respect the simplification, but we don't actually show any decorations.
> However, it works by lazy-loading the decorations when needed; this is discussed in more detail in [0cc7380](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cc7380d8846c30ce0d5d6310b2cb5994f269133) ("`log-tree`: call `load_ref_decorations()` in `get_name_decoration()`", 2019-09-08, Git v2.24.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed6822896bf4d28c12614e18e3fdcc5dc27ff8e5) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b744c3af07a15aaeb1b82fab689995fd5528f120)).
>
> This works for basic cases, but will fail to respect any `--decorate-refs` option (or its variants).
> Those are handled only when `cmd_log_init()` loads the ref decorations up front, which is only when `--decorate` is specified explicitly (or as of the previous commit, when the userformat asks for %d or similar).
>
> We can solve this by making sure to load the decorations if we're going to simplify using them but they're not otherwise going to be displayed.