# make git log --graph --all show current location like hg glog does

Tags: git, graph, logging

How can I make git show my current node in the log graph?  `git log --graph --all`  marks all the nodes equally with *, but I'm used to Mercurial where hg glog visually differentiates my current node by depicting it with @.  This is especially useful after git fetch (aka hg pull), when my current node won't necessarily be at the top.

Currently I have to figure out my current node's hash and then hunt through the output of graph log.  Is there a better way?

PS - I'm in a non-graphical environment so gitk is not an option.

[UPDATE: now I'm fully acclimated to git, and the first thing I do setting up a new environment is issue the following command to setup a git alias:

```
git config --global alias.map 'log --graph --full-history --all --color --decorate'
```

This allows me to type `git map` in any repo and see an ascii-art map of all the branches and commits, and my location on that map.  This alias is probably my single most-used git command at this point (besides add and commit), really indispensable for me]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding the `--decorate` option will show the refs pointing to each commit.
So, for example, you'll see **HEAD** and **origin/HEAD** (or whatever) in the right places.

They may even be in pretty colours if you have that enabled.

PS. thanks for making me check this - it's actually very nice, especially the way it also shows my various stashes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by adding some formatting option, you can see where HEAD is:

```
--pretty=format:"%h%x09%d%x20%s"
```

See "[Visualizing branch topology in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git/1838938#1838938)" for illustration.