# Is there a way to view your a mapping of your git branches?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visualizing branch topology in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git)

I'm creating a git repository and I was creating couple branches. Is there a way to map the branches I have created?

For example:

```
Master
    -Development
        -Feature1
        -Feature 2
    -Hotfix
        -Bug 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using gitk or another program. I like

`git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative`