# Remove all the changes made by a particular branch (developer)

Tags: git, merge, git-revert

We 4 developers work on a single project and merge our code into development. Now I want to undo all the changes made to my particular developer branch. How can I do that? And I want the code of all developers except that one developer.

Removing all the code changes from one particular developer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rollback a Git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722533/rollback-a-git-merge)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534312/revert-a-merge-after-being-pushed

Comment: Roughly how many commits are there by each developer (`git shortlog -n -s`)? What is your merge strategy?