# Tell gitk to draw "busier" branch on the right

Tags: git, gitk

In our project we use a master branch for merging in regular feature branches (left side of the image), and additionally a long-running branch to integrate upstream commits (right side of image). We use this integration branch because upstream is not a git repo, so that way we have a branch that always mirrors upstream (but that's not very relevant here).

Whenever I open gitk in that repo, it shows me the master branch on the very left of the branch graph, and the integration branch on the right. **Instead** I would like to **have the busier branch on the right** (busier meaning more commits), so as to have the commit messages closer to the commit points.

Is there a way to make gitk draw the branches in a specific order? If someone is into the source of gitk, I wouldn't mind some fix that'd require me to compile gitk myself.

*I know that, once merged, git can no longer discern which branch old commits were made on; I used the word "branch" above in a purely graphical sense. Gitk has to somehow determine what commits to draw in which "lane" (column) of the graph, and I'd like to influence that.*

[image: sample history]

*(Sorry about the long image)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the left branch is the one where the current local HEAD is, then you might try to invoke that `gitk log` with the"right" branch checked out first (I realize it is a -- poor -- workaround, but my point is: `gitk` won't do it for you).

However, as far as I know, `gitk` won't display one branch rather than the other or detect the "busiest" one. Only log options can influence how the history of commits is represented (as in "[Visualizing branch topology in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git)").

Comment: I had in fact not considered comparing `gitk`'s output with `git log --graph` -- it turns out the order and display is exactly the same, so `gitk` is really just displaying, not doing anything else. I guess I'll have to dive into the depths of the git source again and figure out how to talk some sense into `git log` :D

Comment: @NevikRehnel I agree with your conclusion: `gitk` is just a graphic representation of the same output as git log.