# Git tree with selectable nodes in terminal?

Tags: git

Emacs has an optional undo-tree. You can cursor to each node, and hit return to go back in time, even along branches.

Is there something similar for git, which can be accessed within the Terminal (not Emacs). 
So, within a git project, I could type a command and it would show the tree. I could cursor around, going back in time or even switching to another branch, then hit return and it would checkout that particular commit's whole state.

[image: git undo tree]

Comment: This isn't a duplicate because it's a view only, but it may lead you somewhere useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git

Comment: yeah, seen those kinda things, but was wondering if there is a selectable version

Comment: `tig` might be interesting for you, which is kinda like `gitk` with an ncurses UI

Answer (score 11):

As @NevikRehnel said, [`tig`](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/) is your friend.

`tig --all` shows you your complete log in a tree form (as `git log`'s `--graph` switch).

[image: tig log view]

You move between commits with up and down keys, you see a `git show` of the selected commit with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you can hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for doing `git cherry-pick` of that commit.

[image: tig show view]

You can press <kbd>H</kbd> anytime to see help.

[image: tig help view]

You can checkout branches, but you can too add [custom bindings](https://github.com/jonas/tig/wiki/Bindings) for doing `git checkout`.

I think [`man tigrc`](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/tigrc.5.html) would be enough to understand how.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `tig`, thanks for sharing. Seems like a great tool. N.B. those running OSX can install it using [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) (`brew install tig`).

Answer (score 0):

For a graphical view of the git, install gitk utility, and type gitk --all and right click to change the head position. Use can use soft reset or hard reset. Caution: hard reset will loose all the changes made after the head to which you are resetting.