# View git repo in UI form

Tags: git

Is there a command line/UI tool to view git repo structure like branches, commits etc in visual form. I have many branches and done many commits. It will be easy to see these in visual form.

Comment: I think [`tig`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14989618/641451) is the best `git` _GUI_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how detailed you want to go, [git-log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) has some nifty options available to you.

This is a command I use to only see select commits, decorated with their branch/tag:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate
```

Other UI components exist, like gitk.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a GUI on whichever OS you're running, [`gitk`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) is a fairly powerful graphical UI for git that comes with most distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure if this is what you're looking for, but SourceTree will give you a visual depiction of your branches and commits.