# Catching String as Argument in Bash

Tags: git, bash, shell

I have a script I use for Git

```
function push() {
  git add --all
  git commit -m $1
  git push
}
```

Which I invoke by

```
p "Commit message"
```

My question is, how can I pass everything after `p` as one argument, essentially passing everything after `p` as the commit message - importantly - I want to know if there is a way to do this without quotation marks

Comment: Use `"$*"` instead of `"$1"` in the function. See [Positional Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters).

Comment: That worked, thanks! http://d.pr/i/10wgo/F1z2FPXo

Comment: With `"Commit Message"`, `"$1"` would have been fine; it's unquoted `$1` that was the problem.

Comment: By the way, the `function` keyword is best avoided -- just `push() {` is enough to define a function, and that way your function will work in any POSIX shell rather than being specific to shells with bash extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the only argument you have, you can use `$*` in your script to get all the parameters. Also, quote them:

```
function push() {
    git add --all
    git commit -m "$*"
    git push
 }
```

You can use `"$1"`, too, leaving place for more parameters, but in that case you **must** use quotes while invoking the function (say, `$ push "Some message"` instead of just `$ push Some message`). It's more correct, but for this function purposes - just to economise time - it may be more useful.

Anyway, I don't think it's a good idea to have such a function. `git add` is a good moment to review your commit, decide what to include in it and what to leave for other commits, and to construct a really nice commit message. Plus, you would often want to delay the `push` until you have a couple of commits.

I recommend you to use something like [`tig`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14989618/641451) for easily selecting what to stage and the like.

Comment: `"$1"` would have worked just as well, for the single-argument case, and would preserve the ability to pass additional arguments. It's unquoted `$1` that was the problem.