# Recover git-svn mirror after svn repository was "rolled back"

Tags: git-svn

How can i repair my git-svn mirror repository?
It is set up with `git svn init ...`, then github remote was added. The cron job is doing `git svn rebase && git push` periodically.

Everything was fine until upstream somehow "uncommited" several revisions from svn, which already was fetched into my git-svn and pushed to github. Then upstream added some new revisions to svn trunk, reusing revision numbers of "uncommited" revisions, which broke my syncronization process.

When i realized what hppened, i did `git svn reset` to last valid revision and commited reverse patch into git.

But since then, i can not pull upstream changes with `git svn rebase`, i have to do `git svn fetch && git merge trunk` instead, resulting in awful history.

Can i somehow tell git-svn that i will not `git svn dcommit` anything, that it can forget about that reverse patch commit, so `git svn rebase` can work like it worked before all this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My investigation results: there is nothing magical in git-svn's rebase function. It is just a `git svn fetch` followed by `git rebase refs/remotes/trunk` and refs update.
In my case, all i had was to move my local tracking branch ref to the last fetched from commit.

```
git svn fetch
git log -1 refs/remotes/trunk
```

gave me latest sha1: ed0fa874ca872bc3a0101ee397f611a537e72c2a

```
git update-ref HEAD ed0fa87
git reset --hard
```

Useful resources: [Pro GIT Book](http://git-scm.com/book), [Visualizing branch topology in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git#1838938).

Hope, this will help someone.