# How do I view all commits for a specific day?

Tags: git, git-log

I've already looked at the relevant docs from [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-3.html) and [gitref.org](http://gitref.org/inspect/), but I can't seem to figure this out.

Let's say I want to get all commits for Tuesday, November 12th, 2013. Using an existing repo as an example, I know for a fact that I have commits on that day, as well as commits the day before and the day after.

#### With `2013-11-11` and `2013-11-12`

All the following give me commits for both November 11th and 12th:

- `git log --after="2013-11-11" --until="2013-11-12"`
- `git log --since="2013-11-11" --until="2013-11-12"`
- `git log --after="2013-11-11" --before="2013-11-12"`
- `git log --since="2013-11-11" --before="2013-11-12"`

#### With `2013-11-12` only

All the following give me no commits:

- `git log --since="2013-11-12" --until="2013-11-12"`
- `git log --since="2013-11-12" --before="2013-11-12"`
- `git log --after="2013-11-12" --until="2013-11-12"`
- `git log --after="2013-11-12" --before="2013-11-12"`

#### With `2013-11-12` and `2013-11-13`

As expected (from the results of `2013-11-11` and `2013-11-12` above), all of the following give me results from both November 12th and 13th:

- `git log --since="2013-11-12" --before="2013-11-13"`
- `git log --after="2013-11-12" --before="2013-11-13"`
- `git log --since="2013-11-12" --until="2013-11-13"`
- `git log --after="2013-11-12" --before="2013-11-13"`

...and so on and so forth. I feel like I've tried every possible combination of `since`, `after`, `before`, and `until` but still can't find the answer, nor do I understand whether those options are inclusive or exclusive, since they seem to be inclusive if the two dates are different, but exclusive if they're on the same day. Did I miss something / what am I doing wrong?!

Comment: I've found git's since/after/until/before handling very weird myself, so I don't know the answer, but have you tried specifying date+time (e.g., --since="2013-11-12 00:00")? Also, do (any of) your commits have different committer vs. author dates?

Comment: You got it! Specifying the time worked. It didn't even occur to me to try it with a time. Thanks!

As for committer vs. author dates -- there were no patches applied during those dates, so that wasn't it.

Comment: Seems to me that 'git log --boundary' should do this for you, so that 'git log --boundary --after="2013-11-12" --before="2013-11-12"' would show exactly one commit (the one you think it would :) ).

Comment: I really love this [GitKraken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37041706/1176573) answer !

Answer (score 340, accepted):

[Thanks John Bartholomew!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987099/how-do-i-view-all-commits-for-a-specific-day#comment29756543_19987099)

The answer is to specify the time, e.g. `git log --after="2013-11-12 00:00" --before="2013-11-12 23:59"`

Comment: Nice. However, that command will omit commits between 23:59 and 00:00 the next day, therefore `git log --after="2013-11-12 00:00" --before="2013-11-13 00:00"` is better. I believe `gitk --since="2013-11-12 00:00" --until="2013-11-13 00:00" &` would also work if you have gitk installed.

Comment: In git 2.13.0. `git log --after="2017-07-25" --before="2017-07-26"` gives valid results for me.

Comment: Is this for the current checked out branch? How to see across all branches?

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I'm still baffled by it and posted this follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691065/what-does-git-log-since-until-do-when-there-is-no-hhmmss-supplied-in-the-v

Comment: Not worked for me dear, thanks

Answer (score 48):

I usually check my git log and see what I was working on a specific day and update my timesheet based on that, but it's a pain in the ass to type in the full date in ISO format so I just do it like this

```
git log --after=jun9 --before=jun10
```

and I add `--author` to only print my commits

```
git log --since=jun9 --until=jun10 --author=Robert
```

This prints commits that happened on the last 9th of June (so for 2016 in this case and not for 2015 or 2014 and so on).

The `--since/--after` and `--until/--before` parameters can also take stuff like `3 days ago`, `yesterday`, etc.

Comment: Simply doesn't work, outputs nothing. Am I missing anything? Should I specify a branch?

Comment: @Aurimas Well, not sure what went wrong on your end. If your `since` and `until` values aren't correct you'll get no output that's for sure. Use `git log` first, and try to pick a `since` and `until` value based on what you see. No branch or anything special required. Not sure since which Git version this feature is available. Make sure you have a recent version as well.

Comment: I had to use spaces: `git log --after="may 2" --before="may 3"`

Answer (score 24):

Nothing wrong with the accepted answer (which I upvoted), but... we're here for science!

The output below can be expanded/customised with `pretty=format:<string>` [placeholders](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats):

```
git log --pretty='format:%H %an %ae %ai' | grep 2013-11-12
```

*Not 100% immune to errors as the same string could have been entered by a user.* But acceptable depending on which placeholders are used. The snippet above would not fail, for instance.

One could as well just parse the whole `git log` to `JSON` and consume/manipulate its data to one's heart content. Check https://github.com/dreamyguy/gitlogg out and never look back!

*Disclaimer:* that's one of my projects.

Answer (score 19):

I made a [git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) for that specific purpose:

```
commitsAtDate = "!f() { git log --pretty='format:%C(yellow)%h %G? %ad%Cred%d %Creset%s%C(cyan) [%cn]' --decorate --after=\"$1 0:00\" --before=\"$1 23:59\" --author \"`git config user.name`\"; }; f"
```

Usage:

```
git commitsAtDate 2017-08-18
```

It results in a nicely scannable output:

[image: screenshot of four commits at a specific date by the author]

Comment: you also can specify relative dates to this alias, i.e. `git commitsAtDate yesterday`, `2 days ago`, etc.

Comment: You can also omit the date entirely to get today's commits, e.g. `git commitsAtDate`. Neat!

Answer (score -2):

This script displays the available date range of commits for the current repo, then prompts for the date that you want to see commits from. It displays a short SHA and the full SHA, the author, the commit timestamp, and the comments in single quotes.

The script keeps prompting for dates until you press Enter or Control-D.

Mac users: requires gnu date.

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMITS=`git log --abbrev-commit --pretty="format:%h %H %ai" | sort -k3 -k4`
FIRST=`echo "$COMMITS" | head -n 1`
LAST=`echo "$COMMITS" | tail -n 1`
echo "First commit: $FIRST"
echo "Last commit: $LAST"
printf "Date to search for commits: "
read DATE
while [[ "$DATE" ]]; do
  NEXT_DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$DATE +1 day"`
  #echo "Searching for commits from $DATE to $NEXT_DATE"
  echo `git log --after="$DATE" --before="$NEXT_DATE" --pretty="format:%h %H %an %ci '%s'"`
  printf "\nDate to search for commits: "
  read DATE
done
```

I called the script `commitsOnDates`, and here it is in action. The first date I enter has no commits, so the response is just an empty line:

```
$ commitsOnDates
First commit: 375bcfb 375bcfbbf548134a4e34c36e3f28d87c53b2445f 2015-08-03 13:37:16 -0700
Last commit: 1d4c88c 1d4c88ce6a15efaceda1d653eed3346fcae8f5e6 2018-10-13 21:32:27 -0700
Date to search for commits: 2015-08-13


Date to search for commits: 2015-08-03
375bcfb 375bcfbbf548134a4e34c36e3f28d87c53b2445f Mike Slinn 2015-08-03 13:37:16 -0700 'this is a comment'

Date to search for commits: 2018-10-13
1d4c88c 1d4c88ce6a15efaceda1d653eed3346fcae8f5e6 Mike Slinn 2018-10-13 21:32:27 -0700 'a comment' 64d6e16 64d6e16338657b82c91ac94bea8ebf7b80dc4c28 Mike Slinn 2018-10-13 18:28:41 -0700 'nother comment' d5eb26e d5eb26e49fc9dceee9b9f5a2d8fa052bff2cfbbc Mike Slinn 2018-10-13 18:16:20 -0700 'no comment' d8a4992 d8a4992df208ba5efb50728311820bdad5ba5332 Mike Slinn 2018-10-13 12:02:00 -0700 'commented'

Date to search for commits:
```