# List git commits to master branch between two dates

Tags: git, git-log

How can i get a list of all the git commits done to the master branch between 2014-01-01 and 2014-06-30?

I know `git log` will give me roughly this format (repeated for all commits):

```
commit <hash>
author: <author name>
date: <date>
<comment>
```

But how can it be limited to selected dates and a one line per commit format?

```
<hash> <author> <date>
<hash> <author> <date>
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/19987099/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1441062/6309

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
$ git log --since "DEC 1 2014" --until "DEC 5 2014" --pretty=format:"%h %an %ad"
```

This will give the format you want for the commits between dec 1 2014 and dec 5 2014, you can change the dates as you like

If you wish to change the format, you can [read about the options here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats)

Comment: add this at the end to write the output to a file`> output`

Answer (score 26):

```
$ git log master --pretty="%h %an %ad" --since=2014-01-01 --until=2014-06-30
```

Here is everything http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Comment: ty. one point, cos you included branch, and prefered date format

Comment: This is perfect because my script already uses this date format

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried

```
git whatchanged --since="2 year ago" --until="1 year ago" [--author="NAME_OF_THE_AUTHOR"]
```

Even `git log` can be utilized to have this result. There are some advance options available in `git log`

```
git log --after="2014-7-1" --before="2014-7-4"
```

For more details about advance git log you can refer to this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log/filtering-the-commit-history)

Answer (score 5):

Well, this should do the trick:

```
git log --oneline --since="1/1/2014" --until="30/6/2014"
```

---

Comment: This is not the requested format, though. Just hash and commit message

Comment: @TimCastelijns yup, im aware of that, but before i managed to fix it you posted your answer and i was too busy upvoting it to fix mine ;)

Comment: @4rlekin Please change `since` to `--since`.