# How can I get a list of all merge commits to a git branch between two dates?

Tags: git, git-extensions

We have something bad occurring in our pre-production environments that is very hard to track down.  We know that it was first introduced to our develop branch between 2018-07-21 and 2018-07-28.

I would like to go look at all the merge commits to develop between those two dates to examine them for anything that might be causing our problem.  Preferably, I would like to do this in some visual tool like Git Extensions, but that is not critical.

So, I need a list of merge commit hashes to branch "develop" between 2018-07-21 and 2018-07-28, but I don't know how to find that specific list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List git commits to master branch between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313309/list-git-commits-to-master-branch-between-two-dates)

Comment: It's not a duplicate; this is specifically just merge commits.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use Bisect (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) that let's your track the commit that introduced the regression.
In GitExtensions it is available under Commands>Bisect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work? I'm no expert on git but I think, looking at some examples I've worked with, this should give you what you need:

`git log --since "JUL 21 2016" --until "JUL 28 2018" --pretty=format:"%H" --merges`