# Git Merge (merge from one branch to another)

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-cherry-pick, gitattributes

I have two branch lets say one branch is `branch_one` and second one is `branch_two`.

Now both branches have been used paralleled for different set of developments.

Now, I want to merge some commits from `branch_two` to `branch_one`, but based on start of time.

I mean `branch_two` has around 100 commits we want to merge from 51 commit on-wards on `branch_one`.

Comment: what do you mean by "but based on start of time."? Actually git merge branch_two can help you.

Comment: And where did those branches diverge? Before or after commit 51? Do you care about the commits after 51 on branch_one?

Answer (score 1):

### Description

If you do not want to merge all changes from one branch to another (using `git merge`), you can [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) some of the commits (either single commits or multiple commits at once). See `cherry-pick` documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) or [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/7598462), that elaborates on cherry-picking a range of commits.

As far as I know, there is no direct option to directly merge commits from a certain date, but you can just use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19987337/7598462) to find the commit created on a certain day and use that commit as the start commit for your cherry pick.

Be aware, however, that cherry-picking does apply the picked commits' changes, but creates new commits. Thus, when you ever merge `branch_one` and `branch_two` in the future, you will have multiple commits introducing the same changes.

### Example

On branch_two:

`git log --after="2013-11-12 00:00" --before="2013-11-12 23:59"`

Output:

```
commit 5f3be6775d78k28ee0e4f55c05ec897de3f02360
Author: someone <some@one.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 22 17:10:48 2017 +0100

    Commit message
```

On branch_one:

`git cherry-pick 5f3be6775d78k28ee0e4f55c05ec897de3f02360~1..<id of the latest commit on branch_two>`

Edit: Note the `~1` behind the first commits' id. This is necessary, since cherry picking multiple commits will

> [...] not cherry-pick A, but rather everything after A up to
>   and including B. – J. B. Rainsberger

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3933416/7598462).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**git format-patch**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) command

```
git format-patch -50 -o <output-directory>
```

It will generate separate patch file for each commit.
And then apply the patch to branch one