# Get the last git commit at the end of every day?

Tags: git

I am needing to work out paid overtime for a project. I have to be compensated for working after 1600. I need to find the last commit to a repository (branch does not matter) for every day over the past 4 months.

How would I achieve this? I need this in a format that I can parse, so I can run a script over it and calculate the hours

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: ```git log --format="%H" -n 1``` Did you try this

Comment: @UnbearableLightness that's the thing, I honestly have no idea where to start. I'm not very good at shell scripts :(. Even a starting point would help.

Comment: What's the starting date from 4 months ago you want to start from?

Comment: @twister_void only shows the has of the latest commit

Comment: @UnbearableLightness December 27th

Comment: @Gibbo Do you want just the last commit for one day or all of them? (In the scenario where you have more than one commit after 4pm for a given day)

Comment: @Gibbo did any of the answers below resolve your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get each day commit like this  `git log --after="2018-11-12 00:00" --format="%ci %cr""`

After that, you can write a script to run for each day

For more details read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987099/how-do-i-view-all-commits-for-a-specific-day#comment29756543_19987099)

Comment: This is what I want, but slightly modifed it. This shows a list of commits + date and time. git log --after="2018-11-12 00:00" --format="%ci %cr"

Comment: This answer is incomplete

Comment: Glad I was the help I will modify my answer

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I think at-least was in right direction

Answer (score 1):

I used the one-liner below to get the commit hashes of the commits since yesterday, 26/03/2020, commited after 16:00:00. You can adjust accordingly with your date:

```
$ git log --all --since="26/03/2020" --oneline --pretty=format:"%H %an %ad" | awk -F ' ' '{gsub(":","",$7); if($7>160000) print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following pipe should provide you with the output you are looking for

```
git log --all --since="26/03/2019" --pretty=format:"%an %ad" --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | process.awk MYNAME=Enrico
```

The script `process.awk` is the following (you have to `chmod +x` it, or alternatively you have to change `| process.awk ...` to `| awk -f process.awk ...`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f
BEGIN {
  fourPM = 16*3600
}
!match($1,MYNAME) || $2 == previousDay { next }
{
  previousDay = $2
  split($3,previousTime,":")
  oversec = previousTime[1]*3600 \
          + previousTime[2]*60   \
          + previousTime[3]      \
          - fourPM
  if (oversec > 0) {
    $(NF + 1) = "overtime: " int(oversec/3600)        \
                         ":" int((oversec % 3600)/60) \
                         ":" int(oversec % 60)
    print $0
  }
}
```