# Git get history of branches that i was in

Tags: git, git-branch, git-reflog, git-history

I need to see the history of branches that i was using. For example i have 4 branches: master, b-1, b-2, b-1-1. Thе branch "b-1-1" is child of branch "b-1". First i was at master branch, then at branch b-1, then at branch b-1-1 , then at branch b-2, then again at b-1-1. The history of my used branches would look like this:

- b-1-1
- b-2
- b-1-1
- b-1
- master

Is it possible to do so in git? If yes, then how?
I have tried to check the git log but it is not what i am searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can see which branch were checked out and in which order in a sense that you've formulated in the question . Branch is a pointer and this pointer can change only if you do commit.

For example, if you:

- checkout the existing branch branch (`git checkout abc`)
- see its log (`git log -n 10`)
- checkout another existing branch xyz (`git checkout xyz`)

Then git won't remember that you were checking out the `abc` branch

Having said that, you can see the commits that you've done during, say last 3 days with this command:

```
git log --since="3 days ago" --author=<HERE_COMES_YOUR_NAME_IN_GIT> --all
```

This `--since` parameter can be really flexible, `1 day ago`, exact time, `1 week ago` are all possible values, check out the documentation and also [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987099/how-do-i-view-all-commits-for-a-specific-day)

Another interesting option is using (in its the most basic form): `git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/`

This command will print all commits in all branches in the descending order. There is already [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188320/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-git-branches-ordered-by-most-recent-commit) in SO about this and it provides way more options of possible usage of this command than I can do so please check that out as well.

Comment: c'mon. `git reflog|awk '/: checkout:/{print $NF}'`

Comment: @jthill I was about to nitpick with "What if OP has not used `git checkout` but `git switch`? Huh? Huh?" ...then I tested it out and learned that it makes no difference in terms of reflog entries : `64ea7a0f3 (HEAD -> dev) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from somebranch to dev`. So thank you :-)

Answer (score 16):

Take a look at `git reflog` to inspect the history of `HEAD` positions.

There's also `git reflog <branch>` for the history of a specific branch.

Check documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

---

**(Bonus)**
If useful in your context, you can also craft an alias to extract them by using the [`@{-<n>}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-em-ltngtemegem-1em) construct

```
$ git config alias.last '!f() { for i in $(seq 1 $1); do git name-rev --name-only --exclude=refs/tags/\* @{-$i}; done; }; f'

$ git last 3
# outputs the 3 last checked out branches
```

Comment: Your alias suggestion is really useful, too bad it's not part of the normal git commands. I would use the alias name branchistory. If I could I would give you 50 points!
You could also add to the alias << |sort|uniq >> to remove duplicates...

Comment: @MartinP. I did not pipe it to `sort -u` because the branch order could be useful also, but yes it's a possibility, it'll be better in some contexts.

Answer (score 5):

This invocation of `git reflog` with some `grep` filtering seems to be working for me:

```bash
git reflog | grep checkout | grep -o 'to .*$' | grep -o ' .*$' | less
```

For example:

```
 b2
 master
 b1
 master
 b2
 b1
 b2
...
```