# How can I create Git tags for a list of releases with timestamps in epoch format?

Tags: git

I have a list of Tags that should be created in some list of lists containing release name and release time in Epoch format.

```
Release1, 1519124404
Release2, 1508330671
Release3, 1489590989
```

I should use annotated tags (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) but I couldn't find a way to add in `git tag -a Release1` command a timestamp (preferably in epoch format) so that my Tag references that time in the past of the current branch. I am aware that for `Tagging later` I could use some `commit` but this is not something which exists and is not applicable for my use case (since this is some migration from other SCM platform to Git and I only have a list of tags that should be created for my branch).

Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use a script for that, in bash or powershell... Simply create the date in epoch format (like using `date +%s` in bash), store it in a variable and use that in the `git tag` command.

Comment: I do not know how to propagate timevalue in `git tag` command. I do not see any option for that in documentation!!! please provide full example

Comment: To create an annotated tag with a message run, for example, `git tag -a Release1 -m "1519124404"`. It's all described in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). If you want to set a timestamp for the tag itself - that's not possible. It always uses system current time. So you'd have to manipulate that before tagging...

Comment: @fredrik what about this "On Backdating Tags" https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html#_on_backdating_tags  will this resolve my query?

Comment: That might actually do it - if it still works. It seems to be provided specifically for when migrating from other VCS and you want to preserve release dates - which you're sort of doing. Hope it works out for you

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you can use commas in tags, but you can use in bash something like that:

```
git tag -a "Release1-`date +%s`"
```

It creates a tag in the form `Release1-1648822173`, with the epoch time in which you called the command. I'm pretty sure that there's a corresponding command for windows in powershell, or you can use git bash for it.

EDIT:

If you need to link the tag to specific commit date, you can do something like

```
git tag -a "Release1-`git show -s --format=%ct HEAD`"
```

If you need to put a tag in a particular date, first you need to find the commit at specific date, and then adding the tag to that date. If you're unsure about the commit, you can use something like [git log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987099/how-do-i-view-all-commits-for-a-specific-day) for viewing all commits in a specific time range.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my requirement. My release name must be "Release1" not with suffix of the timestamp!!! But time that should be referenced for that particular tag must be in the past containing the code for my branch at that moment...

Comment: The tag is linked to a commit, there's no concept of tag date, it's the corresponding commit date. I've edited the answer in order to get the epoch time of the commit where you have to put the tag, otherwise the question is not clear. If you want to add the tag to a specific commit of a specific date, first check out the commit at corresponding date, and then create the tag. You can find commits in a specific date range, for example https://www.30secondsofcode.org/git/s/view-commits-in-date-range

Comment: @Jepessen: An *annotated* tag does have an embedded date (so that's what a "tag date" would be), but your general point is correct that this isn't useful, since that's the date *in* the tag saying *when the tag was created*. :-) I think the OP wants to *fake* the date at which the tag was created, though.