# Vizualize specific git brancheS topology tree

Tags: git

I've searched around for that and while there are plenty of ways to get such vizualization for all branches ([Visualizing branch topology in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git), [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs)), I can't seem to find a way to select a subset of branches in particular.

For instance I have 5 branches that have somewhat diverged, been merged, diverged again, cherry-picked, and so on, and now I'd like to get an idea of how they relate to one another (so presumably a common root, 5 different leafs and some join/fork among the branches).

Any idea how to go about getting that using basic git, or even gitk/gitx...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` accepts multiple branch names on the command line, e.g. to see `master`, `foo` and `bar` you can use

```
git log --graph --decorate master foo bar
```

I don't often use `gitk`, but it seems to work there too:

```
gitk master foo bar
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I needed! In combination with  --oneline, it shows a neat graph!