# Graphical dynamic view of a git revision tree

Tags: git

For small repositories I am quite satisfied with my `git l` command:

```
[alias]
     l = log \
     --all \
     -n30 \
     --graph \
     --abbrev-commit \
     --decorate \
     --date=relative \
     --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)'
```

Unfortunately, with large repositories and hundreds of branches my tree is becoming too wide and too tall to get the general overview. I did not find a good solution in `gitk` and I do not know other utilities.

I am looking for a simple tool that generates an HTML dynamic revision tree (that can be folded) using for instance [cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) or a dendrogram chart from [d3.js](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570).

Is there any good *KISS* tool for this?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not KISS, you might want to have a look at [gource](https://code.google.com/p/gource/), which gives a dynamic graphical representation of who worked on what at what time. That unfortunately only shows the progression of one branch. Have you looked at the tools at [the git homepage](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)?

Comment: Seems that `gource` gives a representation of the working tree not the revision tree or I did not configured it properly

Comment: @nowox: yeah, you are right. Apart from that, there are some links on the git homepage. They probably do not exactly solve your problem either, but you might want to have a look.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [git-big-picture](https://github.com/esc/git-big-picture).

Currently, its graph only contains commit ids and their links, but it should be possible to do an additional git query which supplements the commit message. [The (Python-) source](https://github.com/esc/git-big-picture/blob/master/git-big-picture) is quite readable.

Comment: Nice tool. It would be better in full ASCII-art. I might take inspiration from this and implement my own `git-tree` command