# getting git history as array

Tags: node.js, git

I am interested in making a simple node application for graphing local git repositories. Something like this looks pretty close to what I need graphically (although I'll probably write my own):

http://gitgraphjs.com/

However, **how do I get the git branch history from the command line into an array (or *whatever*) I can turn into a graph?**

I am familiar with node's [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) api, and I know how to get a sort of graph out of git ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs) for example), but how am I supposed to parse that output? And get all the branches in the right place?

Comment: Can you show an array with some made-up sample data that would be similar to what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [NodeGit](http://www.nodegit.org/) for programmatic access to repo

Here an example to walks the git history https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/examples/walk-history.js