# Git- how can I be sure that my local master is the same as the one on the server?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am working on some software that has been written in Python/ Django, and have just tried running a `git pull origin master` on my local machine, and was given the output:

> Already up-to-date.

However, I am suspicious of this, because I know for a fact that some changes have been made to the version on the server since I was last in the office...

When I was last in, there were some errors on the version on the server, which had broken the site, these errors have been fixed when I was out of the office, and I now want to `pull` the working version from the server, to ensure that when working on a local copy, I am working on the latest version, so won't be pushing the errors that have been fixed back onto the server when I next push my changes to the server.

How can I ensure that my local `master` branch is definitely up-to-date with the `master` on the server? Is there a way to 'force' git to pull from the server and overwrite my local branch, even though it thinks that my local branch is already up to date?

Comment: `git log` shows  all the commit history. Have you matched `last commit` of `local master` and `remote master`?

Comment: I've just run `git log`, but it's only showing my commit history- the most recent changes were made by someone else...

Comment: Perhaps the change was in another branch: `git branch -av`. Is your question more like "What must happen, that master and remote/master are not the same although git states that?"

Comment: The only branch on the server is `master`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, start by forgetting everything you know about branch names. :-) The problem here is that these names are almost a sort of hint.  Anyone can change them, any way they like, any time.  A branch name just helps you (and Git) get started in terms of finding *commits*.  The *names* don't matter; it's the *commits* that matter.

(If people are careful and disciplined about the way they use the names, the hints will never mislead you.  Are you, and your team, and any people *not* on your team who you're also relying upon, all very careful and disciplined?  If the answer is "no" even one day of the year, you'll want to pay attention to *commits*.  Starting from the hints is fine, it's like believing that the sugar bowl for the coffee really does contain sugar.  But if you have an office prankster and the coffee goes weird, maybe the sugar bowl is now full of salt.)

#### Now that you know what *not* to trust: how to view commits

You would think `git log` would be the way to view commits ... and it is, but by default it doesn't show you *everything*.  This is on purpose: "everything" is usually way too much.  In my opinion, though, what it shows you by default often isn't *enough*.  This may be one reason Git GUIs are so popular.

There is no perfect viewer.  See [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452) and [Visualizing branch topology in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1838873/1256452) for many possibilities.  Gitk by default shows you more than `git log`.  Both, however, by default start from `HEAD`.  What I personally do most often is to get help from [a dog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075021/1256452): `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.  (I actually have this as an alias, `git lola`, but "a dog" is even more memorable!  Instead of `--all`, you might want `--branches` or `--branches --remotes`, but `--all` is the only way to get A DOG out of it.)  You get the same thing, but in graphics, with `gitk --all`.

Anyway, the point is that this kind of view, that (a) *includes the graph* and (b) *shows you all starting-points* (including all branch and remote-tracking branch names), gives you a great deal more information.  You will be able to see commits *you* have that *they* don't, and commits *they* have that *you* don't.

#### If you want to *discard* what you have

Sometimes you want to *throw away* everything you have in favor of everything they have.  That's easy enough:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

(while on your own `master`).  Be careful with this command as it does something you cannot undo!  In particular, the `--hard` step *discards uncommitted work-tree changes* and you cannot get those back.  The `git reset` step also says "I don't want my current branch name (whatever that is, er, I think it's `master`) to save *my* commits any more, I want it to remember only *their* `origin/master` commits."  So now your current branch name (you *think* it's `master`) only remembers the *same* commits as `origin/master`.  Better check and make sure your current branch name really is `master`, eh?

(If it's *not*, those commits *are* recoverable for a while, unlike unsaved work-tree work.)

Note that when you do this `git reset`, you have just moved your own `master` in a potentially-undisciplined way.  Maybe *you're* the office prankster. :-)

Answer (score 1):

At first, make sure your `fix-changes` are in `remote/master`.

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master

$ git diff master..origin/master         # see if there is any difference between 'local-master' and 'remote master'
```

N.B. `git log` shows all the commit history. Go to your `GitHub` repo using `Browser` and see if the `last commit` is `same` of `remote/master & local/master`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can force to pull by `git pull -f origin master:master`.

Also, you can compare the latest commit id between server and local master branch.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you actually have the latest changes:

```
git fetch
git log origin/master
```

Make sure that that contains the commits you expect. If it doesn't then it's likely that they weren't committed to master on the server like you think they are. Possibly they were put on another branch or something. You'd need to check the server repo. I suppose it's possible that `git fetch` silently failed, but I've never seen that.

Second, hard reset your local branch to the remote:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

That will skip any merge, fast forward, etc, and just point your local branch at the same commit as the origin and reset your workspace.