# Git GUI tool to show branch differences?

Tags: git

I normally use the command line but I find myself opening [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) to view changes between commits or branches.  Is there another tool that I could use with `git difftool`?  `git difftool` seems to use the tool for single files and prompt for each one (or open one at a time with `-y`).

I thought I might be able to see it using `git mergetool` by checking out the old branch and doing `git merge --no-commit` and then `git mergetool`, but that seems to only show files that need merging and no files need merging since the merge can just fast-forward.

The way most of the diff tools work is by looking at two directories, but that would entail checking out each commit and copying to a separate directory and then running the tool manually, so I'm guessing the tool would have to be specifically written for git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visualizing branch topology in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git)

Comment: Not really a dupe, I want to be able to see all the differences between two commits.  In sourcetree you just have to select one commit and ctrl+click on another and you can see all the changed files and click on each one to show the changes.  I want to do something like `git difftool develop master` and get the same type of display.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are looking for a GUI (as the title suggests), or a CLI (as the description and comment suggest?)

Comment: If you are looking for CLI you can use this: `git show ^master branchB`