# Git graph: Gathering commits of branch

Tags: git, commit, atlassian-sourcetree, git-log, gitkraken

How can I get the graph of a multibranches Git revision history for which:

- commits of one branch are gathered together ordered by date, and therefore
- commits of all branches are are not ordered by date.

Illustration:

```
EXAMPLE 1                         EXAMPLE 2
BAD        BETTER                 BAD         BETTER
*          *                      | *        *
|\         |\                     | *        *
* |        | *                    * |        *
| *        | *                    * |        *
| *        | *                    * |        *
* |        | *                    * |        *
| *        | *                    * |        *
| *        | *                    * |        *
* |        * |                    | *        *
| *        * |                    * |        | *
| *        * |                    * |        | *
* |        * |                    * |        | *
|/         |/                     |/         |/ 
*          *                      *          *
```

This is slightly better for reading and understanding big graphs revision history.

I am looking this kind of display for:

- git log

  - `--graph` will implicitly cause a `--topo-order` and solve the example 1
- sourcetree
- gitKraken.

Comment: Doesn't `git log --decorate` do the thing you are asking for? What exactly is the question?

Comment: I can't reproduce the bad example with default options. But the better graphs may be displayed with `--topo-order`.

Comment: Thx @Santa, indeed you are right for git log, --decorate does the job, at least for example 1 (I have not try for example 2 yet). Do you also have an idea for sourcetree or gitkaken  or another maybe ?

Comment: You can check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git?answertab=active#tab-top). The thread has some more ideas apart from the ones you are specifically looking.