# How to commit into a branch in git and show result into a git graph?

Tags: linux, git, github, terminal

What I do is:

1. `git branch sth`
2. `git checkout sth`
3. (Twice):

   - `git add -A`
   - `git commit -m ""`
4. `git checkout master`
5. `git merge sth`
6. `git branch -d sth`

But I must be doing something wrong because I only get a vertical line graph of commits for my local repository without any commits going to a branch. Any tips how to solve my problem?

Comment: Q: Is this what you're trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1838881/421195

Comment: What you're looking for is certainly `git merge --no-ff sth` (at your step 5). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14865661/9164010) for details.

Comment: _Is_ that a problem? If your branches apply cleanly, why _not_ fast-forward?

Comment: In other words, you "only get a vertical line graph" because you don't have any diverging points in your graph, though you can force it with `--no-ff`.