# updating the underlying branch

Tags: git, version-control

in my version control I have:

- master
- branchA
- branchB

branchA was checked out from master and branchB was checked out from branchA:

master -> branchA -> branchB

Questions:

- if I update and push to branchA then how do I pull the update into branchB?
- is there a way to verify what is the origin of a particular branch (I mean where it was checkout out from, sorry if the terminology is incorrect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge `branchA` into `branchB` would bring you the changes from `branchA` to `branchB`:

```
git checkout branchB
git merge branchA
```

With `git log` you can see your commit history in the terminal and also the *origin*/*emergence* of all branches. Have also a look in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1838873/12632699).

Another approach is a *Git GUI-Client* that visualizes a nice Git history tree by default, giving you a simple overview.

To find a suitable *Git GUI-Client*, see [this](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) documentation.

Comment: You can also rebase branch B.