# Output of git branch in tree like fashion

Tags: git

Right now, when I type "git branch"

it lists my branches in an arbitrary order.

What I would prefer would be if "git branch" listed my output in a tree like fasion, somethign like:

```
master
|-- foo
  |-- foo1
  |-- foo2
|-- bar
  |-- bar4
```

Where here, foo & bar were branched from master; foo1 & foo2 were branched from foo; bar4 was branched from bar.

Is this easy to accomplish?

[Command line utilities only. This needs to fit into my zsh/vim workflow.]

Comment: None of the answers here (my own included) seem to provide an adequate solution for what I think you really want, and for what I know I want. I'm going to write a new utility to solve this when I get the chance. Will probably call it `git_tree`. It will output something like `arc flow` does here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227968/whats-the-difference-between-arc-graft-and-arc-patch/54231342#54231342. Perhaps someday I can even get it merged into git itself.

Comment: This person seems to want the same thing too: https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/282c1f/how_to_see_branch_tree_from_command_line/

Comment: `git log --graph` is enough, I think.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

The [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726638/6309) uses [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

I mentioned a similar approach in 2009 with "[Unable to show a Git tree in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064431/6309)":

```
git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

But the full one I have been using is in "[How to display the tag name and branch name using git log --graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7023272/6309)" (2011):

```
git config --global alias.lgb "log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset%n' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --branches"

git lgb
```

---

Original answer (2010)

[`git show-branch --list`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-branch.html) comes close of what you are looking for (with the topo order)

```
--topo-order
```

> By default, the branches and their commits are shown in reverse chronological order.
>   This option makes them appear in topological order (i.e., descendant commits are shown before their parents).

But the tool [git wtf](https://github.com/michaelklishin/git-wtf) can [help too](http://www.mountainprogramming.com/2009/09/git-wtf-in-git-sh.html). Example:

```
$ git wtf
Local branch: master
[ ] NOT in sync with remote (needs push)
    - Add before-search hook, for shortcuts for custom search queries. [4430d1b] (edwardzyang@...; 7 days ago)
Remote branch: origin/master (git@gitorious.org:sup/mainline.git)
[x] in sync with local

Feature branches:
{ } origin/release-0.8.1 is NOT merged in (1 commit ahead)
    - bump to 0.8.1 [dab43fb] (wmorgan-sup@...; 2 days ago)
[ ] labels-before-subj is NOT merged in (1 commit ahead)
    - put labels before subject in thread index view [790b64d] (marka@...; 4 weeks ago)
{x} origin/enclosed-message-display-tweaks merged in
(x) experiment merged in (only locally)

NOTE: working directory contains modified files
```

> `git-wtf` shows you:
>
> - How your branch relates to the remote repo, if it's a tracking branch.
> - How your branch relates to non-feature ("version") branches, if it's a feature branch.
> - How your branch relates to the feature branches, if it's a version branch

Comment: Been using a variation of your pretty format that shows the author email as well, using %ae. Also I prefer to call the alias by "sl" to resemble hg's smartlog.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link to the `git-wtf` tool, it's insanely useful. Seems to essentially break down the conclusions I would draw from staring at a fancy `git log` tree, but in a nice summary.

Comment: I was hoping to find out a way so that checkout branch should show from which branch it was checked out from

Comment: @ChangZhao That is similar to "finding the parent branch", and that is not easy to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162929/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56452713/6309

Comment: WTF there is no `git wtf` in my git (version 2.25.1)

Comment: @jarno That is expected: `git-wtf` is an executable (ruby script) that you should put in your $PATH in order to be able to execute `git wtf`

Answer (score 177):

It's not quite what you asked for, but

```
git log --graph --simplify-by-decoration --pretty=format:'%d' --all
```

does a pretty good job. It shows tags and remote branches as well. This may not be desirable for everyone, but I find it useful. `--simplifiy-by-decoration` is the big trick here for limiting the refs shown.

I use a similar command to view my log. I've been able to completely replace my `gitk` usage with it:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

I use it by including these aliases in my ~/.gitconfig file:

```
[alias]
    l = log --graph --oneline --decorate
    ll = log --graph --oneline --decorate --branches --tags
    lll = log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

**Edit:** Updated suggested log command/aliases to use simpler option flags.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer here, but I think [SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/) or gitk or the like is the way to go for this kind of thing.

Comment: This displays the branches at the origin. Is there any way to get this to display for the local branches?

Comment: @Jeff replacing `--all` with `--branches --tags` would probably do it.

Answer (score 19):

TLDR; use `git show-tree`, or the `git lg` alias (my preferred choice).

### 1. To show *all branches* (including remote branches) in a tree view:

Use `git show-tree`:

Note: `git show-tree` is *not* part of core `git`. You have to install it as an extra utility, known as "git-extras". On Linux Ubuntu, I do that with `sudo apt install git-extras`. Find your operating system in the installation instructions here and follow the instructions to install it: [Installing git-extras](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Installation.md#installing-git-extras).

**Tested on Ubuntu:**

```bash
# Install it
sudo apt install git-extras

# Run it:
git-show-tree
# OR (same thing)
git show-tree
```

This produces an effect similar to the 2 most upvoted answers here.

Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/git-show-tree.1.html

**Examples:**

`man git show-tree` shows the following example:

> **EXAMPLES**
>
> Output the commit history log for all branches as tree view:
>
> ```bash
> *   4b57684 (HEAD, develop) Merge branch upstream master.
> |\
> | *   515e94a Merge pull request #128 from nickl-/git-extras-html-hyperlinks
> | |\
> | | * 815db8b (nickl/git-extras-html-hyperlinks, git-extras-html-hyperlinks) help ronn make hyperlinks.
> | * | 7398d10 (nickl/develop) Fix #127 git-ignore won´t add duplicates.
> | |/
> | | * ab72c1e (refs/stash) WIP on develop: 5e943f5 Fix #127 git-ignore won´t add duplicates.
> | |/
> |/|
> * | 730ca89 (bolshakov) Rebase bolshakov with master
> |/
> * 60f8371 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge pull request #126 from agrimaldi/fix-changelog-last-tag
> * 9627780 (tag: 1.7.0) Release 1.7.0
> * 2e53ff6 (tag: 1.6.0) Release 1.6.0
> * bbd32d8 (tag: 1.5.1) Release 1.5.1
> | * 6b6b758 (nickl/gh-pages, gh-pages) add example git-extras to gh-pages
> | * 19cfd11 (origin/gh-pages) Index page
> | | * 881a70e (tag: 1.5.0) Release 1.5.0
> | |/
> |/|
> * | 4db5ee0 (tag: 1.4.0) Release 1.4.0
> * | 9b0bc89 (tag: 1.3.0) Release 1.3.0
> * | be49961 (tag: 1.2.0) Release 1.2.0
> * | c1d2dfc (tag: 1.1.0) Release 1.1.0
> * | 4a56adb (tag: 1.0.0) Release 1.0.0
> * | 948308b (tag: 0.9.0) Release 0.9.0
> * | 40b131d (tag: 0.8.1) Release 0.8.1
> * | 391431d (tag: 0.8.0) Release 0.8.0
> ```

And here is a sample output of `git show-tree` on the [ardupilot repo](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot):

[image]

---

Also, if you have **[arcanist](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_quick_start/)** installed (correction: [Uber's fork of arcanist](https://github.com/uber/arcanist) installed--see [the bottom of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227968/whats-the-difference-between-arc-graft-and-arc-patch/54231342#54231342) for installation instructions), `arc flow` shows a beautiful dependency tree of upstream dependencies (ie: which were set previously via `arc flow new_branch` or manually via `git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream_branch`). Example output of `arc flow`:

> ```bash
> master                              
> └──graft-D999
>    └──new_feature_1
>       └──new_feature_2
> ```

I really find the `arc flow` view beautiful and useful, so I have this (inactive, and not-yet-functional) `git tree` open-source project where I plan to duplicate its behavior: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/git-tree.

### 2. To show *one branch* in a "tree-like" fashion:

```bash
# Show the currently-checked-out branch
git lg

# OR: show branch_name
git lg branch_name
```

You can add `-p` or `--patch` to show the lines changed too:

```bash
git lg -p
# OR
git lg --patch
```

To **install the `git lg` alias** (source: https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log):

```bash
git config --global alias.lg "log --color --graph \
--pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) \
%C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit"
```

Example output showing forks and merges and stuff on the [`sshfs` repo](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs):

[image]

### Bonus git tricks:

- [How do I know if I'm running a nested shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511407/how-do-i-know-if-im-running-a-nested-shell/57665918#57665918) - see section here titled **"Bonus: always show in your terminal your current `git branch` you are on too!"**

### Related:

1. [What's the difference between `arc graft` and `arc patch`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227968/whats-the-difference-between-arc-graft-and-arc-patch/54231342#54231342)

Comment: Which version of `git` has `show-tree`? Mine doesn't have it.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn, it's not part of core `git`. You have to install it as an extra utility. On Linux Ubuntu, I do that with `sudo apt install git-extras`. Find your operating system in the installation instructions here and follow the instructions: https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Installation.md#installing-git-extras. I've updated my answer with this information.

Comment: can `git show-tree` ignore tags?

Comment: @alper, I don't know what that means. What do you mean by "ignore tags"? It follows commits.

Comment: @GabrielStaples `(tag:` ... `git-show-tree | grep -Ev "Initial commit|tag: " | grep -v '|'`

Answer (score 12):

The following example shows commit parents as well:

```
git log --graph --all \
--format='%C(cyan dim) %p %Cred %h %C(white dim) %s %Cgreen(%cr)%C(cyan dim) <%an>%C(bold yellow)%d%Creset'
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use a tool called `gitk`.

Comment: I love gitk, but I didn't figure out ```gitk``` in Mac. If you have any suggestion, please let me know. I started using ```Github Desktop``` but love to work on command line.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to do it without having to install anything is as follows:

```
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

If you want to add it as a git alias and be able to run it as `git tree`, just run this command once to configure it globally:

```
git config --global alias.tree "log --graph --oneline --all"
```

This would print something like:

```
*   79655da (HEAD -> main) Merge branch 'test'
|\  
| * cda0da3 (test) Added new test
* | e0bc6cf third
|/  
* 5331b57 second
* 3f5be79 first
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Github, they have a branch [network viewer](https://github.com/kiptoomm/twende-web/network) that seems easier to read

Answer (score 0):

I made a [simple CLI](https://github.com/mucansever/gittree) that exactly does that and put it to brew.