# How to find the nearest parent of a Git branch

Tags: git, branch

Let's say I have the following local repository with a commit tree like this:

```
master --> a
            \
             \
      develop c --> d
               \
                \
         feature f --> g --> h
```

`master` is my *this is the latest stable release code*, `develop` is my *this is the 'next' release code*, and `feature` is *a new feature being prepared for `develop`*.

Using hooks, I want to be able to refuse pushes to `feature` to my remote repository, unless commit `f` is a direct descendant of `develop` HEAD. I.e., the commit tree looks like this, because feature has been `git rebase` on `d`.

```
master --> a
            \
             \
      develop c --> d
                     \
                      \
               feature f --> g --> h
```

So is it possible to:

- Identify the parent branch of `feature`?
- Identify the commit in parent branch which `f` is a descendant of?

From there I would check what HEAD of the parent branch is, and see if `f` predecessor matches the parent branch HEAD, to determine if the feature needs to be rebased.

Comment: Generally, I use `git log --first-parent`,  it will show all the commits from the current branch after that will show the parent branch and its commits

Answer (score 405, accepted):

Assuming that the remote repository has a copy of the *develop* branch (your initial description describes it in a local repository, but it sounds like it also exists in the remote), you should be able to achieve what I think you want, but the approach is a bit different from what you have envisioned.

Git’s history is based on a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of commits. Branches (and “refs” in general) are just transient labels that point to specific commits in the continually growing commit DAG. As such, the relationship between branches can vary over time, but the relationship between commits does not.

```
    ---o---1                foo
            \
             2---3---o      bar
                  \
                   4
                    \
                     5---6  baz
```

It looks like `baz` is based on (an old version of) `bar`? But what if we delete `bar`?

```
    ---o---1                foo
            \
             2---3
                  \
                   4
                    \
                     5---6  baz
```

Now it looks like `baz` is based on `foo`. But the ancestry of `baz` did not change. We just removed a label (and the resulting dangling commit). And what if we add a new label at `4`?

```
    ---o---1                foo
            \
             2---3
                  \
                   4        quux
                    \
                     5---6  baz
```

Now it looks like `baz` is based on `quux`. Still, the ancestry did not change, only the labels changed.

If, however, we were asking “is commit `6` a descendent of commit `3`?” (assuming `3` and `6` are full SHA-1 commit names), then the answer would be “yes”, whether the `bar` and `quux` labels are present or not.

So, you could ask questions like “is the pushed commit a descendent of the current tip of the *develop* branch?”, but you can not reliably ask “what is the parent branch of the pushed commit?”.

A mostly reliable question that seems to get close to what you want is:

> For all the pushed commit’s ancestors (excluding the current tip of *develop* and its ancestors), that have the current tip of *develop* as a parent:
>
> - does at least one such commit exist?
> - are all such commits single-parent commits?

Which could be implemented as:

```sh
pushedrev=...
basename=develop
if ! baserev="$(git rev-parse --verify refs/heads/"$basename" 2>/dev/null)"; then
    echo "'$basename' is missing, call for help!"
    exit 1
fi
parents_of_children_of_base="$(
  git rev-list --pretty=tformat:%P "$pushedrev" --not "$baserev" |
  grep -F "$baserev"
)"
case ",$parents_of_children_of_base" in
    ,)     echo "must descend from tip of '$basename'"
           exit 1 ;;
    ,*\ *) echo "must not merge tip of '$basename' (rebase instead)"
           exit 1 ;;
    ,*)    exit 0 ;;
esac
```

This will cover some of what you want restricted, but maybe not everything.

For reference, here is an extended example history:

```
    A                                   master
     \
      \                    o-----J
       \                  /       \
        \                | o---K---L
         \               |/
          C--------------D              develop
           \             |\
            F---G---H    | F'--G'--H'
                    |    |\
                    |    | o---o---o---N
                     \   \      \       \
                      \   \      o---o---P
                       \   \
                        R---S
```

The above code could be used to reject `H`and `S` while accepting `H'`, `J`, `K`, or `N`, but it would also accept `L` and `P` (they involve merges, but they do not merge the tip of *develop*).

To also reject `L` and `P`, you can change the question and ask

> For all the pushed commit’s ancestors (excluding the current tip of *develop* and its ancestors):
>
> - are there any commits with two parents?
> - if not, does at least one such commit have the current tip of *develop* its (only) parent?

```sh
pushedrev=...
basename=develop
if ! baserev="$(git rev-parse --verify refs/heads/"$basename" 2>/dev/null)"; then
    echo "'$basename' is missing, call for help!"
    exit 1
fi
parents_of_commits_beyond_base="$(
  git rev-list --pretty=tformat:%P "$pushedrev" --not "$baserev" |
  grep -v '^commit '
)"
case "$parents_of_commits_beyond_base" in
    *\ *)          echo "must not push merge commits (rebase instead)"
                   exit 1 ;;
    *"$baserev"*)  exit 0 ;;
    *)             echo "must descend from tip of '$basename'"
                   exit 1 ;;
esac
```

Comment: I get this: git : fatal: ambiguous argument '...': both revision and filename. what is the triple dots intention?

Comment: @Schneider I'm pretty sure the '...' is intended to be a placeholder in this example: if you replace it with the SHA of the commit you're trying to perform this check against (say, the HEAD of the branch you're currently on), everything works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer! It is super useful. I want to make a similar hook, but I don't want to hard-code the name of the development branch. Meaning I want a hook for preventing rebase to a branch other than the parent branch. If I understand your answer well (I'm new to bash and stuff) this is not covered in your answer, right? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you willing to answer a related question?  I was not able to get your code to work on a REMOTE repository.  Here is the link to the follow-up question about how to adapt your approach to work with a REMOTE repository:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619492/find-the-remote-parent-branch-of-a-local-git-branch

Comment: This did not work for me when I had `develop > release > feature`, I would get develop back and it requires knowing the parent. The solution to my issue was https://stackoverflow.com/a/56673640/2366390

Comment: I appreciate the T-Rex holding a flag (or meat cleaver) history graph

Comment: @GrahamRussell: it was called a velociraptor in an earlier comment from some years ago, but that comment seems to have been deleted for a while now.

Comment: Chris and @torek you should check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68207171/git-diff-between-current-branch-and-branch-creation/68207523?noredirect=1#comment120707957_68207523. I referenced this answer in a comment there.

Answer (score 383):

### A rephrasal

Another way to phrase the question is "What is the nearest commit that resides on a branch other than the current branch, and which branch is that?"

### A solution

You can find it with a little bit of command-line magic

```
git show-branch -a \
| sed "s/].*//" \
| grep "\*" \
| grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" \
| head -n1 \
| sed "s/^.*\[//"
```

With [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
git show-branch -a \
| grep '\*' \
| grep -v `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` \
| head -n1 \
| sed 's/[^\[]*//' \
| awk 'match($0, /\[[a-zA-Z0-9\/.-]+\]/) { print substr( $0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2 )}'
```

### Here's how it works:

1. Display a textual history of all commits, including remote branches.
2. Ancestors of the current commit are indicated by a star. Filter out everything else.
3. Ignore all the commits in the current branch.
4. The first result will be the nearest ancestor branch. Ignore the other results.
5. Branch names are displayed [in brackets]. Ignore everything outside the brackets, and the brackets.
6. Sometimes the branch name will include a `~#` or `^#` to indicate how many commits are between the referenced commit and the branch tip. We don't care. Ignore them.

### And the *result*

Running the above code on

```
 A---B---D <-master
      \
       \
        C---E---I <-develop
             \
              \
               F---G---H <-topic
```

Will give you `develop` if you run it from H and `master` if you run it from I.

[The code is available as a gist](https://gist.github.com/joechrysler/6073741).

Comment: Removed a trailing backtick that caused error. When running this command though, I get a large amount of warnings, complaining about each branch saying `cannot handle more than 25 refs`

Comment: @JoeChrysler do you think you can make it one line instead of 2, and possibly make it work on Mac as `ack` is not available on Mac (somebody suggested replacing `ack` with `grep`)

Comment: Sounds like an idea. Works in simplest cases. Here is the version with grep:
    `git show-branch | grep '*' | grep -v '$branch' | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//'`

Comment: Sorry, thats a wrong one. Here is the correct one that worked for me: `git show-branch | grep '*' | grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//'`

Comment: I added a git alias configuration as comments on the gist. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: @droidbot Nice, but needs piping reordering to avoid removal of refs when grep -v catch commit message or your branch name is part of another branch name.
`git show-branch | sed "s/].*//" | grep "\*" | grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" | head -n1 | sed "s/^.*\[//"`

Comment: I encountered a situation where this doesn't work - a branch with an ancestor that is no longer present in the local checkout. The branch was first created from the `develop` branch, but then had a divergent `master` merged into it. Then the local `develop` was deleted (it remained on origin). This causes that ancestor branch to not turn up in `git show-branch` output, and it's not the first entry marked with a wildcard, and this parser flies by and doesn't catch that. Maybe just document the fact that this process depends on being run on the git checkout where the branch was created.

Comment: ack is not a standard *nix command.  (Works with grep instead).

Comment: How to add this long command as an alias? Doesn't work in this way `git config --global alias.parent "show-branch | sed "s/].*//" | grep "\*" | grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" | head -n1 | sed "s/^.*\[//""`. Error about | character.

Comment: @OlegAbrazhaev I dont know if you ever got your question answered. using the git alias of: `parent = "!git show-branch | grep '*' | grep -v \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\\[\\(.*\\)\\].*/\\1/' | sed 's/[\\^~].*//' #"` works for me

Comment: Are you willing to answer a related question?  I was not able to get your code to work on a REMOTE repository.  Here is the link to the follow-up question about how to adapt your approach to work with a REMOTE repository:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619492/find-the-remote-parent-branch-of-a-local-git-branch

Comment: @JoeChrysler The comments are confusing. Can you please flag those that have been integrated into the answer in some way?

Comment: I like this one because it's very clear how to find e.g. the "best matching" release branch `release-*`, or some other pattern.

Comment: One problem is when the nearest labeled ancestor has two labels.  For example, we just shipped r/4.1, which is still on the same commit as master.  Which is the nearest parent of a subsequent feature branch?  Thus, this strategy can be helpful for the question above, but in general it is impossible to get a single, reliable answer regarding the nearest ancestor.

Comment: The sed version doesn't include the -a option to show-branch and so probably doesn't behave the same as the awk version or the way the description says it will.

Comment: The rephrasal is wrong for some reasons: "the nearest commit that resides on a branch other than the current branch" 1. The original question is what was the branch *at the time of the creation of the current branch*. Branches are pointers - they move, and they get deleted, thus the rephrasal answers another question. 2. The commit can reside on more than one branch, thus even this is not really answerable.

Comment: This used to work for me for checking that I was off master (not further removed) but it broke when my repo got too big.  Its probably related to this warning that git now gives: warning: ignoring master; cannot handle more than 26 refs

Comment: +1 here, but i think the approach is a little overkill and would be great something that does work even if the branch is not checked out, so wondering if someone thought on filing a ticket for such a feature to be bundled directly into the git program, using a single straight command. (?)

Comment: Its not working for me on windows 10 system

Comment: Shorter sed-expression: `git show-branch | grep '*' | grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\([^\^~]*\).*\].*/\1/'`

Answer (score 202):

### Git parent

You can just run the command

```
git parent
```

to find the parent of the branch, if you add the [Joe Chrysler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/how-to-find-the-nearest-parent-of-a-git-branch/17843908#17843908) as a **Git alias**. It will simplify the usage.

Open the *gitconfig* file located at `"~/.gitconfig"` by using any text editor (for Linux). And for Windows the  ".gitconfig" path is generally located at `C:\users\your-user\.gitconfig`.

```
vim  ~/.gitconfig
```

Add the following alias command in the file:

```
[alias]
    parent = "!git show-branch | grep '*' | grep -v \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\\[\\(.*\\)\\].*/\\1/' | sed 's/[\\^~].*//' #"
```

Save and exit the editor.

Run the command `git parent`.

That's it!

Comment: Getting `cannot handle more than 25 refs` exception.

Comment: can someone edit this to handle the warning ?  @ttemple, can you ?

Comment: @NIKHILCM works like a Champion. But I have a question over here whether the parent indicates from where the branch created or something else?

Comment: @NIKHILCM Blessings

Comment: git log --first-parent this worked

https://github.community/t/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-parent-branch-from-which-branch-head-is-detached-for-detached-head/825/4

Comment: @shajin & others: If you want to mute the warnings, you can pipe the stderr of git show-branch to stdout as such: `git show-branch 2>&1 | ...`. The following sed/grep will filter out the warnings that way. Alternatively you can also pipe error to /dev/null via `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: @NIKHILCM not working for me on windows 10 system

Comment: git parent gives me:
`git: 'parent' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: This is not _an answer_, but _way of applying_ a (someone else's) answer. So it should have been a comment under respective (or basically any) answer, not a separate answer

Comment: @skittlebiz did you add the alias first?

Comment: @andresF no, I guess I skipped that step. But, thanks!

Comment: not working on mac

Answer (score 178):

You can also try:

```
git log --graph --decorate
```

Comment: `git log --graph --decorate --simplify-by-decoration` where `--graph` is optional.

Comment: `git log --graph --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --oneline`

Comment: git log  --decorate=full --simplify-by-decoration --oneline  --format="%D"

Comment: This worked for me to get just the branch names: `git log --graph --decorate --oneline | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | sed 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/' | tr ',' '\n' | tr -d ' '`

Answer (score 69):

This is working fine for me:

```
git show-branch | grep '*' | grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//'
```

Courtesy comment and answers [from droidbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/how-to-find-the-nearest-parent-of-a-git-branch#comment35666518_17843908) and @Jistanidiot.

Comment: `*` is not a proper regex to pass to grep.
Should use `grep -F '*'` or `grep '\*'` instead.
Good solution otherwise.

Comment: I get lots of ``cannot handle more than 26 refs``.

Answer (score 62):

I have a solution to your overall problem (determine if `feature` is descended from the tip of `develop`), but it doesn't work using the method you outlined.

You can use `git branch --contains` to list all the branches descended from the tip of `develop`, then use `grep` to make sure `feature` is among them.

```
git branch --contains develop | grep "^ *feature$"
```

If it is among them, it will print `"  feature"` to standard output and have a return code of 0.     Otherwise, it will print nothing and have a return code of 1.

Comment: This works but it should be noted that it can take a long time on a repository that has a lot of refs. That makes it a bit less than ideal for running in, e.g., a pre-receive hook.

Comment: I was looking for the branch, we'll call it `<branch>`, where i performed: 

`git checkout -b <branch-2>` from...

THIS is the answer!

No need for grep, really. 

`git branch --contains <branch>`

Comment: this is answer is for finding children

Answer (score 43):

## Why isn't there a Parent in the House?

### What to Expect Below

**gists:**

- **[gitr: find (likely multiple) related branches](https://gist.github.com/rsitze/aa985fee5cbe56ae32ff90c1ada96707)**
- **[gitp: find likely parents via git-flow-like internal rules/regex](https://gist.github.com/rsitze/6a9d0ac280bca850e2471634a3f83204)**

Why would anyone want to read this long post?
Because while previous answers clearly
understand the problem with the original question,
they fall short of correct/meaningful results;
or accurately solve a *different* problem.

Feel free to just review the first section;
it solves the "find something" problem and
should highlight scope of the problem.
For some, that may be sufficient.

This will show you a way to
extract correct & meaningful results from git
(you may not like them),
and demonstrate one way to apply
your knowledge of your conventions
to those results
to extract what you are really looking for.

Sections below cover:

- **An Unbiased Question & Solution**:

  - nearest git branches using `git show-branch`.
  - what expected results should look like
- **Example Graph & Results**
- **Batching Branches**: work around limits of `git show-branch`
- **A Biased Question & Solution**:
  introducing (naming) conventions to improve results

## The Problem with The Question

As has been mentioned, git does not track relationships between branches;
branches are simply names referencing a commit.
In official git documentation and other sources we'll often encounter somewhat misleading diagrams such as:

```
A---B---C---D    <- master branch
     \
      E---F      <- work branch
```

Let's change the form of the diagram and the hierarchically suggestive names to show an equivalent graph:

```
      E---F   <- jack
     /
A---B
     \
      C---D   <- jill
```

The graph (and hence git) tells us absolutely nothing about which branch was created first (hence, which was branched off the other).

That `master` is a parent of `work` in the first graph is a matter of convention.

**Therefore**

- **simple tooling will produce responses that ignore the bias**
- **more complex tooling incorporates conventions (biases).**

## An Unbiased Question

First, I must acknowledge primarily Joe Chrysler's response, other responses here, and the many comments/suggestions all around;
they inspired and pointed the way for me!

Allow me to rephrase Joe's rephrasal, giving consideration to multiple branches related to that nearest commit (it happens!):

> "What is the nearest commit that resides on a branch other than the
> current branch, and which branches is that?"

Or, in other words:

#### Q1

> Given a branch `B`:
> consider the commit `C` nearest to `B'HEAD`
> (`C` could be `B'HEAD`)
> that is shared by other branches:
> what branches, other than `B`, have `C` in their commit history?

### An Unbiased Solution

Apologies up front; it seems folks prefer one-liners.  Feel free to suggest (readable/maintainable) improvements!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

# git show-branch supports 29 branches; reserve 1 for current branch
GIT_SHOW_BRANCH_MAX=28

CURRENT_BRANCH="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
if (( $? != 0 )); then
    echo "Failed to determine git branch; is this a git repo?" >&2
    exit 1
fi


##
# Given Params:
#   EXCEPT : $1
#   VALUES : $2..N
#
# Return all values except EXCEPT, in order.
#
function valuesExcept() {
    local except=$1 ; shift
    for value in "$@"; do
        if [[ "$value" != "$except" ]]; then
            echo $value
        fi
    done
}


##
# Given Params:
#   BASE_BRANCH : $1           : base branch; default is current branch
#   BRANCHES    : [ $2 .. $N ] : list of unique branch names (no duplicates);
#                                perhaps possible parents.
#                                Default is all branches except base branch.
#
# For the most recent commit in the commit history for BASE_BRANCH that is
# also in the commit history of at least one branch in BRANCHES: output all
# BRANCHES that share that commit in their commit history.
#
function nearestCommonBranches() {
    local BASE_BRANCH
    if [[ -z "${1+x}" || "$1" == '.' ]]; then
        BASE_BRANCH="$CURRENT_BRANCH"
    else
        BASE_BRANCH="$1"
    fi

    shift
    local -a CANDIDATES
    if [[ -z "${1+x}" ]]; then
        CANDIDATES=( $(git rev-parse --symbolic --branches) )
    else
        CANDIDATES=("$@")
    fi
    local BRANCHES=( $(valuesExcept "$BASE_BRANCH" "${CANDIDATES[@]}") )

    local BRANCH_COUNT=${#BRANCHES[@]}
    if (( $BRANCH_COUNT > $GIT_SHOW_BRANCH_MAX )); then
        echo "Too many branches: limit $GIT_SHOW_BRANCH_MAX" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    local MAP=( $(git show-branch --topo-order "${BRANCHES[@]}" "$BASE_BRANCH" \
                    | tail -n +$(($BRANCH_COUNT+3)) \
                    | sed "s/ \[.*$//" \
                    | sed "s/ /_/g" \
                    | sed "s/*/+/g" \
                    | egrep '^_*[^_].*[^_]$' \
                    | head -n1 \
                    | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'
          ) )

    for idx in "${!BRANCHES[@]}"; do
        ## to include "merge", symbolized by '-', use
        ## ALT: if [[ "${MAP[$idx]}" != "_" ]]
        if [[ "${MAP[$idx]}" == "+" ]]; then
            echo "${BRANCHES[$idx]}"
        fi
    done
}

# Usage: gitr [ baseBranch [branchToConsider]* ]
#   baseBranch: '.' (no quotes needed) corresponds to default current branch
#   branchToConsider* : list of unique branch names (no duplicates);
#                        perhaps possible (bias?) parents.
#                        Default is all branches except base branch.
nearestCommonBranches "${@}"
```

#### How it Works

##### Considering Output of: `git show-branch`

For `git show-branch --topo-order feature/g hotfix master release/2 release/3 feature/d`, the output would look similar to:

```
! [feature/g] TEAM-12345: create X
 * [hotfix] TEAM-12345: create G
  ! [master] TEAM-12345: create E
   ! [release/2] TEAM-12345: create C
    ! [release/3] TEAM-12345: create C
     ! [feature/d] TEAM-12345: create S
------
+      [feature/g] TEAM-12345: create X
+      [feature/g^] TEAM-12345: create W
     + [feature/d] TEAM-12345: create S
     + [feature/d^] TEAM-12345: create R
     + [feature/d~2] TEAM-12345: create Q
        ...
  +    [master] TEAM-12345: create E
 *     [hotfix] TEAM-12345: create G
 *     [hotfix^] TEAM-12345: create F
 *+    [master^] TEAM-12345: create D
+*+++  [release/2] TEAM-12345: create C
+*++++ [feature/d~8] TEAM-12345: create B
```

A few points:

- the original command listed N (6) branch names on the command line
- those branch names appear, in order, as the first N lines of the output
- the lines following the header represent commits
- the first N columns of the commit lines represent (as a whole) a "**branch/commit matrix**", where a single character in column `X` indicates the relationship (or lack of) between a branch (header row `X`) and the current commit.

##### Primary Steps

1. Given a `BASE_BRANCH`
2. Given an ordered set (unique) `BRANCHES` that does not include `BASE_BRANCH`
3. For brevity, let `N` be `BRANCH_COUNT`,
   which is the size of `BRANCHES`;
   it does not include `BASE_BRANCH`
4. `git show-branch --topo-order $BRANCHES $BASE_BRANCH`:

   - Since `BRANCHES` contains only unique names (presumed valid)
     the names will map 1-1 with the header lines of the output,
     and correspond to the first N columns of the branch/commit matrix.
   - Since `BASE_BRANCH` is not in `BRANCHES`
     it will be the last of the header lines,
     and corresponds to the last column branch/commit matrix.
5. `tail`: start with line `N+3`; throw away the first `N+2` lines: N branches + base branch + separator row `---..`.
6. `sed`: these could be combined in one... but are separated for clarity

   - remove everything after the branch/commit matrix
   - replace spaces with underscores '_';
     my primary reason was to avoid potential IFS parsing hassles
     and for debugging/readability.
   - replace `*` with `+`; base branch is always in last column,
     and that's sufficient.  Also, if left alone it goes through `bash`
     pathname expansion, and that's always fun with `*`
7. `egrep`: grep for commits that map to at least one branch (`[^_]`) AND to the BASE_BRANCH (`[^_]$`).  Maybe that base branch pattern should be `\+$`?
8. `head -n1`: take the first remaining commit
9. `sed`: separate each character of the branch/commit matrix to separate lines.
10. Capture the lines in an array `MAP`, at which point we have two arrays:

    - `BRANCHES`: length `N`
    - `MAP`: length `N+1`: first `N` elements 1-1 with `BRANCHES`, and the last element corresponding to the `BASE_BRANCH`.
11. Iterate over `BRANCHES` (that's all we want, and it's shorter) and check corresponding element in `MAP`: output `BRANCH[$idx]` if `MAP[$idx]` is `+`.

## Example Graph & Results

Consider the following somewhat contrived example graph:

- Biased names will be used, as they help (me) weigh and consider results.
- Presume merges exist and are being ignored.
- The graph generally attempts to highlight branches as such (forking),
  without visually suggesting a preference/hierarchy;
  ironically `master` stands out after I was done with this thing.

```
                         J                   <- feature/b
                        /
                       H
                      / \ 
                     /   I                   <- feature/a
                    /
                   D---E                     <- master
                  / \ 
                 /   F---G                   <- hotfix
                /
       A---B---C                             <- feature/f, release/2, release/3
            \   \ 
             \   W--X                        <- feature/g
              \ 
               \       M                     <- support/1
                \     /
                 K---L                       <- release/4
                      \ 
                       \       T---U---V     <- feature/e
                        \     /
                         N---O
                              \ 
                               P             <- feature/c
                                \ 
                                 Q---R---S   <- feature/d
```

### Unbiased Results for Example Graph

Assuming the script is in executable file `gitr`, then run:

```
gitr <baseBranch>
```

For different branches `B` we obtain the following results:

| GIVEN B | Shared Commit C | Branches !B with C in their history? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| feature/a | H | feature/b |
| feature/b | H | feature/a |
| feature/c | P | feature/d |
| feature/d | P | feature/c |
| feature/e | O | feature/c, feature/d |
| feature/f | C | feature/a, feature/b, feature/g, hotfix, master, release/2, release/3 |
| feature/g | C | feature/a, feature/b, feature/f, hotfix, master, release/2, release/3 |
| hotfix | D | feature/a, feature/b, master |
| master | D | feature/a, feature/b, hotfix |
| release/2 | C | feature/a, feature/b, feature/f, feature/g, hotfix, master, release/3 |
| release/3 | C | feature/a, feature/b, feature/f, feature/g, hotfix, master, release/2 |
| release/4 | L | feature/c, feature/d, feature/e, support/1 |
| support/1 | L | feature/c, feature/d, feature/e, release/4 |

## Batching Branches

[Presented at this stage
because it fits best into final script at this point.
*This section is not required, feel free to skip forward.*]

`git show-branch` limits itself to 29 branches.
That maybe a blocker for some (no judgement, just sayin!).

We can improve results, in some situations,
by grouping branches into batches.

- BASE_BRANCH must be submitted with each branch.
- If there are a large number of branches in a repo
  this may have limited value, by itself.
- May provide more value if you find other ways
  to limit the branches (that would be batched).
- The previous point fits my use case,
  so charging ahead!

***This mechanism is NOT perfect,
as the result size approaches the max (29),
expect it to fail.  Details below***

### Batch Solution

```
#
# Remove/comment-out the function call at the end of script,
# and append this to the end.
##

##
# Given:
#   BASE_BRANCH : $1           : first param on every batch
#   BRANCHES    : [ $2 .. $N ] : list of unique branch names (no duplicates);
#                                perhaps possible parents
#                                Default is all branches except base branch.
#
# Output all BRANCHES that share that commit in their commit history.
#
function repeatBatchingUntilStableResults() {
    local BASE_BRANCH="$1"

    shift
    local -a CANDIDATES
    if [[ -z "${1+x}" ]]; then
        CANDIDATES=( $(git rev-parse --symbolic --branches) )
    else
        CANDIDATES=("$@")
    fi
    local BRANCHES=( $(valuesExcept "$BASE_BRANCH" "${CANDIDATES[@]}") )

    local SIZE=$GIT_SHOW_BRANCH_MAX
    local COUNT=${#BRANCHES[@]}
    local LAST_COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))

    local NOT_DONE=1
    while (( $NOT_DONE && $COUNT < $LAST_COUNT )); do
        NOT_DONE=$(( $SIZE < $COUNT ))
        LAST_COUNT=$COUNT

        local -a BRANCHES_TO_BATCH=( "${BRANCHES[@]}" )
        local -a AGGREGATE=()
        while (( ${#BRANCHES_TO_BATCH[@]} > 0 )); do
            local -a BATCH=( "${BRANCHES_TO_BATCH[@]:0:$SIZE}" )
            AGGREGATE+=( $(nearestCommonBranches "$BASE_BRANCH" "${BATCH[@]}") )
            BRANCHES_TO_BATCH=( "${BRANCHES_TO_BATCH[@]:$SIZE}" )
        done
        BRANCHES=( "${AGGREGATE[@]}" )
        COUNT=${#BRANCHES[@]}
    done
    if (( ${#BRANCHES[@]} > $SIZE )); then
        echo "Unable to reduce candidate branches below MAX for git-show-branch" >&2
        echo "  Base Branch : $BASE_BRANCH" >&2
        echo "  MAX Branches: $SIZE" >&2
        echo "  Candidates  : ${BRANCHES[@]}" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "${BRANCHES[@]}"
}

repeatBatchingUntilStableResults "$@"
exit 0
```

### How it Works

Repeat until results stabilize

1. Break `BRANCHES` into batches of
   `GIT_SHOW_BRANCH_MAX` (aka `SIZE`) elements
2. call `nearestCommonBranches BASE_BRANCH BATCH`
3. Aggregating results into a new (smaller?) set of branches

#### How it can fail

If the number of aggregated branches exceeds the max `SIZE`
and further batching/processing cannot reduce that number
then either:

- the aggregated branches IS the solution,
  but that can't be verified by `git show-branch`, or
- each batch doesn't reduce;
  possibly a branch from one batch would help reduce another
  (diff merge base); the current algo admits defeat and fails.

### Consider Alternative

Individually pairing a base branch with every other branch of interest, determine a commit node (merge base) for each pair; sorting the set of merge bases in commit history order, taking the nearest node, determining all branches associated with that node.

I present that from a position of hindsight.
It's probably really the right way to go.
I'm moving forward;
perhaps there is value outside of the current topic.

## A Biased Question

You may have noted that the core function `nearestCommonBranches`
in the earlier script answers more than question Q1 asks.
In fact, the function answers a more general question:

#### Q2

> Given a branch `B` and
> an ordered set (no duplicates) `P` of branches (`B` not in `P`):
> consider the commit `C` nearest to `B'HEAD` (`C` could be `B'HEAD`)
> that is shared by branches in `P`:
> in order per order-of-P, what branches in P have C in their commit history?

Choosing `P` provides bias, or describes a (limited) convention.
To match all the characteristics of your biases/convention may require additional tools, which is out-of-scope for this discussion.

### Modeling Simple Bias/Convention

Bias varies for different organization & practices,
and the following may not be suitable for your organization.
If nothing else, perhaps some of the ideas here might help
you find a solution to your needs.

### A Biased Solution; Bias by Branch Naming Convention

Perhaps the bias can be mapped into, and extracted from,
the naming convention in use.

#### Bias by `P` (Those Other Branch Names)

We're going to need this for the next step,
so let's see what we can do by filtering branch names by regex.

**The combined previous code and the new code below is available as a [gist: gitr](https://gist.github.com/rsitze/aa985fee5cbe56ae32ff90c1ada96707)**

```
#
# Remove/comment-out the function call at the end of script,
# and append this to the end.
##

##
# Given Params:
#   BASE_BRANCH : $1           : base branch
#   REGEXs      : $2 [ .. $N ] : regex(s)
#
# Output:
#   - git branches matching at least one of the regex params
#   - base branch is excluded from result
#   - order: branches matching the Nth regex will appear before
#            branches matching the (N+1)th regex.
#   - no duplicates in output
#
function expandUniqGitBranches() {
    local -A BSET[$1]=1
    shift

    local ALL_BRANCHES=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --branches)
    for regex in "$@"; do
        for branch in $ALL_BRANCHES; do
            ## RE: -z ${BSET[$branch]+x ...  ; presumes ENV 'x' is not defined
            if [[ $branch =~ $regex && -z "${BSET[$branch]+x}" ]]; then
                echo "$branch"
                BSET[$branch]=1
            fi
        done
    done
}


##
# Params:
#   BASE_BRANCH: $1    : "." equates to the current branch;
#   REGEXS     : $2..N : regex(es) corresponding to other to include
#
function findBranchesSharingFirstCommonCommit() {
    if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
        echo "Usage: findBranchesSharingFirstCommonCommit ( . | baseBranch ) [ regex [ ... ] ]" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    local BASE_BRANCH
    if [[ -z "${1+x}" || "$1" == '.' ]]; then
        BASE_BRANCH="$CURRENT_BRANCH"
    else
        BASE_BRANCH="$1"
    fi

    shift
    local REGEXS
    if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
        REGEXS=(".*")
    else
        REGEXS=("$@")
    fi

    local BRANCHES=( $(expandUniqGitBranches "$BASE_BRANCH" "${REGEXS[@]}") )

## nearestCommonBranches  can also be used here, if batching not used.
    repeatBatchingUntilStableResults "$BASE_BRANCH" "${BRANCHES[@]}"
}

findBranchesSharingFirstCommonCommit "$@"
```

##### Biased Results for Example Graph

Let's consider the ordered set

> `P = { ^release/.*$ ^support/.*$ ^master$ }`

Assuming the script (all parts) is in executable file `gitr`, then run:

```
gitr <baseBranch> '^release/.*$' '^support/.*$' '^master$'
```

For different branches `B` we obtain the following results:

| GIVEN B | Shared Commit C | Branches P with C in their history (in order) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| feature/a | D | master |
| feature/b | D | master |
| feature/c | L | release/4, support/1 |
| feature/d | L | release/4, support/1 |
| feature/e | L | release/4, support/1 |
| feature/f | C | release/2, release/3, master |
| feature/g | C | release/2, release/3, master |
| hotfix | D | master |
| master | C | release/2, release/3 |
| release/2 | C | release/3, master |
| release/3 | C | release/2, master |
| release/4 | L | support/1 |
| support/1 | L | release/4 |

That's getting closer to a definitive answer; the responses for release branches aren't ideal.  Let's take this one step further.

#### Bias by `BASE_NAME` and `P`

One direction to take this could be to use different `P` for different
base names. Let's work out a design for that.

##### Conventions

***DISCLAIMER: A git flow purist I am not, make allowances for me please***

- A support branch shall branch off master.

  - There will NOT be two support branches sharing a common commit.
- A hotfix branch shall branch off a support branch or master.
- A release branch shall branch off a support branch or master.

  - There may be multiple release branches sharing a common commit;
    i.e. branched off master at the same time.
- A bugfix branch shall branch off a release branch.
- a feature branch may branch off a feature, release, support, or master:

  - for the purpose of "parent",
    one feature branch cannot be established as
    a parent over another (see initial discussion).
  - therefore: skip feature branches and
    look for "parent" among release, support, and/or master branches.
- any other branch name to be considered a working branch,
  with same conventions as a feature branch.

Let's see how far we `git` with this:

| Base Branch Pattern | Parent Branches, Ordered | Comment(s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ^master$ | n/a | no parent |
| ^support/.*$ | ^master$ |  |
| ^hotfix/.*$ | ^support/.*$ ^master$ | give preference to a support branch over master (ordering) |
| ^release/.*$ | ^support/.*$ ^master$ | give preference to a support branch over master (ordering) |
| ^bugfix/.*$ | ^release/.*$ |  |
| ^feature/.*$ | ^release/.*$ ^support/.*$ ^master$ |  |
| ^.*$ | ^release/.*$ ^support/.*$ ^master$ | Redundant, but keep design concerns separate |

##### Script

**The combined previous code and the new code below is available as a [gist: gitp](https://gist.github.com/rsitze/6a9d0ac280bca850e2471634a3f83204)**

```
#
# Remove/comment-out the function call at the end of script,
# and append this to the end.
##

# bash associative arrays maintain key/entry order.
# So, use two maps, values correlated by index:
declare -a MAP_BASE_BRANCH_REGEX=( "^master$" \
                                       "^support/.*$" \
                                       "^hotfix/.*$" \
                                       "^release/.*$" \
                                       "^bugfix/.*$" \
                                       "^feature/.*$" \
                                       "^.*$" )

declare -a MAP_BRANCHES_REGEXS=("" \
                                    "^master$" \
                                    "^support/.*$ ^master$" \
                                    "^support/.*$ ^master$" \
                                    "^release/.*$" \
                                    "^release/.*$ ^support/.*$ ^master$" \
                                    "^release/.*$ ^support/.*$ ^master$" )

function findBranchesByBaseBranch() {
    local BASE_BRANCH
    if [[ -z "${1+x}" || "$1" == '.' ]]; then
        BASE_BRANCH="$CURRENT_BRANCH"
    else
        BASE_BRANCH="$1"
    fi

    for idx in "${!MAP_BASE_BRANCH_REGEX[@]}"; do
        local BASE_BRANCH_REGEX=${MAP_BASE_BRANCH_REGEX[$idx]}
        if [[ "$BASE_BRANCH" =~ $BASE_BRANCH_REGEX ]]; then
            local BRANCHES_REGEXS=( ${MAP_BRANCHES_REGEXS[$idx]} )
            if (( ${#BRANCHES_REGEXS[@]} > 0 )); then
                findBranchesSharingFirstCommonCommit $BASE_BRANCH "${BRANCHES_REGEXS[@]}"
            fi
            break
        fi
    done
}

findBranchesByBaseBranch "$1"
```

###### Biased Results for Example Graph

Assuming the script (all parts) is in executable file `gitr`, then run:

```
gitr <baseBranch>
```

For different branches `B` we obtain the following results:

| GIVEN B | Shared Commit C | Branches P with C in their history (in order) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| feature/a | D | master |
| feature/b | D | master |
| feature/c | L | release/4, support/1 |
| feature/d | L | release/4, support/1 |
| feature/e | L | release/4, support/1 |
| feature/f | C | release/2, release/3, master |
| feature/g | C | release/2, release/3, master |
| hotfix | D | master |
| master |  | (blank, no value) |
| release/2 | C | master |
| release/3 | C | master |
| release/4 | L | support/1 |
| support/1 | L | master |

###### Refactor for the Win!

Opportunities!

In this last example, the release branch shares a common commit
with multiple others: release, support, or master branches.

Let's "refactor" or re-evaluate the conventions in used, and tight them a bit.

Consider this `git` usage convention:

> When creating a new release branch:
> immediately create a new commit; perhaps update a version, or the README file.
> This ensures that feature/work branches
> for the release (branched off the release)
> will have the commit shared with the release branch
> prior to (and not shared by) the commit for the underlying
> support or master branch.

For example:

```
        G---H   <- feature/z
       /
      E         <- release/1
     /
A---B---C---D   <- master
     \
      F         <- release/2
```

A feature branches off release/1 could not have a common commit
that includes release/1 (it's parent) and master or release/2.

That provides one result, the parent, for every branch,
with these conventions.

DONE! with tools and conventions, I can live in an OCD friendly structured git world.

Your mileage may vary!

## Parting thoughts

1. gists

- [gitr: find (likely multiple) related branches](https://gist.github.com/rsitze/aa985fee5cbe56ae32ff90c1ada96707)
- [gitp: find likely parents via git-flow-like internal rules/regex](https://gist.github.com/rsitze/6a9d0ac280bca850e2471634a3f83204)

1. Foremost: I've come to the conclusion that,
   beyond what's been presented here,
   at some point one may need to accept that there may be multiple
   branches do deal with.

   - Perhaps validations might be done on all potential branches;
     "at-least-one" or "all" or ?? rules might be applied.
2. It's weeks like this that I really think it's time I learn Python.

Comment: massively underrated answer

Comment: How to run this on a windows machine? https://gist.github.com/rsitze/6a9d0ac280bca850e2471634a3f83204

Comment: @viveknuna: These are bash scripts depending on various unix command line tools.  You might try cygwin.  I hear also that newer windows has a linux sub-system, you might try that.

Comment: If I ever get to this, I might rewrite it in PowerShell (the cross-platform Core version).

Comment: Can concirm that most of the solutions listed here work on WSL Ubuntu. Joe Chrysler's answer also works in Git Bash for Windows. @VivekNuna

Answer (score 28):

#### A solution

The solution [based on `git show-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17843908/1138663) did not quite work for me (see below), so I've combined it with the one [based on `git log`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43585658/1138663) and ended up with this:

```
git log --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --oneline \ # selects only commits with a branch or tag
      | grep -v "(HEAD" \                               # removes current head (and branch)
      | head -n1 \                                      # selects only the closest decoration
      | sed 's/.* (\(.*\)) .*/\1/' \                    # filters out everything but decorations
      | sed 's/\(.*\), .*/\1/' \                        # picks only the first decoration
      | sed 's/origin\///'                              # strips "origin/" from the decoration
```

#### Limitations and Caveats

- HEAD can be detached (many CI tools do so to ensure they build correct commit in a given branch), but **origin branch and local branch** have to be both **at par or "above"** the current HEAD.
- There must be **no tags** in the way (I presume; I have not tested the script on commits with a tag between child and parent branch)
- the script relies on the fact **"HEAD"** is always **listed as the first decoration** by the `log` command
- **running** the script **on `master` and `develop`** results (mostly) in `<SHA> Initial commit`

#### The results

```
 A---B---D---E---F <-origin/master, master
      \      \
       \      \
        \      G---H---I <- origin/hotfix, hotfix
         \
          \
           J---K---L <-origin/develop, develop
                \
                 \
                  M---N---O <-origin/feature/a, feature/a
                       \   \
                        \   \
                         \   P---Q---R <-origin/feature/b, feature/b
                          \
                           \
                            S---T---U <-origin/feature/c, feature/c
```

Despite local branch existence (e.g. only `origin/topic` is present since the commit `O` was checked-out by directly by its SHA), the script should print as follows:

- For commits **`G`, `H`, `I`** (branch `hotfix`) → **`master`**
- For commits **`M`, `N`, `O`** (branch `feature/a`) → **`develop`**
- For commits **`S`, `T`, `U`** (branch `feature/c`) → **`develop`**
- For commits **`P`, `Q`, `R`** (branch `feature/b`) → **`feature/a`**
- For commits `J`, `K`, `L` (branch `develop`) → `<sha> Initial commit`*
- For commits `B`, `D`, `E`, `F` (branch `master`) → `<sha> Initial commit`

* - or `master` if `develop`'s commits were on top of master's HEAD (~ the master would be fast-forwardable to develop)

---

#### Why did not show-branch work for me

The solution [based on `git show-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17843908/1138663) proved unreliable for me in the following situations:

- **detached HEAD** – including detached head case means replacing `grep '\*' \` for `grep '!' \ – and that is just the beginning of all the troubles
- **running** the script **on `master` and `develop`** results in `develop` and `` respectively
- **branches on `master`** branch (`hotfix/` branches) end up with the `develop` as a parent since their closest `master` branch parent was marked with `!` instead of `*` for a reason.

Comment: Only answer that worked - as a git alias: `"!git log --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --oneline | grep -v '(HEAD' | head -n1 | sed 's/.* (\\(.*\\)) .*/\\1/' | sed 's/\\(.*\\), .*/\\1/' | sed 's/origin\\///'"`

Comment: this command worked for me  git log --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --oneline | grep -v "(HEAD" | head -n1 | sed 's/.* (\(.*\)) .*/\1/' | sed 's/\(.*\), .*/\1/' | sed 's/origin\///'

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :/

Comment: This can be condensed to `git --no-pager log --simplify-by-decoration --format="format:%D%n" -n1 --decorate-refs-exclude=refs/tags HEAD~1` which may show more than one branch. Add `| sed 's/\(.*\), .+/\1/'` to get just the first branch.

Comment: This worked well for me, but it had a few problems. First, it wouldn't properly return a single decoration (e.g. when there were multiple common ancestors, such as `origin/main, origin/feature/foo`). Second, it didn't strip the `tag: ` prefix if the ancestor was a tag. Here's the updated version that handles both of these scenarios: `git log --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --oneline | grep -v "(HEAD" | head -n1 | sed 's/.* (\(.*\)) .*/\1/' | sed 's/\([^,]*\), .*/\1/' | sed 's/tag: //'`

Comment: Hello @Matt , How to learn about git from intermediate to advance so that i know everything about it?

Comment: Instead of parsing remote refs, we can filter them out by means of git: `git --no-pager log --simplify-by-decoration --format="format:%D%n" -n1 --decorate-refs-exclude=refs/remotes HEAD~1`

Comment: This  should be the answer, additionaly I add a sed `-e 's/, /\n/` to show possible branches in one line and delete tags with `grep -v 'tag:'` https://pastebin.com/jPH8EPkw

Answer (score 15):

Since none of the previous answers worked on our repository, I want to share my own way, using latest merges in `git log`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

git log --oneline --merges "$@" | grep into | sed 's/.* into //g' | uniq --count | head -n 10
```

Put it in a script named `git-last-merges`, which also accepts a branch name as argument (instead of current branch) as well as other `git log` arguments.

From the output, we can manually detect the parent branch(es) based on own branching conventions and number of merges from each branch.

If you use `git rebase` on child branches often (and merges are fast-forwarded often so there aren't too many merge commits), this answer won't work well, so I wrote a script to count ahead commits (normal and merge), and behind commits (there shouldn't be any behind merge in parent branch) on all branches comparing to the current branch.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

HEAD="`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`"
echo "Comparing to $HEAD"
printf "%12s  %12s   %10s     %s\n" "Behind" "BehindMerge" "Ahead" "Branch"
git branch | grep -v '^*' | sed 's/^\* //g' | while read branch ; do
    ahead_merge_count=`git log --oneline --merges $branch ^$HEAD | wc -l`
    if [[ $ahead_merge_count != 0 ]] ; then
        continue
    fi
    ahead_count=`git log --oneline --no-merges $branch ^$HEAD | wc -l`
    behind_count=`git log --oneline --no-merges ^$branch $HEAD | wc -l`
    behind_merge_count=`git log --oneline --merges ^$branch $HEAD | wc -l`
    behind="-$behind_count"
    behind_merge="-M$behind_merge_count"
    ahead="+$ahead_count"
    printf "%12s  %12s   %10s     %s\n" "$behind" "$behind_merge" "$ahead" "$branch"
done | sort -n
```

Comment: Thanks. Although this may not work very well if you use `rebase` often (and merges are `fast-forward`ed often). I'll edit my answer if I found a better solution.

Comment: The only? answer so far that worked sensibly for me in the case where current branch is master. Most other solutions gave a random (and clearly incorrect) result in this admittedly edge-case where there are no actual parent branches.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. To get the first parent instead of a list of the first 10 you can use this:

`git log --oneline --merges "$@" | grep into | sed 's/.* into //g' | uniq --count | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 8`

Answer (score 11):

```
git log -2 --pretty=format:'%d' --abbrev-commit | tail -n 1 | sed 's/\s(//g; s/,/\n/g';
```

> (origin/parent-name, parent-name)

```
git log -2 --pretty=format:'%d' --abbrev-commit | tail -n 1 | sed 's/\s(//g; s/,/\n/g';
```

> origin/parent-name

```
git log -2 --pretty=format:'%d' --abbrev-commit | tail -n 1 | sed 's/(.*,//g; s/)//';
```

> parent-name

Comment: That just returns the remote branch name for me.

Comment: returns latest tag, not parent name

Answer (score 8):

Remember that, as described in ["Git: Finding what branch a commit came from"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/git-finding-what-branch-a-commit-came-from), you cannot  easily pinpoint the branch where that commit has been made (branches can be renamed, moved, deleted...), even though `git branch --contains <commit>` is a start.

- You can go back from commit to commit until `git branch --contains <commit>` doesn't list the `feature` branch and list `develop` branch,
- compare that commit SHA1 to `/refs/heads/develop`

If the two commits id match, you are good to go (that would mean the `feature` branch has its origin at the HEAD of `develop`).

Answer (score 8):

I'm not saying this is a good way to solve this problem, however this does seem to work for me:

```
git branch --contains $(cat .git/ORIG_HEAD)
```

The issue being that cat'ing a file is peeking into the inner working of Git, so this is not necessarily forwards-compatible (or backwards-compatible).

Answer (score 7):

[Joe Chrysler's command-line magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/how-to-find-the-nearest-parent-of-a-git-branch/17843908#17843908) can be simplified.  Here's Joe's logic - for brevity I've introduced a parameter named `cur_branch` in place of the command substitution `` `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` `` into both versions; that can be initialized like so:

```
cur_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Then, here's Joe's pipeline:

```
git show-branch -a           |
  grep '\*'                  | # we want only lines that contain an asterisk
  grep -v "$cur_branch"      | # but also don't contain the current branch
  head -n1                   | # and only the first such line
  sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | # really, just the part of the line between []
  sed 's/[\^~].*//'            # and with any relative refs (^, ~n) removed
```

We can accomplish the same thing as all five of those individual command filters in a relatively simple `awk` command:

```
git show-branch -a |
  awk -F'[]^~[]' '/\*/ && !/'"$cur_branch"'/ {print $2;exit}'
```

That breaks down like this:

```
-F'[]^~[]'
```

split the line into fields at `]`, `^`, `~`, and `[` characters.

```
/\*/
```

Find lines that contain an asterisk

```
&& !/'"$cur_branch"'/
```

...but not the current branch name

```
{ print $2;
```

When you find such a line, print its second field (that is, the part between the first and second occurrences of our field separator characters). For simple branch names, that will be just what's between the brackets; for refs with relative jumps, it will be just the name without the modifier. So our set of field separators handles the intent of both `sed` commands.

```
  exit }
```

Then exit immediately.  This means it only ever processes the first matching line, so we don't need to pipe the output through `head -n 1`.

Comment: Note that some branches can be missing from the output due to too many refs. They are shown as warnings on stderr instead.

Comment: Also ``cannot handle more than 26 refs``.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a PowerShell implementation of [Mark Reed's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/how-to-find-the-nearest-parent-of-a-git-branch/26597219#26597219):

```
git show-branch -a | where-object { $_.Contains('*') -eq $true} | Where-object {$_.Contains($branchName) -ne $true } | select -first 1 | % {$_ -replace('.*\[(.*)\].*','$1')} | % { $_ -replace('[\^~].*','') }
```

Comment: Does not work, see comments in the original answer and also on ladiko's answer. The answer of Justin Grote works instead on Powershell.

Answer (score 4):

[Mark Reed's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26597219) is essentially correct. However, note that the commit line should not only contain an asterisk, but begin with an asterisk! Otherwise, commit messages that contain an asterisk are also included in the matched lines. So it should be:

`git show-branch -a | awk -F'[]^~[]' '/^\*/ && !/'"$current_branch"'/ {print $2;exit}'`

or the long version:

```
git show-branch -a           |
  awk '^\*'                  | # we want only lines that contain an asterisk
  awk -v "$current_branch"   | # but also don't contain the current branch
  head -n1                   | # and only the first such line
  sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | # really, just the part of the line between []
  sed 's/[\^~].*//'            # and with any relative refs (^, ~n) removed`
```

Comment: In the long version, did you mean s/awk/grep/ ?

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
vbc=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
vbc_col=$(( $(git show-branch | grep '^[^\[]*\*' | head -1 | cut -d* -f1 | wc -c) - 1 )) 
swimming_lane_start_row=$(( $(git show-branch | grep -n "^[\-]*$" | cut -d: -f1) + 1 )) 
git show-branch | tail -n +$swimming_lane_start_row | grep -v "^[^\[]*\[$vbc" | grep "^.\{$vbc_col\}[^ ]" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//'
```

It achieves the same ends as [Mark Reed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/how-to-find-the-nearest-parent-of-a-git-branch/26597219#26597219), but it uses a much safer approach that doesn't misbehave in a number of scenarios:

1. The parent branch's last commit is a merge, making the column show `-`, not `*`
2. Commit message contains a branch name
3. Commit message contains `*`

Answer (score 4):

Here's my PowerShell version:

```
function Get-GHAParentBranch {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        $Name = (git branch --show-current)
    )
    git show-branch |
      Select-String '^[^\[]*\*' |
      Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern "\[$([Regex]::Escape($Name)).*?\]" |
      Select-Object -First 1 |
      Foreach-Object {$PSItem -replace '^.+?\[(.+)\].+$','$1'}
}
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't like the unsafe assumptions involved in parsing semi-structured text output, so I wanted a more robust solution with less assumptions:

```bash
# Search backwards in history for the first commit that is in a branch other than $1
# and output that branch's name.
parent_branch() {
    local result rev child_branch=$1
    rev=$(git rev-parse --revs-only $child_branch)
    while [[ -n $rev ]]; do
        result=$(git branch --contains $rev | grep -v " $child_branch$")
        if [[ -n $result ]]; then
            echo $result
            return 0
        fi
        rev=$(git rev-parse --revs-only $rev^)
    done
    return 1
}
```

Caveat: Since this iteratively walks backwards in history, looking at each commit to find the first that is in a different branch than `$1`, it gets more expensive the longer your branch gets. But since normally branches are supposed to be relatively short-lived anyways, that shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Also note that I'm using `git branch --contains`, so this will also find branches that share a common base but have already progressed beyond it. To only find branches that point exactly at the common base, use `git branch --points-at`.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-platform implementation with Ant

```
    <exec executable="git" outputproperty="currentBranch">
        <arg value="rev-parse" />  
        <arg value="--abbrev-ref" />  
        <arg value="HEAD" />  
    </exec>

    <exec executable="git" outputproperty="showBranchOutput">
        <arg value="show-branch" />  
        <arg value="-a" />  
    </exec>

    <loadresource property="baseBranch">
      <propertyresource name="showBranchOutput"/>
          <filterchain>
            <linecontains>
              <contains value="*"/>
            </linecontains>
            <linecontains negate="true">
              <contains value="${currentBranch}"/>
            </linecontains>
            <headfilter lines="1"/>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern=".*\[(.*)\].*" replace="\1"/>
                <replaceregex pattern="[\^~].*" replace=""/>
            </tokenfilter>
          </filterchain>
    </loadresource>

    <echo message="${currentBranch} ${baseBranch}" />
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions based on `git show-branch -a` plus some filters have one downside: Git may consider a branch name of a short-lived branch.

If you have a few possible parents which you care about, you can ask yourself this similar question (and probably the one the OP wanted to know about):

**From a specific subset of all branches, *which is the nearest parent of a git branch?***

To simplify, I'll consider "a git branch" to refer to `HEAD` (i.e., the current branch).

Let's imagine that we have the following branches:

```
HEAD
important/a
important/b
spam/a
spam/b
```

The solutions based on `git show-branch -a` + filters, may give that the nearest parent of `HEAD` is `spam/a`, but we don't care about that.

If we want to know which of `important/a` and `important/b` is the closest parent of `HEAD`, we could run the following:

```
for b in $(git branch -a -l "important/*" | sed -E -e "s/\*//"); do
    d1=$(git rev-list --first-parent ^${b} HEAD | wc -l);
    d2=$(git rev-list --first-parent ^HEAD ${b} | wc -l);
    echo "${b} ${d1} ${d2}";
done \
| sort -n -k2 -k3 \
| head -n1 \
| awk '{print $1}';
```

What it does:

1.) `$(git branch -a -l "important/*" | sed -E -e "s/\*//")`: Print a list of all branches with some pattern (`"important/*"`). (If you happen to be on one of the `important/*` branches, `git branch` will include a * to indicate your current branch. The command substitution `$()` will then expand it into the contents of your current directory. The `sed` removes the `*` from the output of `git branch`.)

2.) `d=$(git rev-list --first-parent ^${b} HEAD | wc -l);`: For each of those branches (`$b`), calculate the distance (`$d1`) in number of commits, from `HEAD` to the nearest commit in `$b` (similar to when you calculate the distance from a point to a line).  You may want to consider the distance differently here: you may not want to use `--first-parent`, or may want distance from tip to the tip of the branches (`"${b}"...HEAD`), ...

2.2) `d2=$(git rev-list --first-parent ^HEAD ${b} | wc -l);`: For each of those branches (`$b`), calculate the distance (`$d2`) in number of commits from the tip of the branch to the nearest commit in `HEAD`.  We will use this distance to choose between two branches whose distance `$d1` was equal.

3.) `echo "${b} ${d1} ${d2}";`: Print the name of each of the branches, followed by the distances to be able to sort them later (first `$d1`, and then `$d2`).

4.) `| sort -n -k2 -k3`: Sort the previous result, so we get a sorted (by distance) list of all of the branches, followed by their distances (both).

5.) `| head -n1`: The first result of the previous step will be the branch that has a smaller distance, i.e., the closest parent branch.  So just discard all other branches.

6.) `| awk '{print $1}';`: We only care about the branch name, and not about the distance, so extract the first field, which was the parent's name.  Here it is! :)

Answer (score 1):

Git comes with a couple of GUI clients that helps you visualize this. Open GitGUI and go to menu *Repository* → *Visualize All Branch History*.

Comment: How exactly is "GitGUI" opened? What platform (operating system, etc.)? Can you add some references to your answer (but ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)?

Answer (score 1):

A shell function that seeks the first commit in more than one branch:

```shell
# Get the first commit hash of a given branch.
# Uses `git branch --contains` to backward (starts from HEAD) check each commits
# and output that branch's name.
first_commit_of_branch() {
    if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ -z "${1}" ] ; then
        (>&2 echo "Error: Missing or empty branch name.")
        (>&2 echo "Usage: $0 branch_to_test")
        return 2
    fi
    local branch_to_test="${1}"; shift
    local commit_index_to_test
    local maximum_number_of_commit_to_test
    local branch_count_having_tested_commit

    git rev-parse --verify --quiet "${branch_to_test}" 2>&1 > /dev/null || {
        (>&2 echo "Error: Branch \"${branch_to_test}\" does not exists.")
        return 2
    }

    commit_index_to_test=0
    maximum_number_of_commit_to_test=$(git rev-list --count "${branch_to_test}")

    while [ ${commit_index_to_test} -le ${maximum_number_of_commit_to_test} ] ; do
        # Testing commit $branch_to_test~$commit_index_to_test…

        # If it fails, it means we tested all commits from the most recent of
        # branch $branch_to_test to the very first of the git DAG. So it must be it.
        git rev-parse --verify --quiet ${branch_to_test}~${commit_index_to_test} 2>&1 > /dev/null || {
            git rev-list --max-parents=0 "${branch_to_test}"
            return 0
        }

        branch_count_having_tested_commit="$( \
            git --no-pager branch --no-abbrev --verbose \
                --contains ${branch_to_test}~${commit_index_to_test} \
            | cut -c 3- \
            | cut -d ' ' -f 2 \
            | wc -l \
        )"

        # Tested commit found in more than one branch
        if [ ${branch_count_having_tested_commit} -gt 1 ] ; then
            if [ ${commit_index_to_test} -eq 0 ]; then
                (>&2 echo "Error: The most recent commit of branch \"${branch_to_test}\" (${branch_to_test}~${commit_index_to_test}) is already in more than one branch. This is likely a new branch without any commit (yet). Cannot continue.")
                return 1
            else
                # Commit $branch_to_test~$commit_index_to_test is in more than
                # one branch, stopping there…
                git rev-parse ${branch_to_test}~$((commit_index_to_test-1))
                return 0
            fi
        fi
        # else: Commit $branch_to_test~$commit_index_to_test is still only in
        #       branch ${branch_to_test} continuing…"
        commit_index_to_test=$((commit_index_to_test+1))
    done
}
```

Caveat: It fails when executed on a branch having a sub branch and no new commit since.

```
A---B---C---D      <- "main" branch
 \   \
  \   E---F        <- "work1" branch
   \       \
    \       G---H  <- "work1-b" branch
     \
      I---J        <- "work2" branch
```

```shell
first_commit_of_branch main # C
first_commit_of_branch work1 # (Fails)
first_commit_of_branch work1-b # G
first_commit_of_branch work2 # I
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to see the name of the branch which you created your new git branch from, use this command:

```
git log --first-parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone wanting to do this these days - Atlassian's [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) application shows you a great visual representation of how your branches relate to one another, i.e. where they began and where they currently sit in the commit order (e.g., HEAD or 4 commits behind, etc.).

Comment: One may need to use the parent branch in a script, and for that you need to extract the parent's name.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sourcetree, look at your commit details → *Parents*. Then you'll see commit numbers underlined (links).

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me when I had done something like *develop* → *release-v1.0.0* → *feature-foo*. It would go all the way back to develop. Note there was a rebase involved and I am not sure if that is compounding my issue...

The following did give the correct commit hash for me:

```
git log --decorate \
  | grep 'commit' \
  | grep 'origin/' \
  | head -n 2 \
  | tail -n 1 \
  | awk '{ print $2 }' \
  | tr -d "\n"
```

Comment: So far that seems to be the only answer that works for me.

Small hint: use ripgrep instead of grep to make it almost instant.

Comment: We actually made this a lot easier by saving the exact answer to a `<branch>.json` file in the repo. Adds a bit of clutter, but it gives us enormous flexibility to define extra variables for storing information and controlling processes in CI. We made a script that creates a branch, creates this file, and then commits and pushes, setting up the origin at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the "parent" of the "feature" branch, is a branch, that I explicitly marked as "base" in a pull request for the "feature" branch. It can be discovered with [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com):

```bash
gh pr list --head "feature" --json baseRefName --jq '.[].baseRefName'
```

Answer (score 0):

This earlier answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37159240/1009693
However, using `git show-branch` assumes the parent branch we're looking for is already cloned in the local repository. What if it isn't?

Suppose the local repository cloned a single branch and we want to find its parent -- most likely, it will be a remote branch, if there is one. This is where `git show-branch --remotes` becomes useful; however, we now need to handle the different output, there may not be any '*' characters! Finally, we also need to extract the name of the remote -- what if it is not `origin`?

The following does all that.

```
vbc=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u})
remote=$(echo $vbc | sed 's|\(.*\)/.*|\1|')
vbc_col=$(( $(git show-branch --remotes | grep '^\s*\!' | wc -l) )) 
swimming_lane_start_row=$(( $(git show-branch --remotes | grep -n "\s\[$vbc" | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1) + 1 )) 
git show-branch --remotes | tail -n +$swimming_lane_start_row | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//' | sed -e "s|$remote/||"
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested for more than a few cases, but this works for the few derivative branches I've tested with?

```
git branch -a --contains \
    $(git show-branch --merge-base) \
    | grep -v -e remotes/ \
    -e $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) \
    | head -1 | xargs
```

Answer (score -1):

`git branch | tail -n1` Works for me

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

An alternative:

```
git rev-list master | grep "$(git rev-list HEAD)" | head -1
```

Get the last commit that it's both my branch and `master` (or whatever branch you want to specify).

Comment: I get the following error: ``bash: /usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long``

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, which is to detect the parent branch name.  This gives a commit that is common between 2 known branches.