# Which git branch was this branch checked out from?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the parent branch of a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-branch)

How do I find out the name of the git branch that the branch in question split off from (if any)?

Comment: Do you mean the remote branch it is tracking, or the branch that a branch split off from (if any)? I don't think you can always find the latter.

Comment: The local branch that this one split off from (if any). Could not state this better than you did.

Comment: I don't think Git even records that information, though I could be mistaken.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-branch

Comment: How about `git brach --contains HEAD~X` that shows the branches that contain a commit HEAD~X of the current branch. If we loop the command, incrementing X, then finally we will find a commit that is contained in this branch and the branch that we are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy for us to think `master` is always `master` and `my_branch` is always `my_branch`, but that is not the case. Say you have your repository in Github, your windows, your linux and your office.

You therefore have 8 different branches:

```
github/master
github/my_branch
windows/master
windows/my_branch
linux/master
linux/my_branch
office/master
office/my_branch
```

You as a human see them as `master` and `my_branch` but git sees them as 8 different branches. So if you have a network like this:

```
------------------------------------------------ linux/master
 \--/ \-------/      /            \-------- office/my_branch
  | \---|--\--------/-------------------\------- my_branch
  |     |
  |   office/master
  | 
windows/master
```

what does it mean to ask where `my_branch` comes from? It is a result of merge of many branches!

---

There, so what I wanted to tell you is that there is a philosophical problem with your question. However there is a way to answer it, although not perfectly. First let's look at `git log`:

```
git log my_branch --pretty=oneline --graph
```

gives you a nice presentation of merges and stuff. From the git-log man page:

```
--first-parent
    Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. This option can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of a particular topic branch,
    because merges into a topic branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated upstream from time to time, and this option allows you to ignore the individual
    commits brought in to your history by such a merge.
```

Using that, you get a linear history of the branch. Removing the graph and outputting only SHA1s, you will get:

```
git log my_branch --pretty=format:"%H" --first-parent
```

Using the following command, you can tell which branches contain an SHA1:

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

Putting a script together using these commands, you can use the following script that basically finds the latest SHA1 that is contained in another branch other than the one you are interested in. It then outputs that other branch. (Note: I'm not good in bash scripting yet, so this may not be so efficient):

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  branch=master
else
  branch=$1
fi

sha1s=$(git log $1 --pretty=format:"%H")
res="Doesn't branch from anything"

for i in $sha1s; do
  b=$(git branch --contains $i | awk '{ if (NF > 1) print $2; else print $1 }') # use awk to remove * from current branch
  other_branch="";
  for j in $b; do
    if [ $branch != $j ]; then
      other_branch=$j
      break;
    fi
  done
  if [ -n "$other_branch" ]; then
    res=$other_branch
    break
  fi
done

printf -- '%s\n' "$res"
```

I said it's not perfect, because of the following situation. Imagine if `my_branch` is branched from `master`. In fact you then see the graph like this:

```
                    /------------ master
------(master)-----
                    \------------ my_branch
```

The initial commits are contained in the history of **both** branches. It is unknown that they originally came from master. Therefore, this script will tell you that `my_branch` was branched from `master` and at the same time tells you that `master` is branched from `my_branch`. There is no way to tell which one was the original one.