# How to find the father branch in git?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the parent branch of a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-branch)

I have made a new feature branch but I have forgotten form where did I branch this feature branch. Now the feature is complete but I don't know in which branch I have to merge
Who do I find the branch that I have branched from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can use gitk or git-log to better visualize your commits history.

Like this:

```
gitk --all
```

or

```
git log --graph --decorate
```

Answer (score 2):

You can a list of child branches by typing: git branch --contains

Only if you don't have many branches that could be the parent branch, I think it could be useful