# How do I ask git to merge branch back to parent

Tags: githooks, git-alias

Is there a way to write an alias that merges a branch back to its parent? I know I can do:

```
git checkout - && git merge -
```

But it only works in simple cases when my previous branch is the parent branch.
As far as I know git does not track this kind of information because there is no branches in there. But I hope it's already implemented as a plugin or a hookset.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Such an alias would involve first finding the "parent" branch.

It isn't trivial, and the question "[Find the parent branch of a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204/6309)" has some good solutions.

> Git’s history is based on a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of commits. Branches (and “refs” in general) are just transient labels that point to specific commits in the continually growing commit DAG.
>   **As such, the relationship between branches can vary over time, but the relationship between commits does not**.

Once you have the name of the parent branch, then you can use it in your alias.

Answer (score 1):

As VonC said first I need to do is to find parent of the current branch. The following script mostly does what I need:

```
git branch | grep -v '*'|xargs -I{} sh -c ' printf "{}:"; git log --oneline `git merge-base "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" "{}"` | wc -l' | sort -t: -k +2n | tail -n 1 | sed 's/:.*//'
```

What it does:

- For each branch finds merge-base with the current branch
- Finds branch:log-length pair maximizing log-length
- Extracts branch name

After that one just need to checkout to it and merge previous head into it:

```
git checkout $parent_branch && git merge -
```

PS: I didn't test it on large repositories and it can behave suprisingly if exists a branch of the current branch. It needs to be fixed.