# Which node is checked out into my local working tree when cloning a remote Git repository?

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git.

Git follows the non-linear DAG model. So there can be many nodes along many work paths. When I clone a remote git repo like below:

```
git clone https://xxx.git
```

Which node in the DAG do I get checked out as my local working tree?

I think it should be some kind of *latest* node. But since DAG model can have many branches each pointing to the tip of a certain development path, which one do I get when cloning? The HEAD symbolic pointer on the server? If so, who decides that HEAD?

Comment: It could be master or no HEAD without `-b `. In the latter case, you need to run `git checkout` after clone is done.

Comment: Note that you may specify a symbolic name when cloning, "git clone -b *name* *url*", to override the default.  This name can be any name that Git sees at the start of the clone process, but not a raw hash.  See VonC's answer for the rest.

Answer (score 4):

> If so, who decides that HEAD?

See "[Change a Git remote HEAD to point to something besides master](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485590/6309)"

By default, HEAD (on the remote repo side) references `master`, but some git repo hosting services ([GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/), [GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31004872/6309), [BitBucket](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/280944/answers/2850342)) propose to change the default branch.
That effectively changes the symbolic-ref that is HEAD, as in [`git symbolic-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref):

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/head/anotherBranch
```

If you point a default branch (on a remote repo), and then later delete that branch, any clone of that remote repo would fail and complain.

Comment: Thx. So, it IS the HEAD that get checked out as my local working tree. And btw, if the default branch `origin\master` is so critical, why not make it un-deletable?

Comment: @smwikipedia branches are just transient markers in that DAG: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24404577/6309. And master is just a naming convention.