# Finding the branch a given branch branched from

Tags: git, github

I have a branch in a GitHub repository, how can I find the branch it branched from? When I look at the commit history within the branch, it shows me all the commits for the branch but nothing seems to mark to the first commit where it branched (i.e. the first commit of the branch).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the parent branch of a branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-branch)

Answer (score 1):

i suggest to use the CLI on your local repo:

```
git config --global color.ui auto
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

Scroll until you see the branches that you search for.

There are also some other alternative as well of course like:

```
git merge-base
```

Comment: Thanks, aside from manually browsing this graph (which is huge and long), is there any other way of getting this information using the CLI?

Comment: there are several ways to travest the log tree. this is the most simple one.

Im a big fan of CLI but for diff and view log history im recommanding using sourcetree http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: Thanks. Would it be correct to assume that doing an exhaustive `git merge-base` against all branches (current and closed) could do it? If so, how can I go to doing this using the CLI?

Comment: if you use windows right click on the repository folder and choose "Git Bash here". If you use unix/mac etc open terminal and navigate to the working repository dir

Answer (score 1):

git doesn't have a notion of "branching points". A git commit can be through of as a node in a singly linked list, each commit knows about it's parent(s) only.

With that said, to get an overview of the history of a git repository you can use

```
git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate
```

and all it's variants.