# Create Branch of Branch in git?

Tags: git, branch, git-remote

I have master with a branch FooDev in git repository. 
Master-----FooDev

Can I create a Branch(es) off of FooDev, so:
master----FooDev--|-----Sprint1Sue
                  |------- Sprint1Joe

If so how do I so this? Can I see this somehow in my local repo? It does not see I can branch from a branch and
git push needs remote branch, but i don't know how/if I can specify a branch as a specific origin.

M

Answer (score 3):

Definitely. You can pass an optional argument to `git checkout -b` to specify where you want to branch from:

```
$ git checkout -b <new-branch-name> <branch-to-start-from>
```

Or from `git branch`:

```
$ git branch <new-branch-name> <branch-to-start-from>
```

In fact, you can create a branch off of *any* commit: branches, tags, even just a commit referenced by its SHA1 hash.

Comment: Ok. How do you know in git that new-branch is a from a of branch-to-start -from? I did this, but git does not seem to indicate the parent branch, at least in local

Comment: @1lostball: That's a bit tricker. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3162929/28804