# Determine a git branch's ancestor branch

Tags: git, git-log

I have a long running git branch. I am trying to determine its ancestor. For example, if I am on a `staging` branch that split from `master`, the following commands would be perfect:

```
> git log --show-ancestor-branch
master
```

or

```
> git log --show-branches-with-common-ancestors
master
```

What I mean by ancestor is that `master` in the following log would be an ancestor of `staging`.

```
* 741c3fd (master) 
| * a8503ef (HEAD, staging) 
|/
| 
|
* bd783e3 Add simple query expressions
```

The following did not work:

```
*  `git log --ancestry-path`
* ` git merge-base -a`
```

The following would work in subversion:

```
svn log --stop-on-copy
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the parent branch of a branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-branch)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible to do, since in the end a branch is just a pointer to some commit hash, and it doesn't "leave marks" where it's been.

You could see who has the nearest common ancestor of your branch but that is not 100% guaranteed to be what you're looking for.

One thing we did on my team was, one the first commit in a new branch, write

> Branched from *some_branch*

And we could track it like that. It's not very l33t but hey, it works :)

Comment: Folks on my team would never agree to this. We like automation too much. I wish Git allowed an option to recognize parent branches by default.